# Deveremos manter algum padrão linguístico ou não?

Tags: debate, tradução, proposta-para-faq, edição, diferenças-regionais

Eu sou português. Como sabem, o português usado em Portugal tem algumas diferenças em relação ao português usado no Brasil.

Também sei que para nós, portugueses, não nos custa muito ler em *brasileiro*. E pela experiência que já tive em contactar com brasileiros sei que existem algumas barreiras linguísticas.

Portanto, a minha questão é: Deveremos todos tentar manter uma linguagem neutra (sem usar particularidades da lingua falada no país) ou um português deverá habituar-se e falar "mais para o brasileiro"? (usando a terceira pessoa, algumas expressões brasileiras, etc).

Acho este assunto interessante porque:

- A lingua é importante e é importante que num site de perguntas e respostas todos se entendam.
- No Stack Overflow é muito frequente haver "correções" linguísticas e estou mesmo a ver muitos *edits* a acontecerem por causa destas diferenças.

PS: As tags não deviam de estar traduzidas? :p

Comment: Também me preocupo com esta questão. Perceba que na url deste site está como br.stackoverflow.com e não como pt.stackoverflow.com. Em muitos fóruns, alguns brasileiros e outros portugueses acontece a escrita tanto em um português como em outro.

Comment: Dado que houve a reforma ortográfica para adequação de vários "portugueses", não acho que seja necessária adequação de vocabulário. Acho até que enriqueceria se nós lusófonos conhecêssemos vocábulos de países do outro lado do atlântico. Existe algo como um "português internacional"?

Comment: Por mim é indiferente. Entendo bem brasileiros e se for preciso escrevo mais "abrasileirado". Mas considero importante que seja definido. Principalmente pela "discordia" que pode haver nas edições. Quanto ao acordo ortográfico muita gente está a evitar de o usar. Também que eu saiba não existe um "português internacional". O acordo ortográfico tinha como objectivo caminhar nesse sentido :p

Comment: Eu poderia escrever bastante sobre isso, mas vou apenas deixar um link para minha opinião em outra pergunta que é relacionada (ainda que tangencialmente) a esta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/679/1658

Comment: @tsippert agora já é pt.stackoverflow.com ;)

Comment: Existe sim muitos edites relativos às regras gramaticais. Eu mesmo já realizei várias correções, principalmente à concordâncias verbo/nominais. Portanto, o que se espera quanto à edição de um post é o mínimo de clareza e objetividade possível, o qual só conseguimos com o mínimo de coerência.

Answer (score 39):

Durante o projeto nós conversamos bastante sobre o que significa "em português", justamente por saber das diferenças bem óbvias no português falado nos diferentes países.

O Brasil é, de longe, o país com o maior número de pessoas que falam português (e consequentemente, o maior número potencial de usuários no site) e é natural que ele venha a ser bastante tendencioso ao PT_BR.

Não queremos de forma alguma que portugueses, angolanos e pessoas de outros países não possam falar sua língua, com receio de downvotes ou edits. Acredito que seja possível nos entendermos sem que ninguém seja forçado a falar "brasileirês".

Melhor esperar pra ver o que acontece. Por enquanto, escreva como quiser.

Sobre as tags, elas vão ser traduzidas... O site ainda é um trabalho em andamento :)

Comment: compreendo perfeitamente. Para já como é tudo mais ou menos experiente na filosofia do SO acho que nao vai haver problema. Um dia mais tarde poderá haver.  Mas conto que fiques sempre atento :p

Comment: Existe também a questão de usar os termos em inglês em muitos casos. Deve-se observar alguma restrição quanto a isso? Pelo que percebo portugueses tendem a traduzir mais os termos que os brasileiros. Algum problema em manter os termos sem tradução?

Comment: Já tive problemas também de termos iguais, defeito e padrão, que causam equívoco. Podemos definir alguma simbologia para manter ambas traduções não?

Answer (score 22):

#### Em relação às perguntas e respostas

Todos nós falamos português, e acredito que sejamos capazes de nos compreender mutuamente sem problemas. Algumas expressões e construções portuguesas podem soar estranhas aos brasileiros e vice-versa, porém não acho que isso deva ser editado. Eu pessoalmente tenderia a desfazer esse tipo de edição, caso encontre alguma. Na minha opinião, devemos sim corrigir erros de sintaxe ou ortografia, mas não variações sintáticas perfeitamente válidas. Inclusive, eu ampliaria essa regra para a ortografia, aceitando termos pré-acordo ortográfico em ambas as variantes (por exemplo, "correção" *versus* "correcção".

#### Em relação à interface do site, incluindo tags

Este ponto é um pouco mais complicado, pois não pode haver variação, a interface deve ser consistente. O argumento do Gabe de que há mais falantes de português no Brasil do que em outros países talvez seja determinante aqui, a acredito que toda a interface do site tenda mesmo ao português brasileiro. Porém entendo que isso possa incomodar ou mesmo afastar falantes nativos de outros países lusófonos. Neste caso devemos nos ater ao (controverso) Acordo Ortográfico, que é o mais próximo que temos de um português "neutro".

Comment: Perfeito! A tradução realmente ficaria melhor sendo o mais neutra possível e quando houver dúvidas o PT-BR poderia ser a prioridade pela proporção provável de usuários. Para escrever, tem que adotar o que muitos outros sites adotam, cada em escreve o que achar melhor e os leitores que se adaptem. Ninguém deve editar alguma coisa para abrasileirar ou aportuguesar um texto de acordo com sua própria conveniência. O mesmo vale obviamente para outros países, mas vou me ater ao Brasil e Portugal por ser os países que terão a esmagadora maioria dos usuários.

Answer (score 9):

Acredito que os outros países lusófonos estão muito mais acostumados ao vocabulário e expressões brasileiras dada a exposição da indústria Audiovisual e Musical do Brasil.

Do ponto de vista de um brasileiro, gosto muito de ler o original (pt_PT) e as outras variantes do idioma e aprender expressões e palavras diferentes.

Já fiz um *edit* equivocado por pura ignorância e tomo bastante cuidado hoje em dia. Menos mal que [o Sérgio tem um grande coração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/14568/revisions) e deixou estar :)

Acho que a diversidade é positiva e, **não**, não devemos forçar nenhuma padronização nesse sentido.

<sub>PS: estando na Europa cheguei a conclusão que algum dia teremos direito à *Língua Brasileira*. Vários europeus ficam estranhados "ah, a língua de vocês é *português* e não *brasileiro*, curioso!". Aqui, qualquer mini-variante já recebe nome próprio e dá até guerra se alguém tiver a ousadia de dizer: "pô, mas são muuito parecidas!".</sub>

Comment: Só de curiosidade, assim como Brasileiro não fala Brasileiro, é legal lembrar que um Estadunidense não fala "estadunidense", tampouco "americano". Eles falam inglês :) (é só um complemento ao que você disse dos europeus estranharem falarmos português aqui no Brasil)

Comment: Os ianques tem um problema mais grave, nem "estados"  nem "unidos" são nomes próprios e nem "américa" é exclusivo (como fantasiam ser). *Poor dudes, the only nameless country of the world* :o]

Comment: @Bacco só os menos informados, toda a gente sabe que no Brasil se fala português ;)

Answer (score 4):

Quanto à questão dos edits linguísticos, a política que eles usam na Wikipédia é de que deve ser mantida a ortografia original. Acredito que no SO em inglês a regra seja similar.

http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikip%C3%A9dia:Vers%C3%B5es_da_l%C3%ADngua_portuguesa

Isso obviamente não impede as pessoas de editarem assim mesmo mas é melhor que nada.