# Como se portar ao perguntar/responder?

Tags: debate, perguntas, comportamento, respostas

Uma dúvida que eu tenho é sobre como se portar nas perguntas/repostas desse site. No Stack Overflow ou Meta se vê um ar mais formal quando usuários dirigem a palavra entre si. Não se vê nada como *"hey dude"* ou *"ya'know"*. É claro que esse tipo de gíria não deve ser usado por aqui também, porém minha dúvida é sobre a formalidade que deve ser adotada, por exemplo:

- Caso 1:

> Bom dia/Boa Tarde/Boa Noite,
>
> Estou com um problema no meu código...
>
> Obrigado/Att.

- Caso 2:

> E ae Galera/Pessoal,
>
> To com uma baita zica no meu código...
>
> Valeu.

O primeiro caso tem um tom mais de e-mail, mais formal. Já o segundo é mais a vontade. Quando fora do *padrão* o post deve ser editado?

Nota: Favor não confundir com [esse post](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3/deveremos-de-manter-algum-standard-linguistico-ou-nao).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Apesar de manter sempre que [aqui não é o SO](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-no-o-stackoverflow-com), certas coisas fogem dos padrões do SE (que existem por um bom motivo). Os exemplos que você citou, e o bfavaretto já tocou no assunto, independente do caso são considerados ruído no post.

Boas perguntas são **descritivas, detalhadas e diretas** (3D, se você for do estilo mnemônico). Sempre tenha em mente que alguém que você não conhece vai, voluntariamente, gastar um tempo do dia pra responder sua pergunta, então o melhor que você pode fazer é tornar esse trabalho mais fácil.

Dê o máximo de informações possíveis sobre o que você quer fazer, que erro está encontrando e que soluções você já tentou. Lembre que quem vai te ajudar não pode (nem quer) ficar conversando com você a tarde inteira pra conseguir mais informações, então forneça tudo de cara.

Nesse contexto, gastar tempo falando *"To com um problema grande aqui que já gastei um tempão tentando resolver e até agora nada"* é desnecessário. Se você não tivesse um problema, não estaria perguntando...

Pode parecer rude não falar "Obrigado", "Por favor" ou qualquer outra coisa mais informal, mas pense que aceitar a resposta como correta é o melhor *"obrigado"* que você pode dar.

Comment: Esse é um ponto importante. Também acho "obrigado", "por favor", etc. desnecessários. Quanto mais direto alguém puder chegar na solução, melhor, pois ela perderá menos tempo filtrando o que realmente importa na pergunta e na resposta. A dúvida que tenho é se deveremos editar perguntas/respostas para remover essas interjeições. Temos que ver como isso vai evoluir...

Comment: Por enquanto, sintam-se à vontade para editar e remover essas coisas. O Stack Overflow tem um filtro que remove esses termos automaticamente quando você posta algo, mas obviamente ele precisa ser adaptado para os termos em PT

Answer (score 10):

Não tenho grandes problemas com gírias ou linguagem informal. Porém, seus exemplos são frases que eu simplesmente cortaria dos posts, por não acrescentar nenhum conteúdo importante. São simplesmente formalidades, que no SO também são considerados "ruídos" a serem ser eliminados.

Comment: Sim, no SO são cortados os "Hi everybody" e "Thank you" por exemplo. Usei mesmo como exemplo.

Comment: Então não entendi o que você quer discutir aqui: linguagem formal versus informal, ou ruídos?

Comment: Eu falei que lá são cortados, to perguntando como vai ser aqui. Assim como na questão de gírias que lá são eliminadas(eu mesmo tiro um monte).

Comment: Ttem que tomar cuidado com gíria porque não tem só brasileiro.

Answer (score 9):

O Caso 2 é simples, é muito informal, beirando o internetês (não que neste caso seja) e não cabe em um site de Q&A (ou P&R? argh!).

- Precisamos nos diferenciar do padrão usado em fóruns
- Precisamos facilitar para todos. Esse tipo de linguagem é muito regional se considerarmos o mundo todo. Na questão que você citou, fala-se sobre isso, pode usar a língua como você conhece, mas se abusar, pode ficar muito complicado de todos os usuários que falam nossa língua entender.
- Esse tipo de linguagem atrai usuários ruins ([veja mais aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/44/teoria-das-janelas-partidas))

O Caso 1 está ok exceto por um ponto. "Bom dia/Boa Tarde/Boa Noite" não faz parecer e-mail (muitos cometem esse erro no e-mail). Parece chat. E-mail nunca deveria ter esse tipo de saudação e uma questão ou resposta em um site de Q&A também não. Não estamos conversando aqui. Não sabemos quando a pessoa vai ler a postagem. Esse tipo de saudação é ótimo em outras situações, aqui é só ruído. Não vejo problemas na cordialidade do obrigado, embora em geral seja desnecessário em editaria para tirá-lo quando visse. Lembre que não estamos conversando, estamos perguntando e respondendo questões técnicas/profissionais.

Nada contra a informalidade, todos somos informais aqui, o problema é quando há ruído, você escreveu demais por um lado e não deu o mínimo necessário com clareza, aí fica feio e nos coloca no mesmo nível que outros sites que se propõe a divertir, que espanta os profissionais especializados e que gostam de se denominar redes sociais. **Aqui NÃO É rede social.**

Portanto minha opinião é que ninguém deve usar esse tipo de linguagem e sempre que possível deve editar quando vê algo assim, atendendo a teoria das Janelas Quebradas.