# Teoria das janelas partidas

Tags: debate, comportamento

Quero apenas citar a teoria das janelas quebradas (ou partidas como alguns traduzem do *broken windows*) aqui no meta porque muitas pessoas não compreendem porque os sites do SE (Stack Exchange) dão certo. E essa informação tem muito valor para direcionarmos nosso rumo adequadamente.

Um dos principais motivos do sucesso do SO e demais sites da rede é a comunidade ativa e preocupada com a qualidade.

Para que essa qualidade aconteça em qualquer lugar do mundo virtual ou real é preciso um policiamento constante de todas ações que as pessoas possam fazer.

Esse policiamento significa, alertar os moderadores para procedimentos e acontecimentos danosos à comunidade, votar à favor ou contra (ou mesmo fechar) questões e respostas de acordo com sua adequação, ajudar quem tem dificuldades de entender a filosofia da comunidade, consertar (editar) pequenos erros entre as muitas coisas que muitos aqui já conhecem.

**Não permitir que algo ruim fique visível e influencie outras pessoas fazer o mesmo**, a ação precisa ocorrer rápido. Quando algo ruim fica visível, ocorre o fenômeno chamado "janelas quebradas".

Quando alguém vê uma janela quebrada, ela acha que isso é o normal nesse local e tende a quebrar mais janelas. Isso inclusive consta de um livro bastante conhecido sobre o assunto: [Janelas Partidas na Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teoria_das_Janelas_Partidas). Se puder veja a [versão em inglês](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory) que para variar é **muito** melhor e vale muito à pena para a vida de qualquer pessoa.

Nesse início é ainda mais importante reforçar a necessidade de que as janelas nunca fiquem quebradas, até mesmos riscos na janela podem comprometer o resultado futuro do nosso site. Apelo para que todos que puderem ajudar (tenha tempo, disposição e experiência), o façam e mesmo que não possam ajudar tão ativamente que pelo menos não ajude a quebrar ou trincar as janelas. Pense duas vezes antes de fazer algo que pode sugerir um comportamento ruim para um leigo mesmo que esse comportamento não seja exatamente contra nossa filosofia. Não se esqueçam que vamos começar receber usuários que nunca usaram ativamente o SO e qualquer coisa que eles vejam que possa indicar que aqui é mais um fórum do tipo "Casa da mãe Joana" onde tudo pode, eles vão seguir com esse comportamento.

E lembre-se que isso é uma comunidade. Por mais que cada um tenha uma visão particular de como as coisas devam andar aqui, as regras da casa precisam ser seguidas. Existe um bom motivo por a comunidade ou mesmo a equipe do SE definirem determinadas regras. Você pode discordar delas sem problemas, expressar sua opinião, e lutar para que elas sejam diferentes, mas no momento que elas são estabelecidas, precisam ser seguidas mesmo havendo discordância. Funciona como a lei de país, com a vantagem que você tem a opção de não participar. Claro que queremos que todos participem e sintam-se à vontade mas não a custa da organização da comunidade. Um usuário que não segue as regras é mais perigoso que um que não participa de forma alguma.

- Votem
- Sinalizem problemas
- Editem coisas erradas
- Comentem para ajudar principalmente os novatos
- Participe do meta
- Evitem comportamentos desagradáveis
- Sigam a filosofia dos sites SE e nossa comunidade

Comment: Isso não deveria ser um post em blog ao invés de uma pergunta?

Comment: Não temos um blog. No meta, as perguntas podem ser usadas para postarmos assuntos importantes que todos devem saber.

Comment: @bigown belo post, e obrigado por me apresentar à Teoria das Janelas Partidas.