# Edições em massa

Tags: debate, edição, comportamento

Notei que o usuário [bigown](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101) esta tarde editou **praticamente todas** as perguntas do site.

Enquanto suas edições não deixam de estar erradas, muitas vezes elas são desnecessárias (por serem tão pequenas).

Acho que deveriamos conter esse tipo de atitude, pois além de o usuário aparecer no site inteiro (sem ter contribuído tanto assim), atrapalha também a página inicial. Enquanto faz edições minúsculas em perguntas antigas (já respondidas e discutidas a fundo) elas acabam escondendo as verdadeiras perguntas novas do site.

O que acham?

Comment: Vou deixar os outros falarem o que acham. O que posso dizer é que eu vi que é melhor arrumar alguns problema agora enquanto é gerenciável (é possível e causam poucos problemas) do que no futuro. Estamos em beta privado para fazer ajustes. http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/44/teoria-das-janelas-partidas lembrando sempre que http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-no-o-stackoverflow-com e ainda estamos definindo nosso rumo

Comment: Acho é que o sistema podia ser melhorado, pois o "crédito" do edit é grande demais, e chama atenção indevida não importa quem edite. E isso é um problema geral do SO/SE.

Answer (score 13):

Resolvi responder:

1. Espero que a ênfase no praticamente todas seja só para chamar a atenção mesmo, porque isso é um exagero.
2. Espero que a frase "*suas edições não deixam de estar erradas*" seja ato falho e a última palavra seja "*certas*"
3. Ser pequena e ser desnecessária são coisas distintas. Eu sei que no SO o pessoal acha que é a mesma coisa. A questão aqui é: Vamos ter a mesma atitude aqui?
4. Basicamente estou acertando tags antes que saia do controle, isso é desnecessário?
5. Alguém acha que a pessoa ter o nome na edição faz parecer que a pessoa contribuiu enormemente? Eu nunca achei, mas posso ser caso atípico. Neste caso, devemos deixar de fazer algo potencialmente útil porque algumas pessoas podem achar que estamos querendo crédito indevido, mesmo que o crédito do que cada um fez seja bem demonstrado? Tem como tirar o nome de lá? Não fiz para ter o nome.
6. Resolvi fazer isso enquanto estamos nos Beta Privado, onde as consequências não são grandes e são mais restritas. Resolvi fazer isso poque percebi que não vamos a público tão rapidamente. E agora é humanamente possível fazer isso. Estava em boa fé tentando evitar termos [janelas partidas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/44/teoria-das-janelas-partidas). Quando resolver o problema do cedilha nas tags, não vamos consertar isso?
7. Não sabia que o algoritmo que determina o que deve estar na primeira página era tão frágil, tão fácil de ser manipulado para destacar uma pergunta que alguém deseja. Se soubesse disso, iria pensar mais antes de fazer ou pelo menos iria buscar uma ordem que não afetasse a sua exibição. Tem como consertar isso, pelo menos parcialmente.
8. Admito que deveria ter perguntado antes se eu poderia fazer tantas mudanças, mas na hora não me ocorreu, peço desculpas se causei algum transtorno, não foi minha intenção. Parei assim que fui contestado. Preferi fazer agora, sabia que mais tarde isso seria problemático e obviamente **não pretendo e não acho que alguém deva fazer no futuro**. Agora fico na dúvida se ainda devo terminar o que comecei hoje ou não mais mexer e deixar inconsistente?
9. O problema é apenas editar nas antigas ou editar em qualquer questão? Ou seja, poderei editar as novas que forem surgindo?
10. Vamos seguir a cultura do SO que não aceita edição mínima, mesmo que ela melhore alguma coisa, ou vamos criar a nossa que preza mais pela qualidade? Na minha percepção, essa cultura provavelmente nasceu do mesmo equívoco que o nome da pessoa aparecer na edição dá a ela o crédito pelo post. [Aqui NÃO É o stackoverflow.com](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-no-o-stackoverflow-com)
11. Note que eu fiz isso quando não mais ganhava reputação por edição para evitar acusação de estar fazendo isso por reputação. Fiz porque achei que era necessário.
12. Acatarei a decisão dos demais membros do que fazer, não quero ir contra o que a comunidade determinar, mesmo que seja contrária ao que eu acho correto.

---

**Edit: Terminei** Embora não tenha nada em mente, agora só vou fazer edições em massa de forma mais limitada e se for absolutamente necessária

Comment: Tudo bem! Você me convenceu, não havia pensado desta maneira, após sua explicação entendi o porque de tantos ajustes e achei válido! Valeu!

Comment: @Pimenta Minha tentativa não é te convencer (pelo menos não simplesmente isso), é tentar entender como vai funcionar. Achei sua pergunta válida também. Ainda vou aguardar outra opiniões.

Comment: Quanto ao 7 o que ocorre é o seguinte: a tab "ativo" (perguntas com atividade recente) traz qualquer pergunta que tenha sido editada para o topo. Eu pessoalmente nunca a uso (prefiro a tab "as mais novas") mas muita gente usa, por isso de fato um grande número de edições faz com que ela mude desordenadamente. Entretanto, num site de grande volume como o SO em inglês ela mudaria de qualquer jeito - pelo fluxo constante de novas perguntas - por isso não acho que umas edições a mais causariam grande transtorno. Além disso, é fácil saber quando uma edição tem o intuito de melhorar ou apenas abusar

Comment: @mgibsonbr Eu também nunca usei, em geral fico nas "mais novas", e nas "mais votadas" em certas circunstâncias. Mas diga o que você acha que deve-se fazer agora. Tem alguma ideia p/ não prejudicar a ordem? Eu até tenho, mas seria fazer edições fakes só para ajustar isso. Se for necessário e útil, eu faço.

Comment: @bigown Eu pessoalmente não acho nada, e já ia até me abster do debate. Mas resolvi dar uma olhadinha no metão pra ver como as coisas são feitas por lá, acabei postando o que achei como outra resposta.

Comment: Eu só tenho pena de neste site _ainda_ só poder aprovar até 20 edições por dia!! Tem sido um excelente trabalho da parte do bigown em arrumar a casa a nível de perguntas, respostas e tags, o tempo necessário para realizar estas tarefas **em condições** é enorme e é de louvar a quantidade de tempo que ele tem dedicado.

Comment: @Zuul Eu nem acho que estou fazendo com muita qualidade ainda. Estou privilegiando a quantidade. Não estou fazendo nada terrível, que prejudique, mas está abaixo do que gostaria. Até porque minha fonte nas tag wikis é o SO e lá tem muita coisa que está ruim e minhas traduções não estão no melhor nível. Mas vou voltar e melhorar grande parte do material, espero que outras pessoas o façam também. Precisa ter material para ajudar os buscadores quando abrir publicamente, melhor ter algo escrito +/-, mas não terrível, do que nada. Tinha acesso a informações, sei o que precisa p/ atrair novos users.

Comment: Sim! Posso dizer que foram poucas as vezes, mas aconteceu ver o meu rato a deslocar-se à procura do botão "melhorar"... mas _404 - Button Not Found!_. Em todo o caso estás a deixar a base para que todos possam ir melhorando! Mas tenho o meu Firefox com muitos separadores abertos em tag-wiki para as editar assim que seja oportuno de forma a melhorar o conteúdo e/ou retificar uns mini-typos! :)

Comment: @Zuul. Admito que alguns erros grosseiros passam e alguns posts deveriam ser até rejeitados. Preciso aprender parar quando estou ficando cansado. Quero começar padronizar algumas coisas também. Estou deixando +/- como está no SO e cada wiki tem um estilo. E vou abrir várias discussões para determinar o melhor uso de tags específicas.

Comment: Nada de grosseiro, mas sujeito a pequenas melhorias que surgem quando outra pessoa lê o texto, embora normal até porque a primeira versão é sempre Alpha :) Vi sim situações tipo `[tag:stack-trace ]` cujo espaço em branco no final quebra a apresentação da tag e deixa o código da mesma visível; ou a palavra `vissivel`... Cenários que qualquer um pode ajustar à posteriori.

Comment: @Zuul muitos erros são culpa da Google :P Mas eu sei que tem coisas piores que esses typos.

Comment: PSC, eu rejeitei uma ou outra das suas sugestões de wiki. Mas em geral aprovei, pois mesmo com problemas eram excelentes pontos de partida - claramente você está dispensando bastante tempo e esforço nessa tarefa. Pretendo ainda contribuir editando e revendo vários desses conteúdos.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu vi uma que você rejeitou agora e tem um erro crasso mesmo. Dá uma entendimento totalmente errado do que é :) Eu ia acertar mas me confundi e mandei sem querer.

Answer (score 8):

Pra mim ambas as preocupações (tab "ativo" fora de controle, e nome do editor na lista/pergunta) são *non-issues*, mas tomei um tempo para buscar disucussões semelhantes no "Metão":

- [Should all answer edits make old questions look “active”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18793/177950)
- [Could we have the ability to mark a change as minor in questions or answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26483/177950)
- [Can trivial edits not bump the question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107528/177950)
- [Non-active edit button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145910/177950)
- [Feature request: Trivial-edit checkbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102499/177950)

Pelo volume de perguntas, nota-se que isse é sim um *issue* para muita gente. No começo estava pensando que seria uma forma de "abuso": ninguém prestou atenção na minha pergunta? faço uma edição trivial e bang! Lá está ela no topo da lista. Talvez seja até esse o motivo pelo qual edições triviais (ex.: uma única correção de erro gramatical, por exemplo) não são encorajadas. Já até estava pensando em trazer isso aqui pro debate.

No entanto, ao ver as respostas às perguntas linkadas, percebi que não estava prestando atenção ao outro lado da moeda: o que acontece se alguém **vandalizar** o site e suas edições **não aparecerem** na tab "ativo"? O dano que isso pode causar é bem maior, e a demora para agir dificulta pros moderadores conterem esse dano.

Há outras respostas e comentários interessantes lá, mas na minha opinião isso encerra a questão. Se houve atividade numa pergunta/resposta, ter mais olhos avaliando a mesma é mais benéfico do que permitir que ela ocorra por debaixo dos panos. E ter o nome da pessoa estampado na edição é um *plus* - pois desencoraja o vandalismo e outros atos de má-fé.

---

Quanto à **extensão** que uma edição precisa ter para não ser considerada "trivial", receio que não tenha muito a acrescentar... Eu não edito meus próprios posts para corrigir menos que 3 erros de digitação, e nem aprovo sugestões de edição igualmente triviais, mas se um usuário com plena permissão de edição quiser fazer isso - não tenho absolutamente nada contra!

E retag, se vale a pena ou não varia de caso a caso... Na minha opinião, o principal valor de um retag seria **chamar a atenção da sub-comunidade** que envolve aquela tag para boas perguntas ainda sem boa solução - de modo que ela não passe despercebida por aqueles que realmente podem contribuir com aquilo que mais sabem. Não sei se é bem esse o objetivo das tags, mas pessoalmente não vejo muito mais utilidade nelas não... (exceto quando estou "passando o olho" pela lista, para identificar perguntas destacadas por estarem nas minhas tags favoritas; se bem que tenho poucas tags marcadas como favoritas, então esse fator não é significativo pra mim)

Comment: Eu não tenho dúvida que isso é até um debate mais amplo e acho inacreditável que o sistema aceite isso normalmente e até agora ninguém achou que deveria resolver. tem maneiras de resolver os dois lados, mas não é a questão aqui, vamos deixar isso p/ o Metão. O que eu estou tentando fazer aqui com o retag e não deixar ficar "de qualquer jeito". Se tivesse feito antes, eu seria crucificado por ganhar reputação fazendo isso. terminado esse ajuste inicial, pretendo ficar de olho para ir acertando o que aparece, para deixar mais organizado. C/ a anuência da comunidade, claro.

Comment: As tags são muito importantes p/ indexação dos buscadores. E o conteúdos das wiki tags também vão trazer tráfego, por isso estou tão preocupado com essas coisas nesse momento.

Comment: A discussão do Minor Edit no "SOzão" tá me lembrando a do "pt ou br" aqui. Vários argumentos, mas nenhum deles justifica a decisão. A decisão "interna" parece já ter sido tomada independente da vontade da comunidade. De qualquer forma, eu também gostaria de minor edits, pois toda hora esbarro em coisinhas mínimas que se eu editar agora sei que vão gerar repúdio. Agora, por mais que a comunidade seja aberta (e o sistema MUITO bom), temos que entender que dono é quem manda, a gente gostando ou não (e nem sempre pra melhor)...

Comment: tem que tomar cuidado com isso ai:
"O que eu estou tentando fazer aqui com o retag e não deixar ficar "de qualquer jeito".

Comment: @mgibsonbr "No entanto, ao ver as respostas às perguntas linkadas, percebi que não estava prestando atenção ao outro lado da moeda: o que acontece se alguém vandalizar o site e suas edições não aparecerem na tab "ativo"? O dano que isso pode causar é bem maior, e a demora para agir dificulta pros moderadores conterem esse dano."

para isso tem como se "proteger"?? edições que distorcem do escopo?