# Como fazer edições massivas de tags?

Tags: debate, tags, edição

Criei uma tag nova ([jquery-select2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-select2)) motivado por uma [nova pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26841/ap%C3%B3s-sele%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-select2-como-preencher-automaticamente-campos-do-formul%C3%A1rio) após conferir que existem umas [<strike>20 outras</strike>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=select2) (ups, na verdade, [são 7](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=select2%20is%3Aq)) que envolvem essa biblioteca.

Vinte é bem diferente de sete, mas acho que isso não muda o espirito desta pergunta. Qual o melhor procedimento para editar várias perguntas para adicionar ou remover uma tag?

- Fazer o máximo possível de uma vez só
- Ir fazendo uma pequena quantidade a cada dia

No WordPress Developers a sugestão é fazer um lote razoável num horário de pouco movimento do site. Talvez sábado pudesse ser um bom dia também. O horário seria algo entre o fuso-horário americano e europeu.

A preocupação principal é não inundar a página principal com edições em lote feitas por um único usuário, como demonstrado na Q&A **[Edições em massa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357/201)**, onde temos estes dois trechos interessantes:

> Admito que deveria ter perguntado antes se eu poderia fazer tantas mudanças, mas na hora não me ocorreu, peço desculpas se causei algum transtorno, não foi minha intenção. Parei assim que fui contestado. Preferi fazer agora, sabia que mais tarde isso seria problemático e obviamente não pretendo e não acho que alguém deva fazer no futuro.
>   <sub>[bigown]</sub>

e

> E retag, se vale a pena ou não varia de caso a caso... Na minha opinião, o principal valor de um retag seria chamar a atenção da sub-comunidade que envolve aquela tag para boas perguntas ainda sem boa solução - de modo que ela não passe despercebida por aqueles que realmente podem contribuir com aquilo que mais sabem.
>   <sub>[mgibsonbr]</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ninguém deu bola para sua pergunta, talvez porque ela meio que já dá a resposta. Só postei para confirmar a sugestão que você postou. Não importa muito se vai tudo de uma vez ou aos poucos (eu prefiro de uma vez) o importante é escolher um dia e horário que vai atrapalhar pouco a organização da página inicial. Se possível tentar escolher por último os posts que são melhores para tentar deixar posts de qualidade inferior mais escondidos no final do processo (mas isso é um *plus*, nada muito necessário).

Comment: Eu "deixei pra amanhã" essa pergunta várias vezes... Complementando: quando é o caso de substituir ou mesclar tags, não deixem de trazer o assunto ao meta, pois os moderadores têm ferramentas que resolvem certos casos numa tacada só, sem influir na home do site.

Comment: big & @bfavaretto, pois sim, tinha no fundo da memória exatamente isso "pô, a solução está na pergunta"... valeu por trazer a questão de volta à tona.