# O que fazer com perguntas que podem parecer ser de desenvolvimento mas se revelam não ser?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Em perguntas como [Envio de email funciona localmente mas não em servidor remoto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2204/envio-de-email-funciona-localmente-mas-nao-em-servidor-remoto) em que até um código foi postado, mas o problema era de configuração do servidor ou da infraestrutura de rede onde ele funciona. Nenhum problema no código ou qualquer outra questão que envolvesse o desenvolvimento de software.

Muitas vezes vamos ter perguntas assim. O próprio autor achava que a pergunta era sobre programação, alguns usuários também achavam que era. Mas após analisar, se concluiu que não era programação. Em muitos casos o autor até obtém uma resposta.

Ok, o problema ocorreu enquanto estava se desenvolvendo um software, mas foi um problema no uso de outro recurso. Parece ser um problema de usuário. O problema foi considerado de desenvolvimento por alguns minutos, mas já não é mais.

Estabelecendo que não é problema de desenvolvimento, ele não é relevante para nosso site. **Há algum motivo para deixá-la aberta? O site ganha alguma coisa em deixá-la ativa?**

Perguntas na plataforma do Stack Exchange precisam sobreviver ao tempo. Elas precisam ser relevantes para outros desenvolvedores por um período longo.

Este seria um caso ligeiramente diferente do encontrado em [O que fazer com perguntas que apenas procuram "code review for typos"?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/514/o-que-fazer-com-perguntas-que-apenas-procuram-code-review-for-typos)? Ao invés de typo é algo que a pessoa esqueceu ou não sabia fazer fora do código ou da solução direta. É algo que ocorre mais em função da implantação do que do desenvolvimento em si.

O que fazer? Fechar a pergunta assim que for constatado que ela não faz parte do nosso foco? Algo mais?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Como a pergunta não está com a devida atenção que eu acho que deveria, vou dar uma resposta.

Já começo dizendo que concordo com a resposta do mgibsonbr quando ele diz que se a resposta é “entre em contato com o suporte do fornecedor”. Não importa se parecia ser um problema de programação. Quando for constatado que não é mais um problema do nosso escopo, a pergunta deve ser fechada. É simples assim. Não precisamos complicar.

## Como usar cada ferramenta adequadamente

Ela não deve ser excluída. Não devemos jogar pedras no autor e falar para ele nunca mais repetir isso aqui, porque o problema não é grave.

Precisamos entender como funcionam as ferramentas da nosso plataforma.

- Para problemas graves, a exclusão é o caminho. Postagens que causam problema para o site [não podem ficar visíveis](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/44/teoria-das-janelas-partidas).
- Para situações onde a pergunta não deve mais ter atividade relevante, o fechamento é o caminho. Fechamento mantem a pergunta visível e permite algumas interações. Ele é reversível se necessário.
- Quando alguém acha que de um tipo de pergunta não é relevante para o site, o voto é o caminho. Se ela está dentro do que se espera no site mas um membro individualmente não gosta desse tipo de pergunta, aí cada um usa sua consciência para decidir se deve receber algum voto destacando-a ou não.

Independente do gosto de cada um, precisamos estabelecer o que será feito em cada caso. Não importa o que for decidido, eu seguirei a recomendação da comunidade, mas precisamos definir qual é o comportamento desejado nesses casos.

Fechamento de perguntas no SE é usado para indicar que a pergunta já não é passível de certas manipulações. As pessoas precisam se acostumar com isso. Não podemos mudar as regras que foram definidas em toda a rede. Podemos estabelecer nossos critérios do que deve ser mantido aberto ou não. Mas se uma pergunta é ruim por qualquer motivo, ela deve ser fechada. Não podemos deixar de fazer por preocupação que os membros não vão gostar da decisão. Podemos nos preocupar em explicar o motivo, ensinar para os novos qual é o significado do fechamento. A maioria aceita isso muito bem e até ajudam no fechamento quando percebem como funciona.

Qualquer pessoa pode achar qualquer atitude da comunidade como punitiva. Isso vive acontecendo e muitas pessoas saem atirando contra o SE. Isso nunca prejudicou o site. A única coisa que podemos fazer é ensinar o porquê das atitudes, porque o fechamento não é uma punição para ele.

**Deixar de fazer o que deve ser feito não é a solução.**

Se uma pergunta não faz parte do nosso foco, ela deve ser fechada. Se houver algum motivo que ele volte ser *on-topic*, nós podemos reabri-la.

## Somos *help-desk*?

Não há má intenção do autor, claro. Mas quando a pergunta fica caracterizada como sendo um *help-desk*, mesmo que acidental, temos que deixar claro para todos que ela já não é o que esperamos lidar aqui. Ela ficará disponível para outras pessoas, até como mensagem que *help-desk* será fechado. Para saber que é um caso de suporte do fornecedor, uma resposta ou comentário foi dado e resolveu a questão. Como é algo específico para um usuário, temos que dar uma conclusão.

Fechamento não foi criado para necessariamente matar a pergunta no ninho. O maior motivo para existir o **fechamento é para dar conclusões para perguntas** que não são tão desejáveis no site. Não tão indesejáveis que mereça a sua exclusão. O fechamento é usado para não deixar pontas soltas.

Claro que podemos optar por aceitar esse tipo de pergunta como normais e que elas devem ficar abertas. Neste caso, por coerência, teremos que aceitar uma quantidade enorme de outras perguntas que normalmente hoje não são aceitas. Não vou fazer uma lista aqui, até porque farei em outro lugar.

## Portas abertas para outros tipos de pergunta

Por exemplo, a pergunta [Como adicionar campos adicionais a um infotipo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2124/como-adicionar-campos-adicionais-a-um-infotipo) foi fechada e logo depois dos fatos ocorridos com a pergunta que deu origem a este post, ela foi reaberta. Com toda razão. É um problema de configuração de um ERP plataforma. Ao invés de programar o funcionamento do software com código, isso é feito com uma interface GUI. E isso geralmente é feito pelo desenvolvedor já que uma mudança dessas tem severas implicações. É o trabalho de um desenvolvedor, trabalhando no software que ele customiza para seus usuários, trabalhando no deployment/configuration e não está sabendo como resolver. Ainda tem a vantagem de que podemos dar uma resposta adequada do que ele deve fazer, a resposta não é “procure seu fornecedor”. Se um problema no deployment/configuration de um script PHP foi aceito, essa pergunta também deve ser aceita. E a porta está aberta para muitas coisas.

A zona cinzenta do que é bom aqui e o que não é, fica enorme e difícil de administrar.

Se alguém quer que eu mude de ideia, é simples conseguir isto, mostre-me a disposição da comunidade em aceitar quase qualquer pergunta que possa beneficiar o desenvolvedor que vem aqui perguntar algo. Que não importa muito que o que ele está perguntando, está apenas indiretamente relacionado com desenvolvimento de software.

Acho que abre uma porta perigosa. Eu não quero fazer isso, mas consigo argumentar porque devemos aceitar perguntas do tipo “cartoon sobre programação” e porque ela é muito mais importante para o site do que uma pergunta que só ajuda uma pessoa.

Dá para decidir que a pergunta não é diretamente relacionada ao desenvolvimento de software em si de forma objetiva. Se tivermos problema em dizer isso, teremos problemas com tantas coisas que não poderemos decidir o que fechar. Para a alegria daqueles que acham que o site deve ser um *quase vale tudo*.

## Posso mudar de ideia

Até agora ninguém me convenceu que o site sairá ganhando alguma coisa com esse tipo de pergunta. E não acho que o benefício de **um** usuário seja um bom motivo para não fazer nada com a pergunta. Historicamente o SO não trabalha bem com perguntas muito específicas. E se não fecham todas, é mais por falha da comunidade do que uma postura oficial.

Quer outra forma de me fazer mudar de ideia? Me mostre que estou errado e que o SO oficialmente, e não acidentalmente, gosta de perguntas de *help-desk* individual que não são sobre programação. Ainda assim, se aceitar esse tipo de pergunta, outros tipos que beneficiam uma pessoa individualmente também terão que ser aceitas.

## Pergunta muito localizada

Quero lembrar que o exemplo é um caso claro de pergunta que não pode ser transposta para outra pessoa. E só estou propondo o fechamento de casos que a nossa solução, na verdade não soluciona nada.

- Qual a probabilidade de alguém com o exato mesmo problema buscar por informações e chegar nesse post?

  Ainda assim ela pode achar a pergunta, mesmo fechada.
- Qual a probabilidade da pessoa ler o que está na pergunta e dizer, “olha, meu problema é igual, então eu sei que eu devo falar com o suporte do meu fornecedor”?

  Ela vai abrir uma pergunta dizendo qual o problema dela, porque nunca é exatamente igual. Ela não precisa da pergunta antiga, apesar dela estar lá. Ninguém vai fechar essa pergunta como duplicada da outra a não ser que ambas ocorram em espaço muito curto e não tenha muitas perguntas sendo feitas.

  Isso vai acontecer e não há nada que possa ser feito. Ela não vai achar a solução pronta, mesmo que aconteça, o altamente improvável, que algo tão específico ajude duas pessoas.

## Qual o objetivo do Stack Exchange?

O mais importante é que uma pergunta como essa, não vai ensinar o desenvolvedor aprender algo lendo uma pergunta desse tipo.

**Parece haver um entendimento equivocado que o SE está no negócio dos fóruns. E esse tipo de pergunta é ótima para fóruns**. Fóruns foram criados para resolver problemas individuais. Não vamos tirar esse trabalho dos fóruns.

O SE não foi criado para tirar os fóruns do mercado (no máximo tirar o Exchange do hífen). O SE é um local para as pessoas aprenderem algo. Se uma pergunta não ensina algo para as pessoas, a pergunta deve ser fechada. Se ela atrapalha a vida das pessoas, ela deve ser excluída (o que não é o caso).

Este é um caso de **pergunta que ajuda um usuário. Legal! Mas ele fica melhor em um fórum**. Ela não ensina outras pessoas nada além de que você deve procurar o suporte do seu fornecedor **nesse** caso específico que não ocorrerá mais.

Este é o motivo do “cartoon favorito” não ser aceito, ele não ensina programadores serem melhores profissionais. Pessoalmente eu aprendo mais com o cartoon do que com uma pergunta assim.

O SE foi criado com regras mais estritas do que fóruns ou outros tipos de sites com regras mais permissivas. As pessoas precisam se acostumar com isso. É isso que faz a plataforma ser diferente. Se for para aceitar quase qualquer coisa, não precisamos de mais um site.
É claro que é muito difícil acertar sempre, mas isso não serve de justificativa para não ter regras restritivas.

## Conclusão

Eu dei minha opinião sobre o assunto. Se vamos usar esse critério para esse tipo de pergunta não cabe a mim, individualmente, definir.

Não importa qual seja a sua opinião, colabore, diga se concorda ou discorda, pode dizer com o voto nas respostas apresentadas.

Comment: Para mim o ponto mais importante é o objetivo do SE, e do nosso site. Se perguntar se a pergunta vai ajudar as pessoas (no plural) a aprender algo é um bom parâmetro para se decidir o que fechar e o que não fechar (ainda que seja um critério subjetivo, ainda é mais claro que se perguntar se a pergunta "faz da internet um lugar melhor").

Answer (score 6):

Eu considero a **interface com sistemas externos** a parte  mais difícil do meu trabalho. Sério! Todo projeto que pego, a primeiríssima coisa que faço é testar como meu sistema vai interagir com os sistemas de terceiros, pois considero esse o maior risco pro sucesso do projeto. Já aconteceu comigo uma vez do projeto inteiro estar caminhando bem, e na última hora tudo vir por água abaixo porque o meu colega que estava encarregado da integração interpretou mal a API, e a arquitetura do nosso sistema acabou ficando toda errada (consertamos, mas o projeto atrasou mais de um mês).

Eu até concordo que 99% das vezes o problema está no **meu código**, não na linguagem, biblioteca, framework, ambiente de execução, SO... Mas na prática, o nosso código interage com sistemas externos o tempo todo. Se eu encontrei problemas para usar a API de uma biblioteca externa, isso é problema de programação, certo? E se for uma API REST, deixa de ser? Mas e se no final os parâmetros da API estiverem corretos, o problema foi que eu invoquei a função de requisição errado, volta a ser problema de programação?

Na minha opinião, se for um caso bastante isolado - em que a ação correta é "contactar o suporte do fornecedor" - então essa pergunta não é bem-vinda aqui. Caso contrário, mesmo se se tratar de uma API de terceiros, ainda que relativamente obscura (i.e. não é só porque o Facebook é "famoso" que questões de integração com o Facebook são on-topic, mas questões de integração com uma rede social menor não seriam - desde é claro que a API seja pública, se for privada cai na questão do suporte mencionado acima), creio que pode ser perguntada aqui. No exemplo em questão, a solução era contactar o fornecedor, mas o problema era bastante genérico: uma aplicação que tenta mandar um e-mail, mas falhou porque faltaram alguns passos **comuns** porém não necessariamente de conhecimento comum 
(por iniciantes, por exemplo). É o tipo de coisa que pode se beneficiar da experiência de outros. Por mim, faz parte do nosso escopo.

Answer (score 3):

Se eu estou fazendo um programa e o mesmo não funciona como esperado, automaticamente é um problema de programação, mesmo se na verdade o erro não estivesse no programa.

Só para dar um exemplo que aconteceu comigo:

> Uma vez eu estava criando um programa que produzia uma imagem contendo uma textura em degradê. Para analisar se o degradê estava correto, eu tirava um screenshot dele e analisava no olhômetro ele com um zoom alto. O resultado é que apareciam artefatos quadriculados e retangulares no degradê. Fiquei um tempão tentando entender o que havia de errado e revi o código muitas vezes. Eu poderia ter postado isso no SO para ver se alguém me ajudaria a encontrar o problema.
>
> No final achei o problema: O monitor que eu estava usando estava zoado, com algum tipo de glitch estranho nas cores verdes. Isso ficou bem evidente ao ver vídeos no youtube cheios de artefatos.
>
> Agora, imagine se eu tivesse postado isso e alguém me respondesse "a sua textura degradê me parece estar perfeita, não vi nada de errado nela", seria uma resposta de grande ajuda.

Voltando ao tópico em questão, o autor inicialmente achava que tinha um problema de programação e após não conseguir resolvê-lo, postou-o no SOPT procurando ajuda. Ou seja: **Quando foi postada, era um problema de programação.** Se no final o problema não estava no código, isso não é motivo para fechar ou apagar a questão. Além disso, escrever programas para enviar um e-mail que seja recebido é algo bem difícil e pode falhar por milhões de motivos diferentes, e portanto este tipo de pergunta de certo será recorrente por aqui.

E mais, uma resposta do tipo "amigo, não há nada de errado no seu programa, o que ocorre é que blablabla..." é uma resposta válida para um problema que o autor pensou ser de programação e que muitos outros usuários pensariam a mesma coisa.

**Motivo para deixá-la aberta:** Por outro lado, alguém poderia acrescentar uma resposta: "Amigo, isso que você está fazendo só funciona em alguns casos X e Y. Se você fizer deste outro jeito vai funcionar bem melhor". Opa, magicamente voltou a ser um problema de programação! Mesmo que esta resposta seja tardia, e venha meses ou anos depois, pode ser que ajude a resolver o problema de outras pessoas que passem por situação semelhante e mesmo do autor original, que pode ter feito uma enorme gambi para tentar amenizar o problema.

Enfim, minha opinião é: Deixe a questão em paz. Se você acha que o código funciona e que o problema está em outro lugar, então poste uma resposta dizendo isso. Se o autor viu que de fato o código funcionava e o problema estava em outro lugar, então aceite a resposta que diz isso.

Quanto a parte em que você alega que:

> Perguntas na plataforma do Stack Exchange precisam sobreviver ao tempo. Elas precisam ser relevantes para outros desenvolvedores por um período longo.

Isso é uma meia-verdade. Julgar se uma pergunta será ou não relevante para outos desenvolvedores por um longo período é difícil. Se fosse exatamente assim, deveríamos fechar em massa milhões de questões no SO que estão sem atividade há anos. Assim, na verdade elas **não** precisam ser relevantes para outros desenvolvedores por um longo período, mas todos gostariam que fosse.

Na minha opinião, uma pergunta só deve ser fechada se ela tiver um problema muito grave, evidente e sem zonas cinzentas. No caso de fechar como descontextualizado, uma pergunta do tipo "como fazer biscoitos de chocolate?" é sem dúvida descontextualizado e deve ser fechado, mas uma do tipo "meu programa de enviar e-mails produz um erro" está pelo menos na zona cinzenta.

Comment: Editei a pergunta para dar ênfase ao que é mais importante e complementar alguns pontos importantes.

Comment: @bigown Complementei a minha resposta para abordar os pontos que você editou.

Comment: +1 Penso da mesma maneira, e não saberia argumentar melhor. =)

Comment: Vamos ver o que o pessoal acha sobre a opinião que "*elas não precisam ser relevantes para outros desenvolvedores por um longo período*". Isso vai contra tudo o que o SE definiu. E não acho que elas sejam tão cintas assim. Elas foram sobre programação, elas **não são** mais sobre programação. Pelo menos você é coerente em defender que não importa o estado dela ao longo do tempo. Discordo radicalmente, mas respeito sua posição bem definida. Se mudasse o foco para aceitar qualquer pergunta de IT, aí obviamente não teria discussão.

Comment: Cabe também notar que o SO original também aceita perguntas de infra, vide as tags: [heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heroku), [aws](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services), [gae](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-engine), entre outras.

Comment: @elias Esses são links relevantes. E acho que com eles você argumentou melhor :)

Comment: @bigown Note que argumento não é de que *as perguntas não precisam ser relevantes pra outros desenvolvedores por um longo período*, e sim de que **não é tão fácil/intuitivo** julgar quando ela será ou não relevante para os outros.

Comment: @elias Muitas coisas são difíceis de julgar. Omitir-se nesses casos pode ou não ser o melhor a fazer. Até porque, não tomar nenhuma decisão, já é uma decisão. Eu acho que essa linha de raciocínio não é o ideal para o site, a sua outra linha é melhor. Vamos aguardar outras opiniões.

Comment: @bigown Concordo em partes. Mas aguardar com paciência != omitir-se. Às vezes é bom conceder o benefício da dúvida, principalmente se tratando de um comportamento que ainda não está causando muita dor a ninguém -- como julgo ser nesse caso.

Comment: @elias Deixar um pergunta off-topic aberta é se omitir. Não entendi o que o resto tem a ver com o assunto discutido aqui.

Comment: Victor, que acha de alterar *"na verdade elas não precisam ser relevantes para outros desenvolvedores por um longo período"* para *"na verdade elas não precisam ser **imediatamente** relevantes para outros desenvolvedores por um longo período"*? Se entendi sua ideia corretamente, essa pequena edição ajudaria a deixar mais claro a posição e evitar confusão. (ou talvez, *patentemente* é mais apropriado?)

Comment: @bigown Eu pessoalmente julgo de uma forma bem simples: Exceto se houver um problema grotesco e gritante, deixa rolar. Você diz que ela é off-topic. Ok é sua opinião. Eu discordo de você, não acho que seja off-topic. Fechar uma questão, do meu ponto de vista é uma atitude punitiva e pesada, e se usado inadequadamente, vai prejudicar a comunidade. Qualquer coisa, se não gostou da pergunta, você ainda tem o botão de votar contra para usar como quiser.

Comment: @elias Na verdade, por mais desagradável e chato que isso venha a soar, realmente nenhuma pergunta tem a obrigação de ser relevante por um longo tempo. Dizer o contrário é ou se iludir com um mundo cor-de-rosa ou permitir que uma ditadura totalitária venha a surgir para forçar isso. Ela idealmente deveria ser relevante para outros ao longo do tempo, mas se não for, que seja enterrada na obscuridade atrás de milhares e milhares de páginas de outras questões e ninguém precisará fazer nada mesmo.

Comment: Eu entendi tudo isso e até concordo. Mas as pessoas vão ter que entender que no SE perguntas são fechadas, faz parte do processo normal. Quem não conseguir se adaptar a isso, não vai gostar daqui. Ou então talvez tenhamos que abrir uma discussão se devemos descaracterizar a plataforma e operar de uma forma que agrade que faz perguntas. Esses critérios que você está propondo não representa uma mudança pontual. A diferença que eu **acho** que a maioria pensa é que se a pergunta não é relevante ou tenha qualquer outro problema, ele deva ser fechada e não apenas esquecida.

Comment: @bigown Há dois problemas: 1. É difícil e subjetivo julgar se uma pergunta é relevante ou não, e acho que o benefício da dúvida é bom. Você acha, ok. Será que **todos** ou **quase todos** acham? Certamente que não, e sem consenso, que se deixe rolar. 2. Fechar perguntas é algo tão normal quanto a colocar criminosos na cadeia. Pode até ser normal, mas só ocorre porque há coisas erradas acontecendo. E é muito pior um inocente na cadeia do que um criminoso a solta.

Answer (score -2):

Eu como autor do tópico em questão vou elucidar as coisas, para que não fiquem "achando" que estão dentro da minha cabeça ;)
    Eu sabia desde do começo que não tinha nenhum erro no meu código, o que eu queria saber é se alguém tinha passado pelo mesmo problema já que o servidor utilizado é bem conhecido assim como a plataforma.
    Uma resposta foi bastante útil e me fez descobrir que o SMTP no servidor em questão não era mais liberado para novos usuários.
    Eu estava tentando fazer funcionar desde de ontem e imaginava que o problema poderia ser minhas configurações de postfix/cyrus, achava estranho porque já fiz isso em diversos servidores inclusive a uns meses atrás na mesma empresa empresa em que contratamos o cloud só que com outro cliente.
    Penso que meu problema pode ser de outras pessoas que acham que seus códigos não funcionam quando na verdade tem um bloqueio em sua conta.
Achei muito chato a forma como o tópico foi tratado por 1 membro(o autor desde tópico) mas nem vou mais discutir isso.

Comment: Daniel: entendo sua frustração, cara. Só note que ninguém está querendo "pegar" você. O pessoal fica bastante preocupado com o futuro do site, receia certos comportamentos que não são muito saudáveis, e às vezes as consequências desse receio acabam pegando meio mal. Mas não desanime, cara, bola pra frente! No fim, estamos aqui pra aprender juntos. =)

Comment: Eu entendo @elias te agradeço pela compreensão, mas eu achei muito chatas as insinuações, só dizer, não faz parte do scopo e pronto.
Mas enfim, problema resolvido, clientes novos tem que pedir liberação do SMTP

Comment: Não importa tanto o caso específico. Nós sempre pegamos um caso que aparece como exemplo para discutir o que fazer de forma generalizada. A pergunta foi só um exemplo. Não se preocupe com isso. Você esclareceu a situação e nenhum problema mais foi observado. Se você analisar *toda* cronologia dos eventos e todas as informações que estevam disponíveis, problemas estavam aparentes. Você mostrou o que estava ocorrendo e o problema foi resolvido. Eu fiz o que tinha que fazer com as informações que tinha. Me desculpe se te chateou, não foi a intenção mas a situação pedia uma ação.

Comment: Até porque (se eu entendi direito, ao menos foi o meu caso), o que chamou a atenção nao foi o Daniel, e sim os outros dois que simplesmente se cadastraram e puseram basicamente o nome da empresa nas 2 perguntas.