# O que fazer com perguntas que apenas procuram "code review for typos"?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Se uma pergunta tem código, já damos um crédito que ela provavelmente pertence ao nosso site, certo?

Mas muitas vezes, é só uma forma de pedir por um *code review*. Mas não qualquer *code review* com requisitos bem especificados. O requisito, muitas vezes implícito, é "cometi um erro de digitação ou tem algo errado que não estou vendo e preciso que alguém ache pra mim".

Um dos motivos de existir a razão "too localized" era justamente para evitar esse tipo de pergunta. è uma pergunta cujo problema só o usuário tem e só interessa a ele. É altamente improvável que outra pessoa tenha um problema semelhante e mais ainda que ache uma resposta procurando no SO por ter esquecido de um ";" ou trocou letras.

Mesmo que aceitemos *code review*, me parece que esse tipo de pergunta não é bom para nós. Provavelmente está fora do escopo do site. O que fazer? O que a comunidade pensa?

Comment: Relacionada no MSO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186366/how-to-flag-a-typo-question

Comment: Muito relevante (em inglês): http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186196/167534

Comment: Idem, ibidem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215587

Comment: Acho que "code review" e "for typos" não combinam, tanto que o [codereview.se] só aceita código funcionando.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No Stack Overflow em inglês tem até uma razão para fechar esse tipo de pergunta:

> This question was caused by a problem that can't be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was solved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Ou seja, um problema que não pode ser reproduzido ou que é apenas um erro de digitação (tão logo fique claro que se trata disso) é *off-topic* lá e acho que deve ser descontextualizado aqui.

Não é o fim do mundo fechar perguntas assim. Mas o texto acima mostra porque ela não é uma boa pergunta para o site e já falei sobre isso em diversos lugares.

Se for outro tipo de erro, até podemos deixar a pergunta aberta. Enquanto não fique claro que é um *typo*, não vamos mexer com a pergunta. Mas vamos dar uma conclusão para ela, fechando-a já que **possivelmente** não ajudará outros leitores. Leia o a citação acima.

Passa a mensagem correta de que não é uma pergunta que gostamos de ter aqui mas que ela não é grave o suficiente para excluí-la.

Nem sempre é fácil lidar com esse tipo de pergunta mas precisamos fazê-lo. E precisamos lidar desde o começo para não acontecer o mesmo que o SO que chegou em uma situação que não era mais administrável.

Answer (score 9):

Eu acredito que se foi um mero erro de digitação mesmo (por exemplo, se fosse o "Hots" no lugar de "Host" como também aconteceu na pergunta, o ideal seria fechar assim que o problema tivesse sido e resolvido para quem perguntou. Um erro de digitação não tem como ser útil para a comunidade nem a médio nem longo prazo, polui as buscas e  gasta tempo de todos da comunidade.

Pra quem já tem mais tempo de SO, há textos mais do que suficientes para se definir o que é ou não uma pergunta útil, e isto não é aleatório. Há um pouco de subjetividade, mas não é mero acaso. A força do SO está justamente nesse poder de ajuste e na capacidade dos membros fazerem sua "lição de casa" para manter o ambiente em ordem.

> Notar que não estou propondo "matar a pergunta no ninho", realmente até pode ser muito importante dar o tempo necessário para que o autor veja e confirme se foi isso mesmo. Depois disso, é evidente que não tem utilidade nenhuma largar o conteúdo no site, uma vez que o autor teve seu problema resolvido e estatiticamente seria absurdo achar que alguém vai ter exatamente o mesmo erro.

Para esse site aqui virar um "fórum", todo bagunçado e ineficaz como a maioria dos outros, basta que não tenhamos ação.

Answer (score 6):

Eu acredito que "a pergunta deve ser de utilidade também para outros" é um ideal inatingível, uma situação utópica que seria inviável de ser imposta em um site como o SO. Lendo o SOEN percebo que a grande maioria das perguntas deveria ser classificada como "too localized" - mas elas continuam sendo feitas, respondidas, ganhando upvotes e sendo mantidas abertas.

Em relação a *typos* (ou similares), se o compilador não pegou, se os métodos normais de depuração não resolveram, não vejo problema em postar aqui. Veja o exemplo da pergunta ["Loop infinito ao caminhar recursivamente pelos nodos do DOM"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1843/loop-infinito-ao-caminhar-recursivamente-pelos-nodos-do-dom): o problema estava na simples falta de um `var` - mas a sintaxe do código continuava válida sem ele, e a depuração complicada (pelo fato de ser um loop infinito - examinar o console, rodar o programa várias vezes, etc, não era uma tarefa fácil). A pergunta despertou o interesse das pessoas, e mesmo depois que a "simplicidade" do problema foi detectada a pergunta e as respostas ganharam vários upvotes.

Eu já excluí perguntas minhas no passado quando reparei se tratar de um erro bobo (aliás, essa semana mesmo fiz isso aqui). Outras, eu mesmo dei o primeiro voto pra fechar (não era tão ruim que merecesse remoção, mas não era boa). Na minha opinião, se a pergunta e/ou as respostas têm algum valor, podemos até fechá-las (se houver um critério apropriado para tal), mas não excluí-las. Somente se a qualidade for muito baixa - ou se o OP [não demonstrou qualquer esforço no processo de depuração](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/105/sobre-esforco-em-perguntas-no-estilo-como-fazer-x/121#121) (ver item 3) - é que elas devem ser excluídas.

Em suma, se o autor da pergunta demonstrou que não está somente "pedindo pra alguém fazer seu trabalho pra ele", e se as pessoas na comunidade decidiram dedicar tempo a ajudá-lo, não acho que nenhuma ação externa seja necessária.

Comment: esquecer var não é um typo, é erro mesmo; escrever vra seria um typo.

Answer (score 1):

A questão é: O autor da pergunta **sabe** que o problema que ele tem é um *typo*? Se ele souber e estiver perguntando "ei pessoal, aonde está o typo?", então realmente, a pergunta não pertence a este site, mas duvido muito que este tipo de coisa ocorra na prática.

Se por outro lado, o autor está fazendo um código em javascript para realizar um cálculo de taxa de juros compostas de uma aplicação financeira, e lá no meio surge um `NaN` ou um `undefined` para ferrar com tudo, e após várias xícaras de café ele não entende o que há de errado e vem postar aqui no SOPT, e 5 minutos depois alguém diz "ei, você está usando `taxaBaisca` mas atribuindo a `taxaBasica`", então perfeito, resolveu o problema do usuário que poderá economizar mais algumas xícaras de café e ainda ganhou de brinde um "accept" e um "upvote".

Comment: Respeito sua opinião e até se a maioria concordar com você, farei o mesmo, claro. Mas essa é fácil discordar. A experiência já mostro nos outros sites que esse tipo de pergunta é um dos maiores exemplos do que tem em outro sites que não faz a internet um local melhor. Claro que algumas pessoas podem gostar de responder isso, até porque gera reputação fácil. Mas os especialistas gostam de perguntas desafiadoras. E vendo esse tipo de pergunta eles costumam se afastar. O SO decidiu por isso e nunca se arrependeu. Vamos ver se o pessoal quer o contrário.

Comment: @bigown Na verdade eu acho que isso cai em uma zona cinzenta aonde o que vale é o bom-senso.

Comment: Concordo com você, mas precisamos estabelecer regras porque cada um tem seu próprio bom-senso. A comunidade tem que ter um caminho definido à seguir. Se deixar em aberto para cada um decidir o que fazer, teremos batalhas. Em última instância o moderador precisa de um diretriz de como agir em nome da comunidade.

Comment: @bigown Então, este é um tipo de comportamento que eu diria ainda não estar causando "dor" pra ninguém aqui. É o tipo de coisa que podemos decidir quando começarmos a ter problemas (e talvez com a participação de mais especialistas). [Não se preocupe com problemas que não existem ainda](http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/2/como-construir-o-site-que-voce-quer-ser-quando-crescer?cb=1). *Easy, man!* =)

Comment: @elias Que vale para todos os lados que se observa.

Comment: Em linhas gerais eu concordo com você, mas vou votar para fechar dependendo do tamanho do código. Acho que é obrigação de quem pergunta tentar restringir o problema a um trecho do código, se ele postar um código muito grande acompanhado de nada (ou quase) além de "qual é o problema do meu código", acho melhor fechar como "ampla demais" ou "não está claro..."

Comment: @bfavaretto +1 acho que eventualmente, vamos precisar de uma versão do http://sscce.org -- até lá, vamos ver o que rola.

Comment: @elias O Shog9 está propondo uma versão mais simples do sscce.org para o SO, acho que deveríamos seguir a mesma linha. Ver http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214955/can-we-create-a-help-center-topic-that-outlines-what-a-sscce-mwe-means-for-sta