# O que está acontecendo com uma pergunta já resolvida?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, razões-fechamento

A pergunta [Copiando registro da tabela nela mesma via vba](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2288/resolvido-copiando-registro-da-tabela-nela-mesma-via-vba) já foi fechada e está para ser excluída.

Não entendi bem qual o problema dela e gostaria dos que fecharam e querem excluí-la possam me ajudar a entender os critérios adotados.

Influenciou alguma coisa o autor ter respondido de forma equivocada?

Ou que ele não pôde voltar ao site para ver o que está acontecendo com a pergunta?

Havia alguma coisa que pudesse ser feito para não fechá-la? Tem algo que o autor pode fazer para salvá-la? E aí será será reaberta?

Porque é necessário excluí-la? Vale à pena não dar nem a chance de resolver o problema da pergunta?

Temos que fechar uma pergunta o mais rápido possível? Ela causa tanto dano ficando aberta até saber a situação exata?

Comment: Abri uma pergunta à parte para discutir se devemos ou não votar para fechar o mais rápido possível: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/537/quanto-tempo-devemos-esperar-antes-de-votar-para-fechar-um-pergunta

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<sup>Eu não faço parte da lista a quem esta pergunta esta dirigida, mas quero deixar a minha opinião:</sup>

### Sumario de acontecimentos

A pergunta foi colocada e pouco depois o autor deu conta do problema e, para evitar que outros utilizadores andassem a *perder tempo* com o que naquele momento era um falso problema, editou a pergunta e adicionou informação a dar conta que já tinha resolvido a questão.

Esta atitude ainda que incorreta mediante o funcionamento do site, é de louvar, pois ele podia ter-se "barimbado" para a questão e partido para outra.

### A grande falha

Existem duas grandes falhas em todo este processo

1. Parece que o utilizador não estava informado sobre o facto de que poderia responder a pergunta dele com a solução;
2. A pergunta foi fechada tão rápido que nem 1 hora de vida teve.

### Analise

Podemos discutir que a pergunta não devia ter sido editada com a solução, ou que o autor sabia que podia responder mas não respondeu porque o problema já era um falso problema, ou simplesmente porque não tinha tempo no momento para lidar com isto, ou porque a resposta não "casava" com a pergunta na sua forma atual...

Fosse qual fosse, a pensar que seria bom ficar com a pergunta, para facilitar, deixei um comentário que graciosamente recebeu 3 concordâncias a dizer:

> Não edites a pergunta para aplicar a resposta... Sugiro que alteres a pergunta de forma a que fique com o código necessário para se notar o erro que descobriste e posteriormente a isso, colocas uma resposta dando conta da solução, marcando a mesma como a resposta correcta, fechando assim este assunto. :)

A ideia era que mais tarde o autor o visse e agisse de acordo com a sua vontade, quer fazendo o que sugeri quer tomando uma outra ação.

No entanto a pergunta acabou fechada, e já com votos para ser excluída! (*Terá sido o próprio autor a votar para exclusão? Se sim, porque?*)

### Parecer

A minha opinião e que caso seja grosseiramente uma pergunta fora do foro do site, a mesma deve ser mantida por um período grande o suficiente para existir oportunidade de ser rescrita ou complementada para ficar aceite. Neste caso em particular, era só esperar que o autor pegasse no texto e o colocasse como resposta.

### Futuro

No futuro, sugiro que as perguntas não sejam votadas para fechar no decorrer das primeiras horas de terem sido colocadas (*ler o Parecer*), podem ser comentadas com informação que ajude os autores a melhorarem ou alterarem o conteúdo das mesmas para que fiquem validas aos olhos de todos e mediante a FAQ.

Dar oportunidade para que as coisas se possam compor é a melhor e mais saudável forma do site crescer.

Comment: Concordo 100%. Ele não poderia ter votado contra ou acertar a resposta porque ele não voltou ao site desde os acontecimentos iniciais. Isso precisa ser avaliado. Claro que se ficar um tempo sem aparecer, algo pode ser feito. Mas o pior é que tenho visto muitos casos de 2 pesos, 2 medidas.

Comment: @bigown Só vim aqui deixar esta resposta porque quando deixei o comentário tinha acabado de entrar para um reunião, e agora que saí da mesma, tinha ido ver como estava o assunto. Constatei que estava fechada e tinha o teu link para aqui! Honestamente tinha pensado "se o autor não reverteu a edição, trato eu disso e respondo em _wiki da comunidade_".

Comment: Mais do que perfeito! Achei que ninguém ia falar isso :) A "malta" :D não está sabendo usar as ferramentas que têm.

Comment: "Terá sido o próprio autor a votar para exclusão?" Não, fui eu quem o fiz. Quando vi a pergunta: a) ela já estava fechada, não dando chance do autor responder a si próprio; b) estava com vários votos contra, mostrando que a comunidade não se interessa pela pergunta; c) deixá-la aberta não beneficia o autor (pois ele próprio já achou a resposta, e era um erro "bobo"); d) deixá-la aberta não beneficia a comunidade (idem). Não vi razão pra mantê-la, por isso votei pra excluir, mesmo inseguro da decisão (entretanto, sabendo que se a comunidade discordasse dessa ação, meu voto seria "vencido"...).

Answer (score 7):

O que realmente eu queria ver aqui são as pessoas que não costumam participar do meta explicar ou debater o que está acontecendo e ver que algumas coisas estão sendo atropeladas. Eu sabia que provavelmente não aconteceria.

Mas tinha outro objetivo de reserva. Mostrar que algumas pessoas estão agindo sem se preocupar muito com o que está acontecendo e não entendendo bem o uso das ferramentas.

Parte do que eu queria ver, já aconteceu: [Quanto tempo esperar antes de votar para fechar uma pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/537/quanto-tempo-devemos-esperar-antes-de-votar-para-fechar-um-pergunta).

Nós que somos mais ativos temos que tomar um cuidado por nós, e por quem não entende como usar as ferramentas disponíveis no site. Se essas pessoas usam sem pensar, quem é experiente tem que pensar mais vezes antes de dar o último empurrão no erro.

Não estou querendo fazer crítica à ninguém. Erros acontecem, eu já cometi vários e vou cometer muitos outros. Critico um pouco, sim, quem age sem saber como agir. Mas mais porque eles não vêm aqui para ver como estamos organizando o site e até influenciar na decisão. Eu sei que é ilusão achar que as pessoas virão, mas se elas não vêm, devem se conter ou ser contidas.

Já escrevi antes e repito: precisamos tentar salvar uma pergunta sempre que possível. Precisamos esperar para ver se o autor ajuda. Ele não pode ajudar se não estiver no site. Isso tem que ser verificado. Chega um ponto que podemos considerar a pergunta abandonada, mesmo que temporariamente.

## Um pouco do uso das ferramentas do site

As diversas ferramentas para lidar com as perguntas tem o propósito de resolver problemas causados por ela ou para dar uma conclusão quando ela pede uma.

A **aceitação** é ótima para o autor dizer "ok, essa resposta resolveu meu problema, era isso que eu precisava". Ela não é definitiva e de fato ainda se espera que outras pessoas possam interagir com a pergunta, podendo inclusive alguém postar uma resposta melhor ainda e a aceitação mudar.

Os **votos**, favoráveis ou contrários, indicam se a pergunta é relevante ou não para o site, para outros membros. Indica se **você** quer que ela seja mais destacada ou não. Perguntas mal formuladas eventualmente podem receber votos negativos.

A não ser que a pergunta faça um pouco de mal ao site e quando acho que ela não deveria ser destacada, eu não costumo votar negativamente. Até já abusei disso no começo porque muitas pessoas foram no embalo de perguntar qualquer coisa banal e eu fui no embalo de votar negativamente. Não faço mais. De qualquer forma, apesar de existir alguns critérios que todos deveriam usar, o voto é individual e depende da consciência de cada um. Veja mais em [Vote cedo, vote frequentemente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente).

A **exclusão** da pergunta só deve ser usada em casos realmente críticos, onde esteja causando mal ou tenha um erro onde sua exclusão é mais benéfica que a permanência da pergunta. Inclui aí a exclusão do próprio autor. Já vi algumas exclusões que não precisavam ser feitas. Mas quando o autor deseja excluir, não podemos fazer nada além de respeitar a sua decisão. Existe o caso da limpeza periódica também, mas isso é outra questão.

**Fechamento** dá conclusão para perguntas que podem ficar no site mas que não devem receber interação significativas, a não ser que se consiga achar um motivo para reabri-la. Fechamento não é punição para ninguém. É conclusão. Em muitos casos, depois de se obter uma resposta.

- Perguntas **duplicadas exatamente** devem ser fechadas tão logo seja caracterizada a duplicação. Mas cuidado. Precisa ser exatamente duplicado. Não nas mesmas palavras, mas precisa estar perguntando algo que essencialmente é igual e gerará respostas iguais. Se você tem dúvidas, não vote para fechar. Se alguém já votou e você acha que a pergunta escolhida não é bem a original que foi duplicada, escolha outra. Não vá no embalo de quem já votou. Especialmente, não vote porque alguém votou. Antes de votar para fechar, você tem que ter certeza. Não vote sem fazer uma análise criteriosa da pergunta. Se você errar na avaliação, paciência, não somos perfeitos. Mas se alguém errar porque foi displicente, temos um problema.

  O fechamento significa que a pergunta permanecerá no site como um apontador para a pergunta original onde tem uma resposta. Uma pergunta não pode ser duplicada de outra que não tem uma resposta ou que só teve uma resposta depois que a pergunta duplicada teve a sua, aí está invertido, mesmo se uma pergunta igual foi feita depois, se ela recebeu uma resposta primeiro, a pergunta anterior é que deve ser fechada, já que ela não tem resposta.

  É benéfico manter a pergunta fechada no site.

  Você precisa entender do assunto ou estar muito claro para analisar a duplicação.
- Perguntas **descontextualizadas** costumam ser as mais fáceis. Mas ainda não definimos totalmente o que queremos ou não aqui. O que não está certo que deve ser *off-topic* não deve ser fechado por enquanto. Mas já vimos casos que não são tão fáceis.

  Se afaste dos casos onde você não entende bem o assunto e não pode dizer claramente se faz parte de um dos nossos tópicos.

  Perguntas muito localizadas, que só atendem quem perguntou (apesar de não existir mais uma opção só para isso), são *off-topic*, elas sempre foram e sempre serão (?). Perguntas que só atendem quem perguntou são boas para fóruns e não para a plataforma SE. Note que são poucas perguntas que são realmente localizadas.

  Perguntas descontextualizadas podem ser fechadas tão logo elas sejam classificadas assim. Não antes de ficar claro que está fora do nosso escopo.
- Perguntas onde **não está claro que o que está perguntando** não precisam ser fechadas de imediato. Podemos esperar um pouco e pedir para o autor ajudar a entender melhor o problema para que possamos ajudar ele. Já falei um pouco sobre isso antes. Vamos tentar salvar a pergunta e só depois de ficar certo que não há o que fazer, vamos fechá-la.

  Se o autor não se esforçou muito mas há quem consiga responder razoavelmente aquilo, então a pergunta era clara. Talvez precise de uma edição para melhorá-la um pouco. Mas se ela tem uma boa resposta, ela era clara.

  Se precisa escrever muita coisa para responder, o problema da pergunta é outro.

  Perguntas especulativas ou que exigem poderes mediúnicos para responder são candidatas para fechamento, após a tentativa de salvação.

  Não gosto de perguntas do tipo “faça isso para mim” mas nem sempre é o caso da pergunta que parecia ser isso, especialmente quando quem avalia não entende bem do assunto dela. Por isso vamos ter calma antes de usar esse argumento para fechar a pergunta. Até porque ela será forte candidata a exclusão em limpeza periódica.

  Perguntas onde a pessoa não se esforça em dizer qual é o problema, seja em edição na pergunta, seja em comentários, poluem o site **no longo prazo**.
- Perguntas **muito amplas** devem ser usadas depois de tentativa de alertar o autor que:

  a) ele está pedindo algo que produzirá múltiplas respostas e só a combinação delas produzirá uma resposta realmente útil (e não dá para aceitar todas elas);

  b) são muitas perguntas em uma (não conta perguntas complementares e relacionadas diretamente com a pergunta principal, também não queremos 10 perguntas separadas que gerem respostas que apenas complementam as outras);

  c) precisa pelo menos de um capítulo de um livro para respondê-la.

  Novamente, se você não conhece bem o assunto, e em alguns casos até quando conhece, você pode ter dificuldade em avaliar com clareza se a pergunta é realmente ampla. Já vimos muitos casos de erros. Vamos com muita calma para votar para fechar uma pergunta potencialmente muito ampla. Precisamos ter certeza e precisamos dar uma chance ao autor. Muitas vezes o autor apenas não sabe como fazer a pergunta. Isso não é desculpa para manter a pergunta aberta, mas também não precisamos crucificá-lo um minuto após ele postá-la. Não vamos punir o autor. Muitas vezes, um exemplo simples resolve o problema do autor.
- Perguntas **baseadas principalmente em opiniões** já foram tratadas várias vezes aqui no site. É tipo de pergunta que não torna a internet melhor. Gera confusão e deve ser fechada rápido. Mas não tão rápido que não dê para ser cauteloso na aplicação do fechamento.

  Tenha certeza antes de votar. Pense se não é você que não está conseguindo ver a objetividade da pergunta ou que as opiniões postadas podem ser úteis, relevantes, significativas e razoavelmente corretas. Nem todas as perguntas subjetivas são ruins. Veja mais em [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective).

Se essas diretrizes não são suficientes ou estão gerando problemas, podemos rever como agir.

## Pergunta específica

Essa pergunta estava ruim, merecia algum tratamento mas precisava de calma. Agora está com uma solução boa. Adorei a solução adotada para resolver o problema da resposta.

Ainda resta a dúvida se ela está no nosso escopo. Eu acho que ela é muito localizada e deve ser fechada. Deixe sua opinião onde esse assunto está sendo debatido: [O que fazer com perguntas que apenas procuram "code review for typos"?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/514/o-que-fazer-com-perguntas-que-apenas-procuram-code-review-for-typos). Preciso saber para dar meu voto de fechamento de acordo com as diretrizes da comunidade.

Aí vem outro problema. Como ela foi mal vista, ela deve ser excluída? Se for só para ajudar o autor na reputação, não. Ele deve arcar com as consequências do que fez. Pelo menos essa é a posição que eu teria oficialmente. Mas se acharem que deve-se fazer isso porque a pessoa ainda não sabe como lidar com o problema. Posso até concordar.

Cometi algum erro nas explicações? Provavelmente. Deixe seu comentário.

Gostaria de ter feito um trabalho melhor nos meus posts das perguntas desta semana mas estou um pouco sem tempo para me dedicar tudo o que precisa.

Bola pra frente.

Answer (score 5):

Não posso falar pelos outros que votaram para fechar, mas vou explicar minhas ações (eu dei o quinto voto, que efetivamente fechou a pergunta).

#### Minha avaliação da pergunta

Olhando a lista de perguntas do site, essa me saltou aos olhos por conter "Resolvido" no título. Abri o link com a intenção de editá-la. Sabia que no mínimo eu mexeria no título, mas naturalmente fui ler a pergunta toda antes de fazer qualquer coisa. Quando vi a resposta incluída na própria pergunta, decidi que iria removê-la de lá, e postá-la como uma resposta, marcada como wiki da comunidade e atribuída ao autor da pergunta.

#### Por que achei que deveria fechá-la

Ao ler a pergunta, percebi que o problema havia sido um erro de sintaxe, que não estava sequer explicado (posteriormente, relendo a pergunta com mais atenção, percebi qual foi o motivo do erro, mas isso não está claro no texto do autor). Considerei que a pergunta, pelo menos com as informações que continha, não iria ajudar mais ninguém que viesse a ter um problema similar. Era localizada demais. Aliás, isso pode ter motivado o voto para excluir, que não é meu.

#### A trapalhada

Nesse momento me apressei, e dei o voto de fechamento sem atinar para o fato de que a pergunta seria fechada imediatamente (só faltava um voto), e que isso me impediria de inserir a resposta como resposta, como eu havia planejado. [Cheguei a editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/2288/5) a pergunta removendo a resposta, e só me dei conta da bobagem que havia feito quando já era tarde demais. Acabei revertendo minha edição e deixando por isso mesmo.

#### Minha avaliação neste momento

Considerando os questionamentos do bigown e a análise do Zuul, agora vejo que agi rápido demais. A edição eu faria de qualquer maneira, considerando que a pergunta estava naquele estado já há algumas horas, e não poderia continuar assim. Mas eu poderia ter adicionado um comentário pedindo ao autor que elaborasse mais a pergunta e a resposta, e mantido a pergunta aberta aguardando um retorno dele.

#### O remendo

Com base em tudo isso, estou votando para reabrir. Se ela continuar fechada, posso até sinalizar para um moderador reabrir com força bruta. Com a pergunta reaberta, o autor terá outra chance de torná-la adequada ao site.

#### No dia seguinte...

A pergunta foi reaberta. Acabo de editá-la para separar a pergunta da resposta. Vejamos se o autor fará mais alguma intervenção nas próximas horas. Caso não faça, a pergunta volta a ser candidata a fechamento, ou até exclusão, pois como está continua sendo localizada demais, de pouca utilidade para outras pessoas além do próprio autor.

Comment: Eu teria feito o mesmo se a pergunta estivesse aberta, mas quando a vi já estava fechada... Vou votar também para reabrir - ainda que tenha minhas dúvidas se essa pergunta acrescenta alguma coisa pra alguém (incluindo o autor).

Comment: A resposta foi bastante completa e não terei tempo para comentar adequadamente agora. Já esperava ela e sem me alongar digo que erros acontecem o tempo todo, é normal. Meu objetivo na verdade era qualquer um de dois: Trazer as pessoas para discutir e achar um ponto comum de como agir porque os últimos dias parece que todo mundo resolveu aprontar alguma e eu comecei tudo; OU expor um problema potencialmente ocorrendo. Algumas pessoas **podem** estar usando as ferramentas sem assumir a responsabilidade do que estão fazendo. O resumo de tudo. Vamos com calma e vamos discutir tudo que gere dúvidas

Comment: Depois volto para comentar mais e vou falar mais genericamente do problema em outros lugares assim que tiver tempo. Darei minha posição sobre o problema da pergunta também.