# Quanto tempo esperar antes de votar para fechar uma pergunta?

Tags: debate, fechamento

Em *[O que está acontecendo com uma pergunta já resolvida?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/533)* há o seguinte questionamento:

> Temos que fechar uma pergunta o mais rápido possível?

#### Como funciona no Stack Overflow em inglês

No SO em inglês, a orientação é que sim, deve-se fechar uma pergunta com problemas o mais rápido possível, para que ela não acumule respostas. E os motivos de não deverem acumular respostas seriam:

- Se a pergunta é *off-topic* ou subjetiva, as respostas também seriam
- Se a pergunta não é clara, as respostas necessariamente seriam baseadas em suposições

Em suma, fechando a pergunta o mais rápido possível, ela tem mais chance de ser mantida "estéril" até que seja melhorada por edição, ou excluída. Isso reduziria a chance de "contaminação" do site.

O lado ruim disso é que muita gente fica contrariada ou se sente ofendida com o fechamento de suas perguntas, abandonando-as como estão. Tenho certeza que muitas perguntas poderiam ter sido editadas e melhoradas se mantidas abertas por mais tempo, e acabam largadas pelo autor, que muitas vezes nem retorna mais ao site. A resposta dos defensores do fechamento rápido é que fechamento não é definitivo, e a pergunta sempre pode ser reaberta – por conta disso, durante um tempo a pergunta é marcada como "em suspenso", e não "fechada".

#### Como poderia funcionar aqui?

Answer (score 12):

Na minha opinião, a menos que a decisão seja "óbvia" (i.e. de cara se vê que a pergunta não tem salvação, então é fechar e esquecer o assunto), só devemos tomar uma ação se estivermos dispostos a **ir até o fim**. Explico:

Nem sempre temos disposição pra ficar horas e horas no site, manter abertas as abas com as perguntas já visitadas (ou guardá-las na memória e/ou nos favoritos, para voltar a elas depois), olhar com cuidado como a pergunta "evolui", etc. Isso cria uma situação de *lose-lose*:

- Se você votou pra fechar e foi embora, não poderá reabrir a pergunta caso ela seja melhorada;
- Se você **não votou** pra fechar e foi embora, uma pergunta "ruim" permanecerá aberta [caso ela não seja melhorada posteriormente].

Isso não é problema se há um grupo significativo de usuários com o hábito de ficar "de olho" na fila de análise: basta a pergunta ser editada após fechada, e poderá ser reaberta com o número certo de votos. Mas nesse momento, ainda não temos tal número. No futuro, a situação pode mudar.

Nesse meio tempo, o que é pior: falsos positivos ou falsos negativos? Na minha opinião, é melhor uma pergunta ruim aberta do que uma boa fechada. Ao fechar, se limita muito as **ações** que os usuários "comuns" podem ter em relação a ela - em especial tentar respondê-la*. Isso pode ser uma coisa boa nas duas situaçõs citadas, mas a menos que os usuários estejam **se comportando dessa forma de fato**, não há razão para tentar "se resolver um problema que não existe".

Em suma, minha resposta é **não**, não devemos fechar uma pergunta o mais rapidamente possível. Quanto ao "tempo ideal" para fechar, costumo observar o comportamento do próprio autor - se ele esteve online por tempo suficiente para ver os comentários [pedindo que a pergunta seja aprimorada] e não tomou nenhuma atitude, é sinal de que não vai fazer nada sem um "empurrãozinho extra"... Ter a pergunta fechada, na minha opinião, pode ser o incentivo que falta para ele melhorar a pergunta (pois se não o fizer, não receberá a resposta que tanto precisa; e se não precisa tanto assim, não era uma pergunta importante mesmo, e não vai fazer tanta falta).

* P.S. Duas coisas que eu detesto: quando fiquei "horas" formulando a resposta perfeita, mas na hora de postar a) o sistema não deixa, pois a pergunta foi fechada; b) o autor [aceitou uma resposta muito rápido](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/494/devemos-ter-pressa-ao-aceitar-respostas) e foi embora... Um exemplo de (a) em que eu "escapei por pouco" foi [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/312/como-prevenir-ataques-do-tipo-sql-injection) - que insito: está muita ampla no seu formato atual, mas não só é "salvável" como também uma boa resposta independe de se considerar uma linguagem/plataforma específica.

Answer (score 6):

<sup>**Editado para clarificar o conteúdo! Ver original se relevante.**</sup>

Tens dois pressupostos na pergunta, os quais carecem de alguma forma uma estratégia independente:

> 1. Existam critérios claros para o fechamento de perguntas neste site (embora eles ainda não tenham sido claramente definidos).
> 2. A pergunta que você está considerando fechar possa ser transformada em uma pergunta adequada se o autor complementar as informações postadas (ele pode ser questionado em comentários). Pense em perguntas do tipo não é claro o que você está perguntando.

### Pressupondo que a pergunta cai fora do que é aceite no site

Se a pergunta está claramente fora dos critérios de aceitação, penso que:

1. Deixar comentário e link para a área da FAQ que fala sobre o problema encontrado na pergunta que a classifica como *off-topic*;
2. Dar um período breve (até 4 horas) para que o autor a possa refazer ou eliminar;
3. Ao final desse tempo se a pergunta continua inválida, sem ter sido editada nem pelo autor nem por nenhum outro utilizador, Fechar!

### Pressupondo que a pergunta cai dentro dos tipos "pouco claro" ou "amplo demais"

Se a pergunta não está clara o suficiente ou aborda um assunto demasiado amplo, votar para Fechar é a última coisa a fazer. A mesma após revista pode tornar-se numa excelente questão, pelo que sugiro:

- Enquanto estamos no Beta Privado, como temos poucos utilizadores, o que se traduz em poucas perguntas, esperar 24 horas antes de agir para colocar a pergunta em "Suspenso".
- Enquanto no Beta mas já aberto ao público, o número de utilizadores vai aumentar, e com eles o número de perguntas, tornando-se quase que impossível andar a monitorizar as perguntas candidatas a fecho, pelo que sugiro um período de 12 horas até iniciar votação para "suspender" a pergunta.
- Quando o site sair das fases Beta, este assunto terá que ser avaliado pois existem diversos factores que são cruciais para a definição de um período de carência até iniciar a "suspensão" de uma pergunta. Todavia, esperaria um máximo de 6 horas até iniciar a "suspensão" da mesma.

---

<sup>Mais tarde irei adicionar alguns detalhes úteis para este assunto com base nas ferramentas que o sistemas no disponibiliza para gerir estes casos.</sup>

Comment: Excelente. Apoio 100%.

Answer (score 6):

Quando surgiu o primeiro caso para aplicar a regra do período de carência que uma pergunta deve ter antes de sair todo mundo fechando, conforme o Zuul colocou na sua resposta, eu vi que tem um complicador que não me deixou confortável.

Algumas razões de fechamento podem ser aplicadas mais rapído, veja mais em [O que está acontecendo com uma pergunta já resolvida?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/533/o-que-esta-acontecendo-com-uma-pergunta-ja-resolvida/562#562).

O Zuul não chegou falar das perguntas duplicadas. Acho que esse tipo de pergunta pode ser fechada imediatamente. E também não falou das perguntas baseadas em opiniões. Acho que deve-se usar o mesmo critério de "muito ampla" ou "não clara". Dependendo do jeito que a pergunta é escrita ela pode ficar mais objetiva ou pedir informações relevantes ao invés de opiniões puras.

Nos casos que a pergunta pode ser salva, tem apenas uma adaptação que eu gostaria de propor.

Os tempos são bons, porém, eu acho que a regra deve ser mais ampla.

O ponto central dessa espera é **dar a oportunidade ao autor da pergunta esclarecer o que ele está querendo e possivelmente editá-la**.

Se ele não está no site, ele não sabe o que está acontecendo, não vamos tomar nenhuma ação com a pergunta.

Vamos verificar no perfil dele se ainda está no site, ou quando você tiver a oportunidade de passar pela pegunta de novo e ver se ele já voltou e pôde ver os comentários deixados na pergunta e ainda se ele tomou alguma ação que a salve.

Se ele voltou, provavelmente viu (não tem porque não ver) os comentários, e não fez nada, nem deu um comentário avisando que ele entendeu e está providenciando uma informação melhor, porque precisamos esperar para fechar a pergunta ruim?

Acho que devemos usar um dos dois seguintes critérios para liberar o voto de fechamento de uma pergunta, **o que ocorrer primeiro**:

1. O usuário **teve a oportunidade** de ver que as pessoas não estão gostando da forma que ele colocou a pergunta e não fez nada;
2. Passou 24hs<sup>1</sup> e ele não retornou ao site, então não podemos ter paciência eterna.

Ninguém precisa votar imediatamente, mas não vejo motivo para segurar ninguém quando o usuário teve a oportunidade de melhorar.

O que acham, não funciona melhor?

---

<sup>1. Ou outros períodos menores de acordo com a tabela do Zuul.</sup>

Comment: Eu gosto da flexibilidade do prazo, contanto que o usuário tenha tido tempo de ver os comentários e atuar de acordo. Porém sempre há o risco de alguém pensar que 60 segundos depois do "visto em" do perfil, a pessoa já teve a sua chance.

Comment: É verdade, mas acho que quem está lendo isso aqui, entendeu o espírito. Se não entendeu, **tem que dar tempo para o autor ver o problema na sua pergunta** :)