# Devemos aceitar perguntas que pedem definição de termos?

Tags: debate, perguntas, big-7, wikis-de-tags, escopo-do-site

Temos que analisar o problema sob várias aspectos.

Perguntas que pedem definição produzirão respostas muitos fáceis de achar, muito mesmo. Até em português. Provavelmente a melhor resposta será um verbete da Wikipedia.

Mas o objetivo dos sites SE é ter uma das perguntas como primeiro link de qualquer busca do Google. Não importa se a resposta já existe em outro lugar. Esse lugar deve ir para a segunda posição.

Definições podem ser muito amplas para nosso site e muitas vezes ficam mais adequadas na wiki da tag do assunto.

Ao invés de simplesmente perguntar o que é MVC, porque não ler a definição na tag?

O que fazer com perguntas desse tipo? Aceitar normalmente já que a pergunta é legítima?

Ou devemos deixar responder e depois fechá-las recomendando que alguém, possivelmente o autor da melhor resposta, copie o conteúdo para a wiki da tag?

Fechar logo porque é *off-topic* e não permitir que nem ocorra a tentativa de resposta?

Claro que perguntas mais específicas que podem dar melhor entendimento ao assunto do termo não serão problema. A dúvida é se é benéfico termos essas perguntas abertas ou se manter essas informações na wiki da tag é suficiente e não justifica a manutenção da pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A parte mais interessante que motiva discordância penso ser este paragrafo aqui:

> Mas o objetivo dos sites SE é ter uma das perguntas como primeiro link de qualquer busca do Google. Não importa se a resposta já existe em outro lugar. Esse lugar deve ir para a segunda posição.

Se o objectivo é que o primeiro lugar nos resultados de pesquisa deste [**exemplo**](https://www.google.com/search?q=own#q=bigown), ou [**este**](https://www.google.com/search?q=MVC) fiquem vinculados à SE, efectivamente terá que existir conteúdo na SE para que isso aconteça.

No primeiro exemplo dado, o conteúdo nem é uma pergunta nem é uma resposta, mas no entanto, o primeiro resultado da pesquisa está vinculado à SE.

### Fica então a questão:

A definição de um termo presente na descrição da tag é suficiente para essa vinculação acontecer?

- **Sim!**

  Ok, então não precisamos de perguntas a perguntar por definições de termos, pelo que, podemos fechar as mesmas quanto antes para não gerarem respostas e tornar todo o processo de eliminação moroso.
- **Não!**

  Ok, então precisamos de perguntas à procura da definição de termos, mas na sua essência essas perguntas já são *off-topic*, o que nos leva novamente à tomada de acção de fechar as mesmas.

Efectivamente a resposta para esta tua questão está na própria questão!

Para não andarmos às voltas e acabarmos sempre na tomada de acção de "Fechar" a pergunta que procurar por definições, temos que garantir que a mesma é específica o suficiente para trazer algo de útil agora e no futuro aos demais utilizadores do site:

> Claro que perguntas mais específicas que podem dar melhor entendimento ao assunto do termo não serão problema.

Deixar responder para depois fechar, não vai resultar! Conforme sugeriste:

> Ou devemos deixar responder e depois fechá-las recomendando que alguém, possivelmente o autor da melhor resposta, copie o conteúdo para a wiki da tag?

Isto porque muita coisa tem que bater certo para que os [processos de eliminação automáticos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) não venham a eliminar a mesma.

---

## Sugestão

A minha sugestão é simples, aplicar as [regras de espera](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/537/quanto-tempo-esperar-antes-de-votar-para-fechar-um-pergunta) e fazer o que for possível para "aproveitar" a pergunta, tornando-a *específica o suficiente*, pois a [definição de uma tag](https://www.google.com/search?q=php) certamente não é suficiente para que os primeiros resultados de pesquisa fiquem vinculados à SE!

Fora isso, sou da opinião que mais vale não vir parar tudo à SE (particularmente este site SOPT), do que o site estar cheio de perguntas que como nos exemplos dados no decorrer da resposta, uma simples pesquisa no Google dá-nos o mesmo:

> Provavelmente a melhor resposta será um verbete da Wikipedia.

[image: _Oh God, noooo..._]

Comment: Fiz a pergunta de forma provocativa tentando mostrar que qualquer decisão tem vários lados :)

Comment: @bigown Dá para ver ;) e o assunto é pertinente, embora propicio a muita discussão! :) _(o que é bom.)_