# Como tratar perguntas que dão um arquivo inteiro, ao invés de um trecho de código?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Todos os dias eu vejo ao menos um par de perguntas desse tipo. Se o título não deixou claro, vou exemplificar (em C# que é minha linguagem mais fluente):

---

Pergunta tipo arquivo:

> Estou com um problema na minha função de soma. Qual é o problema?

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.LINQ;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MeuProjeto.MeuFramework.MinhaOutraNamespace;

namespace MeuProjeto.MeuFramework.MinhaNamespace;
{
    public class MinhaClasseQueSoma
    {
        public double NumeroUm { get; set; }
        public double NumeroDois { get; set; }

        public MinhaClasseQueSoma()
        {
            NumeroUm = NumeroDois = 0;
        }

        public MinhaClasseQueSoma(double numeroUm, double numeroDois)
        {
            NumeroUm = numeroUm;
            NumeroDois = numeroDois;
        }

        public double Somar()
        {
            return NumeroUm + " mais " + NumeroDois;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Pergunta tipo trecho de código:

> Estou com um problema na minha função de soma. Qual é o problema?

```
public class MinhaClasseQueSoma
{
    public double NumeroUm { get; set; }
    public double NumeroDois { get; set; }

    public double Somar()
    {
        return NumeroUm + " mais " + NumeroDois;
    }
}
```

---

A pergunta tipo arquivo dá mais do que o dobro de código necessário. O trecho de código na pergunta tipo trecho dá só a informação suficiente, deixando o problema mais claro. E caso não fosse possível reproduzir o problema, alguém poderia comentar pedindo mais trechos de código específicos.

Notem que eu **não** estou reclamando de perguntas *longas*. Estou reclamando de perguntas **desnecessariamente** longas. Essas que têm um problema simples sendo expresso em 3 telas de pergunta, chegam a dar preguiça de ler e responder. Creio eu que estes sejam conteúdo ruim para o site. Se não for, por favor, me expliquem porquê.

No final, a pergunta é a seguinte: Qual deve ser o tratamento a essas perguntas desnecessariamente longas? Devemos editá-la, procurando aonde está o problema, ou devemos comentar pedindo para o "perguntante" colocar apenas o trecho aonde se encontra o problema? Ou simplesmente devemos deixá-la?

Comment: Sou a favor de pedir a quem pergunta que reduza o código ao mínimo necessário. Também acho correto editar a pergunta nesses casos.

Comment: No SO.com temos a cultura de pedir um [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), acho extremamente útil, talvez fosse legal tentar implantar uma ideia similar por aqui.

Comment: As duas perguntas do seu texto são ruins. Nenhuma delas explica o que está acontecendo com o código. Não me incomodaria se a pergunta fosse com o arquivo inteiro mas tivesse uma stacktrace ou uma explicação do que está dando errado.

Comment: Muitas vezes, os desenvolvedores iniciantes não possuem o discernimento correto sobre, qual é a parte do código relevante para o se entender o problema. Cabe a cada um orientar os usuários. O objetivo, além de tentar ajudar na resolução do problema,é também, ajudar a desenvolver melhor as questões.

Comment: Quase sempre: fechar como não clara, e pedir um [MCVE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (postei pra atualizar o link)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Qual deve ser o tratamento a essas perguntas desnecessariamente longas? Devemos editá-la, procurando aonde está o problema, ou devemos comentar pedindo para o "perguntante" colocar apenas o trecho aonde se encontra o problema? Ou simplesmente devemos deixá-la?

Eu acho que devemos comentar pedindo para que o autor reduza o código ao mínimo necessário para reproduzir o problema. Se ele nem tentar isso após [algum tempo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/537/quanto-tempo-esperar-antes-de-votar-para-fechar-um-pergunta), eu votaria para fechar como "não está claro..." ou "ampla demais". Claro que se alguém tiver paciência para ler, entender o problema, criar o código mínimo, e editar, ótimo, salvou a pergunta.

Se isso vier a se tornar um problema frequente no site, podemos ter um motivo de fechamento específico, como existe no SO.

Answer (score 2):

A meu ver, uma pergunta ou uma resposta longa é diferente de uma pergunta e uma resposta com muito código.

Reparem que uma pergunta/resposta que tenha muito código recebe um bloco `<pre>` com `max-height: 600px` e `overflow: auto` (que é convertido pra um scroll), justamente pra não ocupar muito espaço da tela com código. Ou seja, já houve essa procupação no engine gringo e que já foi resolvida muito bem.

Agora, tem perguntas e respostas com dezenas de milhares de palavras de trechos explicativos. Essas são bem complicadas de ler, tomam tempo e normalmente a resposta é muito prolixa.

Acho que vale a pena mais *recomendar* uma resposta sucinta do que propriamente *intervir* numa resposta longa. Naturalmente, respostas mais curtas e sucintas recebem mais upvotes porque vão direto ao ponto. No caso de respostas muito longas, acho que vale um pequeno comentário pedindo ao respondente que enxugue um pouco sua resposta.

Comment: Entendi que o foco desta pergunta são perguntas, e não respostas. Especificamente, perguntas do tipo "O que está errado com o meu código?", seguida de tripa de código. Coisa de help vampire.

Comment: Vale pra ambos. Só ver a maioria das perguntas em Java.