# O problema dos Vampiros de Ajuda

Tags: debate, proposta-para-faq

Como nos precaver e lidar com o problema dos [**Vampiros de Ajuda**](http://slash7.com/pages/vampires)?

Citação do artigo:

> Reconhecer Vampiros de Ajuda tem seus truques porque parecem uma pessoa comum. Porém, se analisarmos seu comportamento a partir das seguintes dicas, será mais fácil identificá-los em nossa área de trabalho:
>
> - Perguntam a mesma, e repetida, pergunta que outros perguntam (numa taxa de mais de uma por minuto)?
> - Carecem claramente da habilidade de perguntar ao todo-poderoso Google?
> - Se recusam a tomar o tempo mínimo para escrever uma pergunta específica e coerente?
> - Acreditam que ajudá-los vai ser a melhor coisa que acontece na sua vida?
> - Partem para a ofensiva como se **você** precisasse provar que eles precisam usar Ruby on Rails?
> - Esperam clara, óbvia e despreocupadamente que alguma pobre, bem-intencionada, pessoa faça toda a análise pra eles?
> - Você consegue afirmar que seu interesse é ter sua pergunta respondida tanto quanto ter alguém que faça o trabalho deles?

<sub>Inspirada em:</sub>

- <sup><sub><sup>(Meta.SOPT)</sup></sub></sup> [Esclarecer ou fazer o trabalho pelos outros?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1157/eslcarecer-ou-fazer-o-trabalho-pelos-outros)
- <sup><sub><sup>(Meta.SOPT)</sup></sub></sup> [Como tratar perguntas que dão um arquivo inteiro, ao invés de um trecho de código?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/788/201)

<sub>Tradução e adaptação de:</sub>

- <sup><sub><sup>(Meta.SO)</sup></sub></sup> [**The Help Vampire problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19665/185667)

[Retorne para o índice da FAQ](/q/699)

Comment: Fiz uma pesquisa meio rápida e não encontrei tradução para *Help Vampire*. Anyway, por favor, editem a pergunta e resposta sem piedade, meu Português tá meio enferrujado :)

Comment: Em uma discussão com o Gabe sobre isso há alguns meses, sugeri o termo "sanguessugas".

Comment: Tomei a liberdade de transformar a pergunta numa [meta-tag:proposta-para-faq].

Comment: Também sinalizei para transformar a pergunta em wiki, se discordar por favor manifeste-se aqui, ou sinalize também.

Comment: @bfavaretto, perfeito, de acordo com tudo.

Comment: "Reconhecer um Vampiro de Ajuda tem seus truques porque _parecem_ uma pessoa comum." Deveria ser **parece** pois concorda com "um Vampiro", não? Ou talvez, trocar "um Vampiro" por "Vampiros" já que quase todo o restante do texto está no plural.

Comment: @EMBarbosa, valeu pela revisão editorial, ajustado ;)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Do artigo referido:

> Perguntam a mesma, e repetida, pergunta que outros perguntam (numa taxa de mais de uma por minuto)?

- Vote para fechar como duplicata.
- Vote negativamente.
- Sinalize para atenção de moderadores se for realmente ruim.

> Carecem claramente da habilidade de perguntar ao todo-poderoso Google?

- Isso não é um problema aqui. Se a pergunta não está no SOPT e é relacionada com programação, é uma pergunta válida.
- O objetivo é que o primeiro resultado no Google seja um pergunta no SOPT.

> Se recusam a tomar o tempo mínimo para escrever uma pergunta específica e coerente?

- Vote negativamente.
- Vote para fechar se for realmente ruim.
- Alternativamente, se a pergunta tiver salvação, edite-a em algo compreensível.

> Acreditam que ajudá-los vai ser a melhor coisa que acontece na sua vida?

- Bom, você vai ganhar reputação por isso, não é uma maravilha?!

> Partem para a ofensiva como se **você** precisasse provar que eles precisam usar Ruby on Rails?

- Bom se ele não usa *RoR*, e você diz que ele deveria, a responsabilidade de provar isso é sua, não?

> Esperam clara, óbvia e despreocupadamente que alguma pobre, bem-intencionada, pessoa faça toda a análise pra eles?

- Ok, mas e se isso beneficia outras pessoas, quem se importa?
- Se você acha que é escandaloso, vote negativamente ou sinalize.

> Você consegue afirmar que seu interesse é ter sua pergunta respondida tanto quanto ter alguém que faça o trabalho deles?

- De todas formas, tente ensinar alguma coisa.
- Se é uma boa pergunta, quem se importa...
- Se é uma pergunta ruim, vote negativamente ou para fechar.