# Usuário com várias perguntas e não qualifica/aceita/comenta

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, status-recusado

Usuário que faz várias perguntas e não qualifica/aceita como resposta ou comenta, há alguma notificação que alerte o mesmo sobre este comportamento?

Comment: Creio que a única forma seja comentar na publicação, instruindo ele a escolher uma resposta ou mesmo dar *upvote*. Não há muito o que fazer, a ação depende do AP.

Comment: Relacionado: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/452/pergunta-j%C3%A1-tem-resposta-definida-por%C3%A9m-n%C3%A3o-foi-marcada-como-aceita

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Antigamente existia o [*accept-rate*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16721/177950) ("taxa de aceitação") que mostrava embaixo do perfil do usuário, em cada pergunta, que porcentagem de suas perguntas tinham uma resposta aceita. Isso criava uma certa "pressão dos colegas" para que os usuários aceitassem mais respostas - pois se um usuário tinha *accept-rate* zero, os outros apontavam pro fato e/ou deixavam de responder perguntas desse usuário (prevendo que seus esforços não seriam recompensados).

[image: Exemplo de accept rate baixo]

Eu gostava dessa funcionalidade, pois ajudava a manter a população de [vampiros](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1160/215) sob controle. Mas aparentemente a SE pensa o contrário, que isso estava encorajando os usuários a antagonizarem os novatos, e a partir de um certo ponto ela [parou de ser exibida](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136951/177950). Houve discussões acerca de [algum mecanismo alternativo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165179/177950), mas que eu saiba isso nunca foi pra frente...

Se a questão for notificar o usuário de que ele não está se comportando da melhor forma, a [proposta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136959/177950) de exibir esse *accept-rate* (pois internamente ele ainda existe) não em público, mas **apenas pro autor da pergunta**, seria uma solução aceitável. Assim evita-se o *bullying*, mas ao mesmo tempo fica um alerta pro usuário de que um dos seus "indicadores" está baixo (e pelo princípio da gamificação isso deve encorajá-lo a trabalhar nisso, se ele for do tipo que dá atenção a esse tipo de coisa).

(Muito embora eu pessoalmente pense que o ideal seria continuar exibindo-o, mesmo que restrito a determinado nível de participação; pois se uma das premissas do modelo do Stack Exchange é que usuários mais experientes podem ajudar na moderação, creio que pode-se confiar que os mesmos entenderão a importância de ser receptivo, e que mostrar a eles o *accept-rate* não seria por demais danoso.)

Comment: Concordo, algo como a reputação mínima para ver a quantidade de up/downvotes.