# Como contribuir com o SO sendo iniciante

Tags: debate

Imagino que minha situação se assemelha à muitas pessoas que acessam SO.
Já tive algum contato com programação, mas decidi me dedicar à ela propriamente dita quando meu trabalho me "forçou". 
Sempre me interessei na verdade, mas precisava do famoso "empurrãozinho".

Gosto muito da maneira que as pessoas discutem e respondem perguntas dos mais variados tipos e queria saber, em nome dos iniciantes, como poderíamos contribuir para o SO.

Críticas e comentários são bem vindos.

Answer (score 24):

Olá, Felipe, seja bem vindo!

Abrir uma pergunta no Meta aos 8 pontos de reputação indica claramente que você se interessa pelo funcionamento do sistema e preciso tirar o chapéu pra isso, olé!

O que digo a seguir se refere ao site principal e aqui ao Meta.
O único que se espera, depois que já frequenta há algum tempo, é que você tenha lido o que foi discutido anteriormente antes de abrir um novo tópico.

Estudar os temas que te interessam já é uma grande contribuição, pois vai aprendendo como funciona o sistema e contribui com *views* e ao marcar tópicos como favoritos.

Logo depois disso é votar. A partir dos 15 pontos já pode votar positivamente. O voto positivo quer dizer "obrigado" e que a pergunta e/ou resposta te ajudaram a resolver um problema e/ou a aumentar seu conhecimento.

Para fazer um *bootstrap* na sua reputação, até os dois mil pontos, pode sugerir edições, cada edição aprovada te dará 2 pontos de reputação. Vendo a qualidade da sua redação nesta pergunta tenho certeza que sua contribuição será extremamente valiosa para corrigir o português ruim de vários colegas programadores e deixar nosso conteúdo claro e limpo para quem vier depois procurando solução para seu problema.

Aos 125 pontos já vai poder votar negativamente e isso também é valorizado pois ajuda a separar o joio do trigo. Pessoalmente, prefiro ajudar quem mostra esforço do que um [vampiro de ajuda](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160/o-problema-dos-vampiros-de-ajuda?s=2%7C0.3260). Se meus colegas já deram -1 sei que vou ver um post problemático.

**Pode sugerir edições sem medo**. A idéia é deixar os títulos mais claros, remover ruído do texto ("obrigado", "oi", "tudo bem", "e aí galera") e formatar o *post* para deixá-lo o mais claro possível. Se for uma pergunta não toque o código a não ser para limpar linhas em branco ou identar código que está grotesco. Nas respostas, não toque o código a não ser que saiba exatamente o que está fazendo. Fora isso, pode editar sem perdão lembrando de escrever um resumo de edição conciso e coerente.

Confira os posts aqui do Meta dentro da tag [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), especialmente os das tags [edição](/questions/tagged/edi%c3%a7%c3%a3o), [título](/questions/tagged/t%c3%adtulo) e [formatação](/questions/tagged/formata%c3%a7%c3%a3o). Confira também [**Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/201). Depois disso pode ir no site principal editar qualquer coisa que precisar um *upgrade*.

Ok, até agora foi tudo gramática e estilo.
Ao navegar seus temas de interesse vai encontrar respostas que dirá "puxa, que bem explicado". E também "nossa, formatação e explicação excelentes". E logo, "opa, de novo essa mesma pessoa". Pode copiar o estilo à vontade dando uma olhada no Markdown e usando isso como base para desenvolver seu próprio estilo de respostas. Responder é o que vai levar sua reputação nas nuvens, afinar sua redação técnica e aumentar, e muito, seu conhecimento sobre o tema em questão.

RESUMINDO:

- edite o que quiser como se não houvesse amanhã;
- responda tudo que lhe parecer de interesse e que sirva para aumentar seu próprio *know-how*.

Comment: O incentivo à edição sem limites é para gente que preza a boa redação, senão não, não edite; responda e ganhe muitos mais pontos.

Comment: Esclarecedor. Espero que mais pessoas possam ter acesso à essas informações antes de se adentrarem ao meta. Obrigado.

Comment: Bom, acho que não tem muito jeito e que o visitante normal quer encontrar solução pro seu problema e pronto... Se o sistema funciona assim ou assado, azar, o que interessa é que funcione e que alguém me ajude a resolver meu pepino. A questão é que, muito espertamente, os criadores do Stack encontraram o jeito de fazer com que profissionais e aficcionados batam ponto, dia sim, dia não; fiquem de olho na reputação, editem no melhor estilo Wikipedia e façam parte do processo de decisão de como o site funciona. *["E la nave va"*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087188/)