# Como eu posso ajudar a comunidade? Preciso ser moderador para isso?

Tags: suporte, faq, comportamento, comunidade, moderação

> Estamos em tempos de eleição para moderador. Gosto muito do Stack
> Overflow, já obtive várias respostas aqui! Será que devo me candidatar
> para ser moderador ♦ e então ajudar a comunidade? E se eu não for
> eleito, vou ter que esperar até a próxima eleição para tentar ajudar
> novamente?

Apesar da citação acima ser uma situação hipotética, esse pensamento pode ser relativamente comum aos novatos, e é por isso que estou fazendo essa pergunta.

As coisas não são tão claras para quem está entrando na rede agora e algumas dúvidas parecidas já se passaram na minha cabeça conforme fui aprendendo sobre o SO:

- O que eu posso fazer para ajudar a comunidade do Stack Overflow em Português?
- Preciso ser muito bom e responder todas as perguntas que conseguir?
- Preciso ser moderador ♦ e só então poder ajudar a comunidade?
- Preciso de uma reputação alta para ter muitos privilégios e só então poder ajudar a comunidade?

[Retornar para o índice da FAQ](/q/699)

Comment: Relacionado: [Como contribuir com o SO sendo iniciante](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4348/100416)

Comment: A citação é real ou é uma citação hipotética? Só pra dar um contexto, nada errado com as duas coisas. A iniciativa é boa só estou na dúvida se a *tag* de suporte é a melhor.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, parabéns! Espero que, se você está lendo isso, é porque de fato tem interesse em retribuir à comunidade toda ajuda que recebeu por aqui.

**Todos podem ajudar a comunidade.** Não importa a reputação, se é moderador diamante ♦ ou não, se está por aqui há 10 dias ou 5 anos. Uma comunidade é sempre feita pelos seus membros, e aqui vai uma lista das principais coisas que você pode fazer:

### De acordo com a Reputação

Veja a página de [privilégios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) para acompanhar seu progresso sobre os privilégios que você possui.

#### Reputação >= 1

Você acabou de chegar ao Stack Overflow, e por isso possui uma reputação baixa. Existem alguns modos de aumentar a sua reputação (veja [Como aumentar a minha Reputação?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5050/100416)). Não deixe de ler o [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/100416), você pode ter dúvidas que já possuem uma resposta no FAQ.

- **Perguntar e responder**

A principal maneira de aumentar sua reputação é através das perguntas e respostas, então é importante que você saiba como fazer boas perguntas (veja na [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) - ou como **não** fazer perguntas ([Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/100416)) - e dar boas respostas ([Como ser um usuário mais dedicado no Stack Overflow?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4329/100416)).

Boas perguntas e boas respostas provavelmente terão votos positivos, e com isso você ganhará reputação (10 pontos de reputação por voto). Uma resposta marcada como solução também te dá mais pontos (15 pontos de reputação).

Dedique um tempo para entender como o SO funciona ([Guia de sobrevivência do SOpt - Versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/100416)) e como fazer boas perguntas e respostas antes de tentar fazê-las. Não esqueça de fazer o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour).

E não pense que as perguntas e respostas são apenas para conseguir mais reputação, elas são a parte mais importante daqui. Provavelmente é por causa delas que você conheceu o Stack Overflow e resolveu criar uma conta.

- **Sugerir edição**

Você pode sugerir uma edição em publicações, e essa sugestão irá para uma fila de análise. Se a edição for aprovada por dois usuários qualificados ou pelo autor da publicação, você ganhará 2 pontos de reputação. As edições devem ser feitas para tornar a publicação mais clara ou arrumar as tags da pergunta, leia a [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing) para mais informações.

- **Aceitar uma resposta**

Você pode marcar uma resposta para a sua pergunta como **aceita**. Assim, o usuário que respondeu ganhará os 15 pontos de reputação e você ganhará 2 pontos de reputação. Caso a resposta aceita seja sua, você não receberá pontos por isso. [Dê uma olhada no FAQ](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) para saber como e em quais circunstâncias aceitar uma resposta e porque isso é importante.

#### Reputação >= 15

Além de poder continuar fazendo o que foi dito acima, você ganhou novos privilégios.

- **Votar a favor**

[Os votos são a segunda coisa mais importante para os sites da rede](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/159/100416), a primeira são as perguntas e respostas, como dito anteriormente.

Receber um voto positivo traz uma sensação boa. Alguém investiu tempo lendo a sua pergunta/resposta, gostou e votou positivamente para dar mais destaque à ela. Retribua: quando ver uma boa resposta, vote; quando ver uma boa pergunta, vote.

Além disso, os votos servem como uma indicação rápida sobre a qualidade do conteúdo, para todos os visitantes futuros do site. Então não vote só porque gostou de algo (não use votos como um *like* das redes sociais), avalie se os aspectos técnicos estão corretos, se a solução é realmente boa e correta, etc. Lembre-se que o site prioriza a qualidade.

- **Sinalizar**

Você pode sinalizar publicações. Com o tempo você sinalizará melhor, mas é importante fazer uso desse privilégio. Ler a [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) deve deixar mais claro as situações que uma publicação deve ser sinalizada para que seja fechada ou apagada.

#### Reputação >= 50

- **Comentar**

Mais um privilégio: você pode [comentar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) em qualquer publicação. Agora você pode pedir esclarecimentos do autor da publicação, fazer críticas construtivas e adicionar informações relevantes.

Você também pode fazer uso dos [Comentários enlatados para situações comuns](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/707/100416). Usuários novos tendem a cometer erros comuns, e os comentários enlatados existem para essas situações.

#### Reputação >= 125

- **Votar contra**

Tão importante quanto votar a favor, é votar **contra**, e agora você pode fazê-lo! Se você leu os links indicados anteriormente, sabe distinguir uma publicação boa de uma ruim, e use os votos para indicar isso. Novamente, faço referência ao [Vote cedo, vote frequentemente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/159/100416).

#### Reputação >= 500

- **Filas de análise**

Você pode acessar as filas de análise de [Primeiras publicações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) ([*Como analisar a fila de Primeiras publicações?*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-posts)) e [Respostas tardias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers) ([*Como analisar a fila de Respostas tardias?*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/review-late-answers)).

Ao analisar uma publicação você pode fazer o que já podia fazer antes: sinalizar, votar a favor, votar contra e/ou deixar um comentário. Isso é importante para ajudar a remover o conteúdo ruim do Stack Overflow, deixando o site mais limpo.

#### Reputação >= 2.000

- **Edição**

Agora você pode editar as publicações sem precisar de aprovação. Faça um bom uso desse privilégio, continue editando e melhorando as publicações :)

- **Mais filas de análise**

Você pode acessar as filas de análise de [Publicações de baixa qualidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) ([*Como analisar a fila de Publicações de baixa qualidade?*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality)) e [Edições sugeridas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits) ([*Como analisar a fila de Edições sugeridas?*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/review-suggested-edits)).

A fila de *publicações de baixa qualidade* é similar às filas que você possuía acesso: se a publicação for de baixa qualidade, você sinalizará de acordo. Na fila de *edições sugeridas* você avaliará sugestões de edição de usuários, podendo aceitá-las, recusá-las ou melhorá-las.

#### Reputação >= 3.000

- **Votar para fechar ou reabrir**

De maneira geral, ao encontrar uma pergunta que sinalizaria para fechar, agora você pode *votar para fechar*, e caso seja spam ou ofensivo, você continua com a sinalização como faria antes. Veja mais detalhes em [Como minha sinalização deve mudar quando eu puder votar para fechar?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/3154) (em inglês).

O voto para reabrir é similar. Se acredita que a pergunta deve ser reaberta porque uma edição tornou-a válida, por exemplo, vote para reabrir :)

- **Mais filas de análise**

Você pode acessar as filas de análise de [Votos para fechar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close) ([*Como analisar a fila de Votos para fechar?*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/review-close)) e [Votos para reabrir](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen) ([*Como analisar a fila de Votos para reabrir?*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/review-reopen)). O processo é similar às filas anteriores e ao que foi dito acima.

#### Reputação >= 10.000

- **Acesso à ferramentas de moderação**

Conforme dito na [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), você pode fazer algumas coisas extras como: ver posts removidos; votar para remover ou restaurar uma pergunta; acessar ferramentas de moderação; editar tags *inline*.

Diversas estatísticas (citadas na Central de Ajuda) estão disponíveis nas ferramentas de moderação, então seja criativo com o uso delas e veja como isso pode te ajudar a cooperar ainda mais com a comunidade do que você já estava cooperando até agora.

#### Reputação >= 20.000

- **Usuário confiável**

Agora você pode fazer coisas como votar para excluir respostas negativadas; votar para cancelar exclusão de respostas; votar para excluir perguntas com -3 ou inferior; e editar wikis de tags sem precisar de aprovação. Veja mais detalhes na [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).

### Outras formas

#### Tradução

Qualquer usuário pode sugerir traduções de frases e isso também é uma forma de ajudar a comunidade. Talvez você já tenha se deparado com alguma frase em inglês no site, e você pode ajudar a corrigir isso! Dê uma lida em [Como ajudar quem traduz o site?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4764/100416) e acesse o site [Traducir](https://pt.traducir.win). Mais detalhes sobre essa plataforma podem ser encontrados em [Estamos mudando para o Traducir.win para as traduções da interface](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7515/100416).

#### Presença no Meta

[Você precisa de 5 pontos de reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) para isso, mas dificilmente entenderá a comunidade a ponto de conseguir usar o Meta perguntando e respondendo com menos de 5 de reputação, por isso deixei esse tópico separado.

Existem FAQs, manuais, os comentários enlatados, sugestões, são diversas formas de cooperar com a comunidade pelo Meta.

#### Moderador diamante ♦

Se você não fez nem metade do que está citado acima, *talvez* você não precise se tornar um moderador diamante ♦, certo? Existem **muitas** formas de ajudar a comunidade sem ter o ♦ ao lado do seu nome.

Para se candidatar a moderador você precisa de [300 pontos de reputação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3883/100416), mas o mesmo raciocínio usado para o Meta vale aqui. Leia [Diferença de Moderador ♦ para Usuário Confiável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3963/100416) para entender os *super poderes* de um moderador ♦ e perceba que você não precisa de tudo isso para começar a ajudar a comunidade, mas que de fato o ♦ pode ser um próximo passo.