# Muitas perguntas estão sendo fechadas sem critério?

Tags: debate, razões-fechamento

Parece existir no site muitos votos para fechar do tipo "maria-vai-com-as-outras".

Há a **impressão** que alguns usuários votam em tudo o que entra na fila de análise para fechamento. Em geral as mesmas pessoas votam para fechar perguntas que alguém considerou problemática antes. Eles não costumam iniciar a votação (embora aconteça também), eles **parecem** entender que se uma pessoa achou que devo fechar, ela está certa e merece um empurrão.

Muitas vezes isso produz um resultado equivocado. Se todos os votos fossem criteriosos, até não seria problema.

Não sei o que leva a isso, possivelmente um *badge-hunting*. Ou um entendimento errado de como funciona o fechamento. Ou ainda que o SOpt é o SO.

Comment: Eu não sei qual o critério de alguns usuários, mas eu sempre vejo o motivo que levou a alguém querer fechar, e com isso leio a pergunta e vejo se o motivo faz sentido, se não faz deixo aberto, se faz, fecho de acordo com o motivo. Agora se falta 1 voto para o encerramento, será que compensa ficar analisando a fundo a questão? Eu vejo superficialmente e dou o ultimo voto, talvez tivesse que ler de forma mais critica, mas com 4 votos em um único motivo, difícil estarem errados.

Comment: @PauloMaciel Eu discordo. Vejo o último voto como a última oportunidade de desfazer um possível erro e não como um voto "obrigatório" de concordância com os demais. Esse é o voto que efetiva o fechamento e tem que ser **o mais bem analisado de todos os votos**. Por outro lado, o primeiro voto deveria ser apenas como uma sugestão, para fazer a questão ir para a fila de análise. Mas parece não ser o caso.

Comment: Bom, a discussão é válida realmente, pois ficou claro que os votos anteriores influem nos votantes, o que não deveria acontecer. Isto significa que se não aparecesse que há votos anteriores, o comportamento das pessoas mudaria? Acredito que voto deva ser individual, senão não precisaria dos 5. Bastariam os 4 primeiros.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal realmente isso não acontece e acho difícil acontecer, a cada dia SOPT tem mais usuários. Efeito cascata existe em qualquer lugar, você acaba seguindo a maioria e as vezes sem muito critério. Por outro lado tem como reabrir uma questão caso tenha sido fechada por equivoco, não vejo outra solução para este problema, talvez ocultar a quantidade de votos para fechar? Não sei.

Comment: @PauloMaciel Eu vejo solução para o problema. São **poucas pessoas** que estão votando em tudo o que aparece na fila de análise sem analisar o conteúdo. Não são muitas! Todo mundo sabe que não deve fazer isso e quem faz sabe que faz. Eu abri este debate justamente para alertar essas pessoas que elas estão abusando do sistema quando elas votam porque outros votaram antes. As pessoas gostam de fechar coisas, nem sempre se consegue 5 votos para reabrir. Mas mesmo que consiga, você realmente acha que um usuário não deve se preocupar em cometer um injustiça deliberada porque pode ser desfeita?

Comment: @bigown concordo que tem que haver critério ao fechar uma questão, isso não há dúvidas, mas a probabilidade de estar cometendo equivoco ao dar o voto de minerva é bem baixa. O usuário que se sentir prejudicado pode vir ao meta discutir o seu problema quanto ao fechamento de uma questão, eu mesmo já fiz isso quando fecharam uma questão que eu havia feito, a partir daí comecei a participar do meta. Acho que o problema principal está na forma como isso afeta novos usuários, pois poderão desistir ao ver sua pergunta fechada. Não tenho uma opinião sólida sobre o assunto, mas não vejo muita solução.

Comment: @PauloMaciel não é baixa e mesmo que seja, é uma forma de erro que não precisa ocorrer. Segundo o seu critério, não precisa de 5 pessoas avaliando a pergunta, só de 4. Porque vai atirar primeiro e perguntar depois? Porque a pessoa que se sentir prejudicada é que tem que resolver o problema causado por quem não tem critério? Sendo que a maioria das pessoas do site não sabe como se defender, não sabe que o meta existe. Já começa haver solução se você parar de usar seu voto para fechar o que está encaminhando para fechar. Pode não resolver, mas você já estará fazendo a sua parte.

Comment: @bigown se houvessem 10 votos para fechar uma questão, o efeito "cascata" seria ainda pior. Acho que uma saída para este problema seria ocultar a quantidade de votos e mostrar apenas qual o motivo que está em pauta, fazendo assim com que a pessoa que esteja avaliando seja mais criteriosa e não faça uma avaliação superficial baseada em quantidade de votos. Tem muitas questões que ao bater o olho já fica visível o problema, mas investigando mais a fundo pode ser que não exista, e esse é o problema da visão superficial, o que ocorre quando falta apenas 1 voto.

Comment: Talvez o sistema que deva ser melhorado, é complicado exigir um comportamento por parte dos usuários sem haver punição ou recompensa.

Comment: @PauloMaciel Teria que esconder da fila de análise porque algumas pessoas votam em qualquer coisa que esteja na fila de análise. Mas só de você parar de dar o voto de minerva porque "4 pessoas não podem estar erradas", já ajuda. Cada um tem que fazer a sua parte. Não adianta reclamar que os outros não vão fazer.

Comment: @bigown no mérito da questão isso não funciona na prática, posso parecer não fazer um uso "adequado" da análise ao não investigar a fundo a questão, ainda digo que isso é uma causa sem solução se não houver recursos do próprio site para coibir esse tipo de comportamento. Quantidade de votos remete aquela questão sobre se reputação influência ou não http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1200/ate-que-ponto-a-reputacao-contribui-para-a-comunidade-alem-dos-privilegios

Comment: @bigown cada voto é um ponto de confiança, e isso pode sim reduzir a qualidade da avaliação de quem dá o voto de minerva, não estou dizendo que isso é um comportamento intencional, mas um comportamento natural.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tem vários fatores em jogo aqui, vou falar um pouco sobre cada um deles.

### Comportamento de manada

Trata-se de um fenômeno bastante conhecido e estudado: os animais, incluindo os humanos, tendem a seguir o comportamento de um membro do grupo que toma a dianteira. Por exemplo, se um membro de uma manada sai correndo de repente, os outros tendem a fazer o mesmo, pois o comportamento do primeiro indivíduo pode indicar a aproximação de um predador. É um mecanismo de auto-defesa. Nos humanos a coisa ainda é mais complicada, pois envolve também o sentimento de pertencimento ao grupo. Para mais detalhes e exemplos, recomendo a leitura do [artigo da Wikipedia em inglês](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herd_behavior) sobre o assunto, mas o paralelo disso com o que ocorre no site é claro: um único voto para fechar funciona como uma um estopim, atraindo o surgimento de mais votos.

### A fila de análise é tendenciosa

Isso é verdadeiro em todas as filas de análise, não só na de fechar. Cada fila tem uma "ação padrão" representada pelo primeiro botão entre as opções. Na fila de votos para fechar, o primeiro botão (e o próprio nome da fila) incentivam o voto para fechar. Isso é um pouco subjetivo, mas essa ferramenta me passa a impressão de que foi feita mais para "fechar perguntas onde alguém já identificou problemas" do que para "avaliar se perguntas devem ser mantidas abertas". A distinção pode ser sutil, mas somada aos outros fatores que abordo aqui, só faz aumentar o problema.

### Falta de critérios claros para fechamento

A comunidade ainda não definiu regras claras para fechamento de perguntas, especialmente de perguntas *off-topic*, como já disseram o @Renan e o @Math (os demais motivos de fechamento, mesmo "baseada em opiniões", não causam tantos problemas). Infelizmente não vejo uma saída imediata para isso. A comunidade precisa continuar debatendo o assunto até chegar a algo próximo de um consenso (porque consenso total nunca vai haver, e toda regra será sempre sujeita a mudanças posteriores se a comunidade achar necessário). Uma das coisas que podemos fazer neste momento é verificar o histórico de perguntas fechadas, localizar erros e incoerências e discutir os casos mais graves aqui no meta. Outra é rever o que já discutimos antes, e debater se as respostas ainda são válidas. Por exemplo, em [Quanto tempo esperar antes de votar para fechar uma pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/537/quanto-tempo-esperar-antes-de-votar-para-fechar-um-pergunta), falou-se em esperar um tempo antes de votar para fechar, dando ao autor da pergunta chance de melhorar a explicação. Isso raramente é respeitado, e vemos perguntas "salváveis" sendo fechadas bem rapidamente. Tudo bem, a decisão pode ser continuar fazendo assim (como é feito no SO em inglês), mas não me parece que haja um consenso sobre o assunto.

### Falta de conhecimento

Muitas vezes a forma de uma pergunta pode enganar o analista. Por isso é muito importante **pular** as perguntas cujo assunto você não domina. Às vezes pode parecer ampla de demais, mas na verdade tem uma resposta simples.

### Falta de interesse pelo conteúdo

Esse é o pior caso, o dos *robo-reviewers*: gente que está mais interessada em ganhar medalhas no site do que em garantir que tenhamos conteúdos de qualidade. Esses tipos sempre existirão. Revisam os conteúdos sem prestar atenção ao conteúdo, seguindo o que os outros fizeram ou clicando na primeira opção que vê pela frente. É difícil identificar essas pessoas, pois nunca podemos ter certeza sobre as intenções dos revisores, exceto em casos muito gritantes. O sistema tem uma proteção mínima quanto a isso, as auditorias de revisão, mas acho que elas não estão ativadas no nosso site. E mesmo que estivessem, é um sistema que elege perguntas já fechadas baseado em heurística, o que provavelmente não funcionaria muito bem agora pois temos vários casos de perguntas fechadas que talvez devessem estar abertas (e vice-versa) – nem dá para afirmar isso com tanta certeza, dada a falta de critérios.

Por enquanto o que podemos fazer é sinalizar algum post do usuário e pedir para um moderador dar uma olhada. Só moderadores poderão tomar alguma atitude em relação a isso (como dar um toque por mensagem privada, ou mesmo suspender o usuário).

### Minha postura com a fila de fechamento

Eu tenho entrado mais na fila de fechamento ultimamente, mas pulo muitos itens e postergo a decisão em muitos casos. Antes disso, fiquei praticamente ausente dessa fila.

Isso foi proposital. Tenho participado de discussões sobre o foco do site desde o início, e percebi que é muito difícil julgar o que é *off-topic* enquanto não temos regras mais claras. Quando voto é porque para mim a pergunta é extremamente *off-topic*. Em caso de dúvida, prefiro me abster. Acho que mais usuários deveriam adotar essa mesma postura por enquanto.

Comment: Bem lembrando que o problema é em todas as formas de fechamento (não só off-topic) e em outras filas de análise. Até já tem outra discussão falando das pessoas que aprovam sugestões de edição sem ver o que foi escrito. Se entrou na fila, a pessoa vota. Acho que a questão de falta de critério  claro para fechamento de off-topic ou falta, para este debate, nem cabe, porque não estou querendo tratar dos erros nos votos e sim dos votos "maria-vai-com-as-outras", sejam eles certos ou não. Mesmo que o voto tenha sido acertado, se foi por sorte, o site perde.

Comment: Não dá pra separar o maria-vai-com-as-outras da falta de critério. O comportamento dos outros vai ter mais influência quando a pessoa não tem (a) critérios claros que sejam mais ou menos reconhecidos pela comunidade ou (b) uma opinião pessoal forte. O sistema dá as filas para as pessoas, o sistema as recompensa com medalhas. Não vou culpar as pessoas por usarem o que o sistema dá a elas, a não ser que sejam mal-intencionadas. E eu não tenho dados suficientes para julgar boa parte dos casos que vejo e discordo nas filas de análise.

Answer (score 4):

Se alguma questão foi fechada por um motivo que você considera errado, você pode iniciar a votação para reabertura. Isso vai para a fila de análise também, onde outros usuários podem ver - e se concordarem com a questão, podem contribuir para sua reabertura.

Sobre o motivo dos fechamentos estar correto ou não, o que vejo é que para certos assuntos, certas formas de se perguntar e responder, **não existe ainda consenso** sobre certo e errado. Já vimos casos de [perguntas puramente opinativas que foram mantidas abertas a força, via atribuição de recompensa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11594/e-errado-usar-heranca-de-classes-para-agrupar-comportamentos-e-atributos-comuns/11713) (essa especificamente foi melhorada a ponto de ser boa e merecer ficar). Muitos usuários ficam, com o perdão da palavra, putos com perguntas de recomendação, mas a comunidade em geral tolera e uma ou duas dessas perguntas têm mais votos positivos do que negativos. Aliás, basta ver esta pergunta no meta: [Quais assuntos devem fazer parte do nosso foco (on-topic)?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic) As respostas com mais votos são indiscutíveis; quaisquer perguntas bem formuladas nesses tópicos serão bem vindas no site. Mas veja tópicos como [este](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/498/1658), [este](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/792/1658), [este](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/960/1658) e [este](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275/1658). Não ficarei surpreso se uma pergunta em qualquer um desses tópicos gerar uma disputa de fechamento e reabertura.

**edição após o comentário do Bacco:** no SO original, nas tarefas de analise, de vez em quando aparecem "pegadinhas" - situações que te testam. São perguntas ou respostas que nem estão na fila de verdade, e se você der um voto "errado", você recebe uma mensagem dizendo *"isso é só um teste - e você não deveria ter votado para fechar/reabrir/aceitar pelos motivos A, B e C"*. Não sei o que ocorre com quem "erra" demais, mas acho que isso é um bom mecanismo de controle. Faz o usuário pensar duas vezes antes de votar levianamente. Acredito que, por ser uma característica do SE em geral, e não apenas do SO, essa feature deve estar ativada no SOpt também.

**Segunda edição:** Pergunta no Meta do SE sobre o mecanismo de **auditoria**, que é ao que me refiro no parágrafo anterior: [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)

Tem até um termo para quem vota na fila de análise sem pensar: *robo-reviewer*.

Comment: A questão principal nem é tanto o erro. Quem praticamente não se abstêm de votar. Quem tem como critério para votar o fato de outra pessoa já ter votado. Já temos até uma confissão que o critério p/ votar é ter outras votando antes. O motivo deste post é chamar a atenção para isso e ver se as pessoas que estão adotando essa linha repensem isso. Como não temos moderadores, nem sempre conseguimos 5 pessoas para reabrir algo fechado equivocadamente. Errar todo mundo erra, o problema é amaneira como erro está acontecendo.

Comment: Até concordo com uma parte considerável do que foi respondido, mas tenho uma forte impressão de que isso não muda o problema da pessoa ter voto superficial só por estar na fila.

Comment: @Bacco no SO original, ao menos, quando vou realizar uma tarefa de fila, de vez em quando aparecem "pegadinhas" - situações que te testam. São questões que nem estão na fila de verdade, e se você der um voto de encerramento "errado", por exemplo, você recebe uma mensagem dizendo *"isso é só um teste - e você não deveria ter votado para fechar pelos motivos A, B e C"*. Não sei o que ocorre com quem "erra" demais, mas acho que isso é um excelente mecanismo de controle. Não tem isso no SOpt também não?

Comment: Quem erra demais é suspenso da fila de análise por um tempo. Acho que isso está desligado aqui, mas pelo visto está mesmo na hora de ligarem.

Comment: Fale mais sobre esse teste no SO, tem alguma referência sobre isso? Achei sensacional.

Comment: @bigown http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work

Comment: @Bacco não é necessário criar perguntas-teste ;)

Comment: Acredito que ainda não temos auditorias aqui (perguntas testes) pois como dito nessa resposta ainda **não temos critérios bem definidos**

Comment: @Math imaginei o mesmo, li o link que o Renan passou, e percebo que como o sistema se baseia na qualidade do que foi feito antes, aqui ainda não seriam consistentes os resultados (o que é justamente o início da atual discussão). Os problemas seriam refletidos no audit.

Comment: @Bacco até onde entendi as auditorias refletem o trabalho da moderação, não dos usuários em geral, então acho que se torna consistente por conta própria em pouco tempo.

Comment: Seria legal se o @Gabe desse um parecer sobre essa mecânica também. Eu gostaria de ver isso funcionando aqui o quanto antes (desde que funcione mesmo).

Comment: Se não temos uma forma de avaliar a qualidade da moderação dos usuários comuns, precisamos que diamantes tomem alguma providência. Esta pergunta foi aberta justamente para tratar disso. A avaliação seria subjetiva de qualquer jeito, o teste de auditoria só daria melhores subsídios para essa avaliação.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que o maior problema que temos hoje é a falta de definição de critérios.

Temos aquele tópico [Quais assuntos devem fazer parte do nosso foco (on-topic)?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/264/3117) onde a comunidade pode dizer o que é on-topic e o que é off-topic. Entretanto dentro de cada resposta ainda existe margem para interpretação pois nem sempre é claro quais são os limites impostos por determinada resposta, por exemplo:

[Dificuldades na instalação ou uso de ferramentas de desenvolvimento.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/704/3117) (saldo líquido de 7 votos a favor)

Entretanto a seguinte pergunta foi fechada e reaberta acredito eu que sem um consenso entre nós usuários:

[Migração de ambiente de desenvolvimento local de Windows para Mac](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13590/3117)

Será que votamos errado no Meta dizendo que queriamos que aquele tipo de pergunta fosse on-topic? Se sim, por que fizemos isso? Talvez por que o texto dava margem para interpretação? Ou demos votos displicentes a favor desse assunto?

Mais um exemplo. O seguinte tópico também eleito pela comunidade para ser on-topic:

[Dificuldades (técnicas e administrativas) com publicação de aplicativos (apps) em mercados online (Apple Store, Play Store, Chrome Web Store, etc).](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/8759)  (saldo líquido de 12 votos a favor)

Não deveria garantir que as seguintes perguntas permanecessem abertas?

[Tipos de pagamento proibidos no IOS [em suspenso]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/8759)

[Alternativas para pagamentos de bens ou serviços com cartão de crédito no iOS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/8744)

Os assuntos discutidos nela não são dificuldades técnicas e/ou administrativas? Talvez sim, talvez não. Esse que é o problema, o *talvez*, reforçando o que disse anteriormente existe muita margem para interpretação, e esse no meu ponto de vista é o maior problema que temos hoje.

### Outro problema: votos displicentes na fila de análise

*Talvez* (mais uma vez o talvez na resposta) seja um problema, mas não temos como garantir. Ou é possível afirmamos que alguns usuários votam displicentemente? Na minha opinião: **Não! Não é possível acusarmos ninguém de votos displicentes**, pelo menos na maioria dos casos.

Vamos deixar como está então? Claro que não! Precisamos resolver isso, mas ao meu ver só tem um jeito de fazer isso em definitivo:

**Definindo critérios claros**

E posteriormente ativando as auditorias para casos claramente off-topics para identificarmos os *robo reviewers*, ou seja, os votos displicentes apenas para aumentar o número de revisões do usuário apenas para ganhar medalhas.

Comment: Acho que a única coisa que temos consenso hoje é que não queremos listas. _Acho_.

Comment: Essa frase "Não! Não é possível acusarmos ninguém de votos displicentes" me lembrou de uma outra: "Yo no creo en brujas, pero que las hay, las hay."

Comment: acho que temos que separar duas coisas: 1) pessoas que discordam, aí cai na falta de critérios. 2) voto sem análise nenhuma ou com análise superficial. Isso não se resolve por mais que sejam claros os critérios, se a atitude não mudar. Esse segundo caso é a maior impressão que eu tenho. Vejo questões serem editadas pra arrumar os problemas, com um voto pra fechar, e de repente, acaba sendo fechada de qualquer forma por causa do primeiro voto. Não vou lembrar de nenhuma em especial nesse exato momento, mas já vi coisa do tipo o suficiente pelo site. Mesma coisa pra review, upvotes etc.

Comment: `voto sem análise nenhuma ou com análise superficial. Isso não se resolve por mais que sejam claros os critérios, se a atitude não mudar.` discordo. Por isso existem as auditorias. Além do mais podemos ver o que cada pessoa votou na fila de análise, então poderemos afirmar que o usuário votou displicente em um tópico por mais que não fosse uma auditoria. Sendo assim, mudamos a atitude da pessoa na força, rsrs

Comment: @Bacco eu tb ja tive impressão de votos maria-vai-com as outras, mas eu não vejo uma forma de resolver isso sem tomarmos a atitude que citei na resposta: definir critérios. O Gabe tentou levantar o assunto de novo mas até agora parece não ter surtido efeito. Talvez poderíamos dar mais atenção para ele: [Quais vão ser os tópicos do nosso site?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1216/3117). Inclusive nesse tópico um usuário diz que não vê problema com as listas, rsrs.. Já eu resolvi enfatizar que não quero lista :P

Comment: Adorei os exemplos das perguntas sobre pagamentos e iOS. Acho que até resolvermos o impasse do que é off-topic e o que não é, não poderemos atribuir malícia aos votos de fechamento por problema de escopo.

Comment: @Bacco não estou apontando dedos, talvez eu tenha me equivocado em mostrar a lista com os nomes de quem votou em o quê, minha intenção era mostrar que houveram tanto votos para fechar como para manter aberto, ou seja, que houve desconsenso. (estou pensando em editar minha resposta para linkar direto para as perguntas ao invés de linkar para as análises)

Comment: @Renan exato! Enquanto isso eu vou seguindo o que eu li faz um certo tempo aqui no meta (to com preguiça de procurar para linkar aqui), que dizia algo assim: `enquanto não tivermos critério temos que ser mais complacentes`. Ainda não temos critérios, então publicações na área cinzenta eu voto para deixar aberta. Se um dia decidirmos que aquilo ali é off-topic precisaremos vasculhar o passado fechando tais perguntas, por mais que isso dê trabalho faz parte do negócio.

Comment: Não precisa de critérios para acabar com o voto das pessoas que só votam porque algo está na lista. Precisa apenas que essas **poucas** pessoas parem com isso. Elas sabem que elas estão votando sem critério. A pergunta não trata das pessoas que estão errando eventualmente no voto porque não entende bem como votar. Também temos a situação que as pessoas que votam sem critério, acertam na maior parte das vezes, apenas  seguindo os outros. Mas acertam pelos motivos errados. E isso faz diferença. O problema é a pessoa votar em tudo o que aparece, ela não questiona nada.

Comment: E não é só no fechamento por off-topic. Vale para tudo. O problema não é de critério ruim, é de total falta de critério, ou melhor, ter como único critério, alguém ter votado antes. São pessoas que praticamente não iniciam votações, mas votam em todas as perguntas que ele tem chance quando entra na fila de análise. Ninguém está questionando as diferenças de opinião entre os usuários. É bom ter diferenças se elas forem respeitadas. O problema é justamente o usuário que não quer ser diferente, ele quer seguir o que os outros estão fazendo.

Comment: `enquanto não tivermos critério temos que ser mais complacentes` Como fechar tudo o que aprece pela frente pode ser complacência? O problema é esse, falta de complacência. Se a pessoa tem dúvidas, ela não deve votar. Não causa mal. Ser rígido e votar em algo só porque já foi votado é que causa mal.

Comment: @bigown Concordo que as pessoas não devem se influenciar pelo votos dos outros para decidir seu próprio voto, mas como pretende terminar com isso? A única maneira concreta que enxerguei de solucionar foi definindo critérios e _batendo_ em quem não os seguir, pois senão vai virar um monte de acusações sem fundamentos. Aproveitando a frase do Bacco sobre as bruxas, eu tb acredito nelas, e adoraria tacar fogo em algumas, apenas precisamos tomar cuidado para não colocarmos na fogueira alguém pensando que é bruxo quando na verdade não é.

Comment: `São pessoas que praticamente não iniciam votações, mas votam em todas as perguntas que ele tem chance quando entra na fila de análise.` Até onde eu sei isso não é um problema, pois existem medalhas que recompensam os analisadores das filas entretanto não existe medalhas que recompensam o primeiro a votar para fechar, logo acredito que é um comportamento incentivado pelo SE. Existem mais de 100 sites da SE, provavelmente muitos já sentiram na pele o que estamos sentindo, e como eles resolveram isso? Você acha que uma campanha para conscientizar as pessoas funcionaria? É essa sua sugestão?

Comment: Para mim, desde que as análises sejam feitas com critérios não há problema as pessoas nunca iniciem um fechamento, caso contrário deveria existir senão uma medalha pelo menos uma condição: _Cada usuário tem o direito de cinco votos na fila para cada vez que for o primeiro a votar para fechar uma pergunta e ela realmente for fechada_. Mas para mim essa não é a solução, mais uma vez, a solução para mim é definirmos critérios claros. Claro que eu posso estar sendo simplista demais e estar enganado, mas até agora não vi nenhuma proposta concreta de parar os robo-reviewers.

Comment: O problema não é de critérios. Isso existe mas não causa problema sério no site, porque o erro é eventual. O problema é quem sempre está votando por votar. Conscientizar ajuda resolver com os bem intencionados. Esse foi um dos motivos que abri aqui. Quem está fazendo isso, vê que há problema nisso e pare. Mas há aqueles que não querem mudar. Aí a única solução que vejo (podem existir outras) é a retirada do privilégio.

Comment: @bigown entendi, então o tópico foi criado basicamente para os usuários verem e perceberem que podem estar sendo prejudiciais para a comunidade? Tipo, o tópico por si só já resolveria parte do problema sem nenhum outro tipo de ação junto com isso. É isso?

Comment: Para os bem intencionados, sim. Eu entendo que algumas pessoas agem sem pensar no que etão fazendo. Outros têm algum objetivo próprio que vai contra os interesses da comunidade, mas apessoa não se preocupa com isso.