# Fechar e Reabrir questões

Tags: debate, edição, perguntas-fechadas

Mais uma pergunta para discussão aqui no META: [Publicar automaticamente no Twitter a partir do site PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15767/7210)

**Acho que se enquadra na discussão** [Aqui É UM Stack Overflow. Qual?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/522/7210)

Se virmos as [edições](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/522/7210) vamos reparar que foi votada para fechar e reaberta, sem que nada se tivesse alterado.

O que levanta outra questão [Quanto tempo esperar antes de votar para fechar uma pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/537/7210)

O que acham sobre a pergunta em questão?
Estamos perante uma falta de critérios de fechar/reabrir?
Ou Será apenas "normal" isso acontecer, ser fechada e reaberta?

Mais uma pergunta exemplo:
[Programar C em Linux - IDE vs. editor + linha de comando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15794/programar-c-em-linux-ide-vs-terminal)

**Um exemplo gritante de que deveria ser logo fechada imediatamente:** [Inserir imagem no banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16396/inserir-imagem-no-banco-de-dados)

Comment: Acho que a pergunta inicial poderia ser razoável, se houvesse o mínimo de esforço em tentar resolver o problema. Ao pedir recomendação de tutorial, no meu ver o autor invalidou a questão. Como está, entendo que deva ser mesmo fechada. Lembrando do mais importante: basta o autor melhorar a questão para justificar que ela seja aberta. Fechamento não é castigo, nem é permanente, desde que o usuário se adeque. Não é o SOpt que é radical, os usuários que se assustam à toa. Em alguns casos (nao digo esse), há falta de interesse de aprender a ferramenta. Não podemos fazer um SOpt só pra esse perfil.

Comment: @Bacco eu criei mesmo esta questão aqui por causa dos critérios falados na "Aqui É UM Stack Overflow. Qual?". Como podemos ter critérios desses já definidos se a comunidade ainda esta muito verde para isso. Ainda não deu para perceber o que poderá ser fechado ou reaberto por exemplo. Por isso é que acho que devíamos ir analisando casos, como eu fiz aqui agora, e depois sim, tentar definir critérios. Nota: Eu fui um dos que votei para fechar. Não coloquei isso na pergunta para não influenciar as respostas.

Comment: Se quiser adicionar mais um exemplo na sua pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15794/3117

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu fui um dos que voltou para reabrir. Mesmo concordando com a razão de que ela foi fechada por ser ampla demais (nenhum exemplo de código ou dúvida pontual) a resposta é pontual.

Seguindo a pergunta proposta, vi pela abordagem que estava lá que era:

> Via de regra, por enquanto é melhor permitir qualquer pergunta que
>   satisfaça as seguintes condições:
>
> Essa pergunta torna a internet um lugar melhor?
>   Ela aumenta ou diminui
>   o número de programadores que podem se beneficiar do site?

Então, se foi possível dar uma resposta pontual e isso ira auxiliar quem quiser um pontapé inicial para começar a integrar-se com o Twiter, votei pela reabertura.

Houve uma [outra pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1278/muitas-perguntas-estao-sendo-fechadas-sem-criterio) do @bigown que pega exatamente sobre esses critérios (ou falta deles) para fechar ou reabrir.

No fim das contas abrir e fechar questões são questões de opniões e pontos de vista. No momento da análise e da forma que a pessoa que analisou interpretou a questão

Comment: @Caputo, concordo contigo

Comment: @Caputo gostei da abordagem, acho que é um ponto de vista que vai de encontro os atuais critérios do SOPT e que me diz que, SE CALHAR, ainda estamos muito verdes para assumir critérios. O que para 5, eu inclusive era *off-topic* para outros era bem *on-topic*, até porque já leva alguns votos positivos a pergunta.

Comment: @JorgeB. Acho que o ponto é que descontextualizado ou amplo deveriam ser vistos de acordo com aquela regra citada na resposta. Se é valido para o operador e pode melhorar a base de conhecimento do site sem gerar discussões ou com tema diverso deve se pensar bem antes de fechar

Comment: @Caputo Sim eu concordo, e quando voto para fechar ou reabrir é sempre consciente. E algumas das vezes vou contra a maré, porque discordo dos outros. Ali votei para fechar porque realmente achei que seria ampla demais.

Comment: Eu acho que este é um caso da resposta que salvou a pergunta. A pergunta continua ruim e por si só deveria ser fechada mesmo. Mas tem uma resposta boa que responde melhor do que foi perguntado.

Comment: @bigown A resposta salvou a pergunta, mas a pergunta foi reaberta sem nenhuma resposta, foi reaberta porque muitos entenderam que daria uma boa resposta.

Comment: @JorgeB. Acredito até que o autor da resposta reabriu porque ele viu que tinha uma resposta que ele podia dar. Ele pode confirmar isso. Curioso é que lá dá para ver que tem gente que realmente vota em tudo, vota para fechar e para reabrir algo que essencialmente não mudou nada. O importante é votar em qualquer coisa.

Comment: @bigown Só para confirmar. Eu votei para abrir pois achei que a resposta seria um conteúdo relevante para o SOpt pois a API do twitter só é documentada em inglês, e que portanto aumentaria o número de beneficiados do site

Comment: Melhorando o comentário anterior: Eu tomei ciência da pergunta na análise de reabertura e percebi que poderia dali construir uma boa resposta. Só não quis alterar drásticamente a pergunta para que ficasse mais objetiva

Comment: Na verdade, a modificação [**é muito pequena**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1344/fechar-e-reabrir-questoes/1352#1352) pra deixar a pergunta mais objetiva ;)

Comment: Concordo @basofilo, realmente não consegui moldar a pergunta quando tentei editar. Essa alteração realmente transformou um pedido de tutorial em pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

Iniciei uma discussão aqui no meta e a principal causa era fechar perguntas amplas, que podem suscitar opiniões mas que possuem uma reposta pontual.

A pergunta em questão "***publicar automaticamente no twitter a partir do site php***", possui uma resposta pontual, bastava transcrever alguns trechos de códigos prontos e comentar o que cada linha faz.

Mas isso é trabalhoso e notamos que o autor não se preocupou em pesquisar primeiro antes de fazer a pergunta, há muitos exemplos.

Penso que é esse o real motivo pelo qual fecharam a pergunta, não por possuir uma resposta ampla mas sim pelo fato do autor não se esforçar para encontrar uma reposta.

Eu entendo que pelos critérios do SO a pergunta é válida sim, porém ninguém quer fazer o trabalho do autor.

Outro ponto de vista é, responde-la em forma de um tutorial para que no futuro outros possam utiliza-lo como referência.

Acredito que o problema não seja falta de critérios e sim amadurecimento, no que diz respeito a utilização do SO, até porque o SO em inglês possui os mesmos critérios e funciona muito bem.

Comment: E no corpo da questão, para piorar, ele ainda pede recomendação de tutorial, o que invalida a premissa do título.

Comment: O fato do autor não investir muito esforço na pergunta justifica votos contra, não fechamento. Já o fato de pedir tutoriais para mim justifica fechamento, mas parece que não há consenso, a favor ou contra essa posição, infelizmente.

Comment: "Acredito que o problema não seja falta de critérios e sim amadurecimento, no que diz respeito a utilização do SO, até porque o SO em inglês possui os mesmos critérios e funciona muito bem." **Frase chave para mim.**

Comment: @JorgeB. O SO possui um conceito novo, pelo menos para o publico pt-BR. A grande maioria está acostumada com o fórum, diferente do SO que é focado em soluções e não em discussões. A medida que entendermos isso, vamos amadurecendo, por isso disse que não é o SO que precisa de amadurecer, e sim os utilizadores. A ideia do SO está bem consolidada.

Answer (score 2):

Com uma modificação muito pequena é possível converter algo duvidoso em uma pergunta adequada:

[image]

Comment: Por acaso já tinha visto, ficou mesmo muito diferente!

Comment: Pode ser falta de domínio meu no assunto, mas não sei de que tipo de "passos básicos" o autor estaria precisando, se a resposta existente é avançada para ele ou não. Um tutorial estilo *for dummies* sobre o uso dessa API pelo PHP seria a resposta ideal, mas será que ficaria grande demais? E será que tutoriais são o tipo de conteúdo que queremos? Não digo que sim nem que não, só deixo as questões aqui.

Comment: @bfavaretto acho que a ideia ai era fazer um *guideline* e não um *tutorial*.