# Como proceder com questões de novatos no SOpt com pouca chance de recuperação?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Nesta **[pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16044/plugin-para-eclipse-uml-engenharia-reversa)** a OP quer indicação de um plugin. É uma pergunta difícil de ser editada para chegar a ser realmente objetiva e vai gerar respostas baseadas em opniões.

Tenho visto um esforço em dar as boas vindas aos novos usuários e ajudá-los a entender os padrões do SOpt.

Vi também que em pouco tempo ela já estava votada para ser fechada, editada e comentada.

Existe um esforço da comunidade para engrandecer o SOpt mas como todos querem ajudar e cada um de sua forma fica complicado saber como proceder.

Sei que este assunto está tratado [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1333/estado-da-pilha-1-carinho?cb=1) e [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1344/fechar-e-reabrir-questoes) e em outros lugares, mas acho que realmente precisamos de um senso comum de como receber as primeiras perguntas.

Então fiquei em dúvida. Como acreditam ser uma boa acolhida?

Comment: Eu acho que deveríamos dar hipótese ao utilizador de editar a sua própria pergunta inicialmente, mas também é uma boa abordagem edita-la e colocar um comentário com o que se fez.

Comment: Baseado nesta questão, acrescentei um ítem sobre o voto para fechar na minha [resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1347/70).

Comment: A pergunta, quando [em suspenso] está apta a ser adaptada e então reaberta. Já haviam comentários explicando como proceder, portanto optei pelo upvote no primeiro comentario do @JorgeB. e votei para fechá-la aguardando edição a fim de não incitar nenhum usuário a iniciar uma discussão puramente baseada em opiniões.

Comment: Realmente, eu ando sem saber o que fazer. Parece que nada mais é adequado.

Comment: Concordo @bigown quando eu vou ver a pergunta de um novo usuário ele já está comentada, editada e com votos para fechar. Tudo em um prazo muito curto. Eu comecei no SOpt há pouco tempo. Escrevi perguntas com saudações e mal formatadas. Cada edição ou comentário era bem vindo e eu fui aprendendo aos poucos. Ainda não sou um expert, mas já tento ajudar. O problema é que antes de acabar de ler a pergunta todas as possíveis ações foram tomadas em conjunto o que deixa incluse os novos usuários perdidos.

Comment: Boa observação. Talvez a gente já tenha vários usuários fazendo várias coisas e o melhor seja os mais experientes se afastarem um pouco e se entrar quando os outros falham.

Comment: Acho que alguns usuários, como o da pergunta citada estão se intimidando com essa chuva de informações como eu vi como eu vi [neste comentário](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1363/sopt-na-tdc-florianopolis?cb=1#comment3568_1363) em outra publicação

Comment: Entendo a proteção da discussão @Filipe.Fonseca, mas acho q com comentário já feito, deveria dar um tempo para que o usuário tome uma ação. Um usuário que já conheça o modelo não se intimida com um pergunta fechada, mas um novo usuário se sente censurado e repreendido em minha opnião. Seria uma ação como [nesta resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1333/estado-da-pilha-1-carinho/1347#1347)

Comment: É o que sempre faço, mas com muita gente agindo, sem uma diretriz clara, já que a recomendação é que todo mundo deve ficar à vontade para agir, um faz uma coisa e outro faz outra, aí vários fizeram tudo o que dava para fazer. Eu posso tentar fazer minha parte para evitar a avalanche de ações no primeiro momento, mas não sei se todo mundo vai fazer o mesmo. Tem usuário que não está nem aí para a comunidade, ele  acha que está ajudando mas está fazendo algo com agenda própria.