# Sem comentários

Tags: debate, sinalização, fechamento

Querem saber qual é o tipo de sinalização que eu mais odeio? Este aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando uma pergunta é fechada/suspensa sem nenhum comentário, o sistema sinaliza automaticamente para que um moderador dê uma olhada. Quase sempre é o caso de informar melhor quem perguntou sobre os motivos do fechamento (que são meio obscuros para quem não conhece bem o site), e orientá-lo sobre como melhorar a pergunta para reabertura, ou como evitar que as futuras perguntas dele também acabem fechadas.

O @utluiz tem feito um excelente trabalho com esses sinalizadores que, admito, eu tendo a empurrar com a barriga. Acontece que os moderadores não deveriam precisar lidar com tantos sinalizadores desses! **Se cinco pessoas leram a pergunta e votaram para fechar, pelo menos uma delas poderia tentar orientar o autor**, não é? Especialmente se for um usuário com pouca experiência no site. Aproveito para pedir para **pensarem melhor antes de votar para fechar uma pergunta**, especialmente a partir da fila de análise. Porque o que tenho visto é que **[muitas perguntas estão sendo fechadas sem critério](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1278/muitas-perguntas-est%C3%A3o-sendo-fechadas-sem-crit%C3%A9rio)**.`</rant>`

Comment: Alguns fechamentos são bem irritantes. Os usuários estão cada vez mais virando autômatos (descobrem uma falha ou outra numa pergunta que pode ser ótima e votam pra fechar, e exemplos não faltam), isto fora os downvotes. Creio que é mais fácil votar contra do que tentar orientar o autor da pergunta/resposta sobre como ele deveria proceder, e evitar que mais tarde esses usuários venham fazer rebu no meta.

Comment: Principalmente quando o voto é dado através da lista de revisões as nossas ações tendem a ficar mais mecânicas e impessoais, pois logo após o voto a fila segue e a publicação fica para trás. Precisamos ficar mais atentos para esse tipo de situação.

Comment: Abri um pedido de novo recurso: [*Oferecer suporte no Meta ao colocar uma pergunta em suspenso*](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2009/201)

Answer (score 15):

Precisamos de mais participação. Não pode ficar nas costas sempre das mesmas pessoas editar, comentar, tentar resolver todos os problemas do site. Não pode ficar tudo para os moderadores e meia dúzia de usuários mais ativos. Precisa distribuir melhor o trabalho.

Estamos começando receber uma leva grande de usuários *hit and run* que não vão aprender como usar o site, eles precisam de um cuidado especial. O volume de trabalho para gerenciar todos estes *posts* ruins está aumentando. Ou agimos para resolver os problemas ou o site vira bagunça. Existem vários usuários que são bem ativos em algumas ações mas falta ser em outras. Não dá para exigir que sempre os mesmos usuários façam tudo. Até porque se for assim, fica fácil, deixa tudo para os moderadores :) Mas é óbvio que esta não é a solução.

Se todo mundo fizer um pouco, não fica uma carga pesada para alguns usuários e o site rola melhor. Não é o caso do AP que todos sabem que é bem ativo, mas se todo mundo achar que os outros é que devem ajudar e não fizer alguma coisa, o problema vai persistir.

Tem muitas perguntas sendo fechadas sem critério conforme eu reclamei na pergunta linkada acima e outras estão sendo mantidas abertas ou recebendo votos quando elas são ruins. Este problema não é grande mas ele existe. O pessoal que é mais ativo precisa entender melhor o funcionamento do site para ter uma ação melhor coordenada.

Não dá para ficar nomeando aqui cada usuário, mas quero deixar claro que existem vários usuário que fazem um trabalho espetacular na organização do site. Não quero ser injusto de reclamar da falta de atitude das pessoas erradas. Nós vemos a todo momento que algumas pessoas vivem participando ajudando de várias formas. Não podemos culpar alguém porque não participa aqui e ali. O que falta é melhor distribuição. Infelizmente alguns usuários acham que deveria não fazer nada, aí a distribuição fica prejudicada.

Não há dúvida que é um problema não ajudar os novos usuários mas se tivermos muitos *posts* ruins e poucos ajudando, vai cansando e mais cedo ou mais tarde só teremos os votos mesmo, estes poucos vão cansando de fazer o que dá mais trabalho.

Answer (score 10):

Um fechamento sem sequer um comentário impede inclusive o usuário que é novato de tentar qualquer argumentação, pois ele simplesmente não tem para quem falar. Se ele postar um comentário abaixo da sua pergunta (o que já é muito improvável), ninguém será notificado. De forma alguma ele trará o assunto para o Meta. Consequentemente ele estará, de certa forma, completamente abandonado e ignorado.

Dificilmente um usuário que passar por uma situação desse tipo se sentirá motivado a tentar participar novamente, e com isso teremos menos membros querendo se juntar a nossa comunidade.

Tenhamos mais atenção com os votos da fila de análises e também com as orientações aos usuários, principalmente os novatos.

Comment: É vero total: *"ninguém será notificado"* e *"de forma alguma trará o assunto ao Meta"*.

Comment: Estava aqui pensando e eu acho que consigo compreender porque às vezes não se posta um comentário. É muito comum um comentário desencadear outras reações, de repente quem comentou acaba gastando horas em cima daquilo. Aí a pessoa aprende que é melhor votar e não comentar. Não sei se existe uma solução para este problema. Talvez exista uma dicotomia entre as duas opções.

Answer (score 10):

Eu tenho tanta capacidade de projetar vontades na mente de terceiros quanto qualquer um aqui, então fui pesquisar pra tentar dar uma luz sobre essa flag, quando ela acontece, que tipo de atividade ela gera, pra que a gente pudesse talvez chegar num jeito de lidar com ela. No máximo, fornecer umas curiosidades pra aliviar a dor...

Vamos ao que eu aprendi:

- **"Fechado sem comentário" só existe em sites que estão em beta**
  Eu não sabia disso mas faz bastante sentido, se considerarmos que o intuito dela é garantir que os autores de posts fechados tenham a chance de aprender onde erraram, enquanto o site ainda é novo.
- **Realmente é preciso comentar mais**
  Armado desse conhecimento, quis saber quais tipos de pergunta estavam mais torrando a paciência dos nossos moderadores, então ei-las:

  ```
  fora de escopo          | 67
  amplo demais            | 47
  pergunta não está clara | 39
  baseado em opiniões     | 21
  ```

  Vamos falar das fora de escopo daqui a pouco... agora queria me concentrar no resto. *"Amplo demais"* e *"não está claro"* são dois motivos que praticamente *gritam* pela mão de um usuário mais experiente. Mesmo que não sejam casos fáceis de se resolver, são simples de se explicar pro autor que erro ele cometeu e como pode corrigir.
  Não é necessariamente o caso com *"baseado em opiniões"*, mas ainda assim temos quase 50% das flags que poderiam ter sido evitadas, ou pelo menos sensivelmente reduzidas. Nesse ponto temos sim onde melhorar.
- **Vamos falar do escopo**
  A maioria não absoluta das flags foi para publicações fora do escopo do site. E aí, discussões sobre nosso escopo à parte, entramos num ponto interessante:
  **Faz sentido comentar em perguntas que claramente fogem ao escopo?**
  Faz sentido esperar isso de quem vota para fechar? Perguntas que não fazem parte do nosso escopo não podem ser salvas e um comentário na pergunta nao seria mais explicativo que a caixa padrão que o site já exibe. E são essas perguntas que geram grande parte do fardo para os moderadores.
- **Daqui pra frente, só piora**
  Quanto mais o SOpt cresce, maior vai ser o número de desusos. Isso é normal e esperado. Isso também implicaria em **mais** posts fora de escopo, encerrados sem comentário, para os moderadores. Esse modelo é insustentável.

A situação, senhoras e senhores, é grave<sup>1</sup>.
<sup>1. Mentira, só é meio inconveniente</sup>

## O relato sobre a minha morte é <strike>um exagero</strike> verdade

Armado de todo este conhecimento, juntando A+B, conversando com meus estimados colegas CMs, pensei... Por que não extinguir de vez essa flag? Que bem ela faz?

Essa flag joga em cima dos moderadores um trabalho que deveria ser da comunidade, de guiar e ajudar posts que apresentam problemas durante o beta. Da forma atual, sobrecarregando apenas 3 pessoas, **ninguém aprende**.

Os moderadores obviamente se cansam de ter que escrever comentários em todas as perguntas fechadas no site; as pessoas que votaram para fechar não aprendem que *deveriam* ter comentado; Ao não receber o comentário, o usuário novato não aprende onde errou.

Então que tal essa ideia: Criar uma nova fila de análise, com as perguntas fechadas sem comentário? Uma fila com um requerimento baixo de participação, provavelmente, efetivamente transformando essa flag automatica em uma ferramenta de aprendizado, e fazendo uso do poder da comunidade de se auto-gerenciar.

Isso vai para discussão no MSE, como um [feature-request](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request), mas queria ver o que vocês pensam a respeito já que são o principal motivo da criação dessa nova fila. Nem 1 ano de idade, e já bagunçando a casa!

O que pensam?

<sup><sup><sup>A outra solução, óbvia, é graduar o SOpt :)</sup></sup></sup>

Comment: Fazia tempo que eu não via uma proposta concreta para pelo menos tentar achar uma solução para um problema. Embora eu ache a outra <sup><sup><sup>solução</sup></sup></sup> mais fácil e adequada (apesar de não entender todas implicações neste caso, mas se está dizendo que resolve, posemos ir nela, não dá trabalho para os devs).

Comment: @bigown As soluções não são mutuamente exclusivas

Comment: Melhor ainda. Qualquer ferramenta que ajude deve ser pelo menos tentada.

Comment: @bigown "tentada" não é a palavra certa, já que nenhuma das duas soluções caso/quando aplicadas é reversível

Comment: *"Fechado sem comentário só existe para sites em Beta"* Será que não seria o caso de abrir uma exceção para o SOpt? Mesmo estando ainda em Beta, não dá pra remover a opção?

Comment: @Andrey Não acho que isso valeria a pena, porque perderíamos uma ferramenta útil sem ganhar nada em troca. Além de não saber o quanto de trabalho de desenvolvimento isso demandaria.

Comment: @Gabe concordo com a segunda solução, mas ela não é uma ferramenta, estou falando especificamente de ferramentas. Só não sei porque a primeira não seja reversível. Não pode desativar esta fila se ela der errado?

Comment: @bigown O problema é desperdiçar as horas gastas implementando a lista. Se o `[feature-request]` for aceito, e implementado, a fila está aí para ficar, em todos os sites

Comment: Gosto da ideia da fila! Dois complementos: acho que ela deve sim incluir perguntas off-topic (muitas não são tão óbvias, pelo menos no nosso site), e que perguntas de usuários com N de rep ou mais não precisam ir pra fila (essas pessoas ou entendem o fechamento, ou sabem onde reclamar).

Comment: Concordo com o @bfavaretto sobre não ser necessário a todos os usuários, mas principalmente aos menos experientes no modelo da comunidade e a fila seria válida mesmo após graduado o SOPt pois ajuda a dar um feedback mais pessoal para perguntas fechadas de usuários novos, aumentando a retenção deles