# Oferecer suporte no Meta ao colocar uma pergunta em suspenso

Tags: novo-recurso, comunidade, fechamento

Pensando no que o Math disse sobre "nunca vir ao Meta" no debate  *[Sem comentários](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2002/sem-coment%c3%a1rios)*, pensei em adicionar algo do tipo na mensagem de fechamento, o que acham?

<kbd>[image: Adicionar a mensagem: Pode também abrir um pedido de suporte no Meta Stack Overflow em Português]</kbd>

Pouco depois de abrir esta pergunta, fiz o mesmo pedido de [novo-recurso](/questions/tagged/novo-recurso) no Meta principal ([Add Meta as help venue on the on-hold/closed notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240623/185667)) pois é uma melhoria que pode ser aplicada em todos os sites da rede. Como até hoje houve pouco feedback, gostaria de saber se é possível aplicar essa mudança somente aqui no SOpt?

Comment: Não consigo pensar em nenhum motivo para não existir isso.

Comment: Se os usuários novatos se sentem mal ou não sabem o que fazer quando a pergunta é fechada, eu acho que pode ser culpa deste box que não está atendendo ao propósito. Já que a SE é tão boa em entender a psicologia humana, ele poderia achar uma solução para isto. Ou pode ser que o usuário prefira ignorar os detalhes do box e sair chutando tudo. Aí não sei se existe solução plausível. Isso quer dizer que o box precisa ser melhorado mesmo.

Comment: Uma das formas de reformular uma pergunta (vir ao Meta e pedir ajuda) tá faltando ali, @big. Se a pessoa ignora e chuta, já não é problema nosso.

Comment: @brasofilo claro, concordo, o problema é que às vezes eu tenho a sensação que alguns acham que deve ser nossa responsabilidade fazer tudo para que o usuário se dê bem no site e quem pede a ajuda não precisa se esforçar nada. Acaba caindo naquela coisa do restaurante que doa para instituições o que sobra de comida no dia e além de fazer um favor ele ainda tem que se responsabilizar se alguém passar mal com a comida que foi normalmente servida para os clientes. Então ele prefere não doar. Ele só tem a perder se tentar fazer o favor.

Comment: @bigown, é, não dá pra gastar saliva com vampiro de ajuda e pessoa problemática. Acho que igual que no site principal, a porta tem que estar aberta e a gente vai separando o joio do jquery, quero dizer... :)