# Devemos ser mais tolerantes com novos usuários?

Tags: debate, fechamento

Por muitas vezes vejo perguntas de novos usuários na SO-pt sendo fechadas rapidamente(seguindo as regras) porém, me pergunta se é mesmo o ideal para a comunidade...

Acredito que quando um novo usuário faz uma pergunta fora do escopo ou que não é claro o que ele está perguntando, nossa primeira atitude não deveria ser votar para fechar e sim auxiliar o OP e esperar um retorno do mesmo, pois uma vez que fechamos a pergunta dele é muito difícil ele voltar. São raros os casos em que um OP novo na SO-pt reformula sua pergunta após a mesma ser fechada, e mais raros ainda os OP's que permanecem ativos na comunidade...
**Talvez um dos moderadores possa nos fornecer os números, pois isso é o que eu vejo**

Acredito que um nível de tolerancia maior com essas pessoas ajudaria no crescimento da comunidade, talvez um prazo de 12 horas, após o primeiro comentário indicando os erros do OP com relação a sua pergunta, antes de começar os votos para fechamento...

Deixo como exemplo essa pergunta: 
**[unificar arrays respeitando o indices](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33533/unificar-arrays-respeitando-o-indices)**

Com 20 visualizações e cerca de 30 minutos após ser postada, já foi fechada(votei para fechar também). Acredito que é um caso de esperar um pouco mais...

Um pouco de paciência com novos usuários não vai matar ninguém(eu acho) kkk

Obs: não vou marcar nenhuma resposta como certa pois entendo que um debate não existe certo ou errado, apenas opiniões...

Comment: Não vou responder porque o Math já o fez por mim, mas se reparares a pergunta já tem respostas *"Imagino que queira isso:"* e o que até poderia (ou não) ser uma boa pergunta vai estar cheia de respostas vagas. Eu acho preferível fechar e tentar orientar o AP. Como eu fiz aqui: [Fazer em java uma janela](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33536/7210)

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/537/215

Comment: Pra mim, o termo "tolerância" significa: *não gosto de você mas vou te tolerar mesmo assim*...

Comment: @brasofilo pode ser, só vamos aplica-lo a circunstancias certas... "Não gosto que infrinjam as regras mas vou tolerar por ser seu primeiro post então vou te orientar em como corrigir esses erros"... Fica mais legal :D

Comment: Me gusta eso, @RodrigoBorth :)

Comment: Alguem me explica o significado da tag `fechamento`?

Comment: @RodrigoBorth o debate é sobre o fechamento de perguntas.

Comment: @bfavaretto ahhhh... adiciona na wiki da tag fazendo o favor? :D

Comment: Eu concordo com a maioria do que foi dito aqui, [mas as vezes é o caso de fechar sem pensar duas vezes mesmo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34410/por-favor-olhem-a-pergunta-antes-de-jugar).

Comment: Sempre existem exceções...

Answer (score 14):

Não acredito que apenas deixar a pergunta aberta vai fazer com que o usuário goste do site e vire um frequentador assíduo. O que **pode** fazê-lo voltar e se tornar um membro ativo é ele ter suas perguntas respondidas, e para isso ele precisa perguntar de acordo com as adequações do site, senão não é possível dar uma resposta de qualidade para ele. (Conforme muito bem observado pelo @bigown no comentário, muita gente não vai voltar de qualquer jeito)

Sobre fechar rápido ou demorar mais para fechar, é algo que gera polêmica e que inclusive já tem um tópico exclusivo para tratá-lo (veja o link que o @mgibsonbr deixou abaixo da pergunta). Eu acho que depende de caso para caso, mas no geral eu sou a favor de não fazer muita cerimônia para fechar, pois se ela permanecer aberta pode atrair respostas sem pé nem cabeça de usuários geralmente também novatos tentando chutar para acertar a solução, sendo que muitas vezes nem o próprio AP sabe o que quer.

Você pode auxiliar o AP e votar para fechar ao mesmo tempo, não tem problemas quanto a isso. Isso na verdade é justamente o comportamento desejado que foi enfatizado nesse tópico: [**Sem comentários**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2002/3117)

Comment: É um ponto de vista interessante, mas, se a pergunta for fechada rapidamente, acredito que o OP perca o interesse em corrigir seus erros, perca o interesse em se adequar as regras por isso, um tempo antes de fechar poderia manter pelo menos um pouco esse interesse... Quanto as repostas sem pés nem cabeças, acredito que a negativação das mesmas faça seu trabalho, além de que, se o OP não corrigir a pergunta ela será posteriormente fechada... e as respostas consequentemente...

Comment: Sobre corrigir os erros, eu diria que é necessário que alguém ajude ele via comentários dizendo quais são e como arrumá-los, que é justamente o último parágrafo da minha resposta. Acho que ele não ficará ofendido se estiverem votando para fechar desde que demonstremos que estamos querendo ajudar e melhorar a postagem, acho que pelo contrário, ele se sentirá mais parte da comunidade assim. É claro que isso é minha opinião, podem haver outras que destoem da minha, vamos aguardar e ver se alguém compartilha de outro ponto de vista.

Comment: +1 Math a minha opinião é a mesma.

Comment: A minha opinião é que se a pessoa não consegue se dar ao trabalho de ler a mensagem de fechamento (que poderia ser um pouco melhor, só para citar um exemplo o *on hold* poderia ser melhor traduzido para "em avaliação" ou algo parecido, mas isto é outro assunto) e não é capaz de entender que aqui as coisas são organizadas, provavelmente o site não é para ele. Não adianta tentar agradar todo mundo. De qualquer forma a maioria destes usuários são *hit and run*, eles não voltariam de qualquer forma, muitas vezes não voltam nem mesmo para ver uma boa resposta na pergunta que ficou aberta e positiva

Comment: De resto concordo com tudo o que estão dizendo, ajudar os novatos é algo extremamente desejável independente se a pergunta merece ou não ser fechada.

Answer (score 11):

A questão não é só fechar rapidamente ou esperar. Existem situações onde isso é necessário e outras, pelo contrário, poderiam ser salvas com um pequeno esforço. Vou focar esta resposta no último caso.

## O lado ruim de fechar

Infelizmente, acontece que votar para fechar é muitas vezes o que posso chamar de ***saída fácil***.

Se não gostei da questão, não entendi ou achei mal formulada e não quero me dar ao trabalho de tentar entendê-la para então melhorá-la ou adicionar um comentário de esclarecimento, então basta escolher o *caminho fácil e cômodo* de fechar.

A verdade é que muitas perguntas fechadas poderiam ser salvas se houvesse um esforço por parte de pelo menos um usuário mais experiente e com domínio sobre o assunto, embora o ideal fosse um trabalho sempre em equipe.

Eu já vi várias perguntas que foram fechadas como *não é claro o que você está perguntando* sem ter nada de errado. Só porque o código ou mensagem erro era algo muito específico, de modo que quem não tivesse trabalhado especificamente com a tecnologia X iria enxergar hieroglifos.

## Devemos jogar as regras em cima dos usuários?

Eu sou cristão. Se você visitasse a minha igreja, não iria gostar que eu jogasse em cima de você todas as regras, certo? Primeiro eu preciso lhe convencer de é realmente melhor seguir essas regras.

Da mesma forma, ninguém pode entrar numa religião e exigir que ela mude conforme seus gostos. Se alguém deseja ficar ali, deve adaptar-se a ela. É algo voluntário, não uma obrigação.

Pense nessa dinâmica. O *ideal* seria que o usuário novato fosse "evangelizado" de modo a entrar nas regras e não simplesmente barrado na entrada. Claro, tudo isso sem deixar que as regras sejam violadas.

## Onde reside a raiz (ou uma delas) do problema

A questão de como tratar os novos usuários tem sido um debate recorrente aqui no meta.

O que por vezes falta por aqui no SO tem tudo a ver (como o @Math comentou) com a [questão do @bfavaretto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2002/227).

Em resumo, o problema reside em que *sobra* disposição em votar para fechar e *falta* disposição em orientar o OP.

Não estou dizendo que é culpa de alguém, nem que ninguém é obrigado a fazer isso. Entretanto, o fato é que novos usuários continuarão a encontrar dificuldade em participar do site sempre que lhes faltar essa orientação inicial, afinal nem todos os programadores são seguros.

E também não estou dizendo que devemos simplesmente afrouxar as regras. Eu também não quero "lixo" espalhado por nossa vizinhança.

Mas "lixo" para uns pode ser uma obra de arte para outros. Talvez precisemos nos esforçar um pouco mais para reciclar o que tem potencial, antes de simplesmente enterrarmos o que não nos serve.

Comment: Concordo plenamente. Nesse caso especifico eu não percebi a pergunta, sendo conhecedor de PHP. Percebi que o Bacco percebeu a pergunta e orientou o AP, por isso nem comentei. De seguida analisei as respostas e vi muita subjetividade. Então, na minha opinião, já deveria estar fechada. Estarei errado? Não sei, se pus para fechar é porque depois de uma analise a tudo achar que deveria estar fechada até ser alterada.

Comment: Por isso que o @utluiz tem meu respeito... É exatamente esse ponto de vista, da chegada do usuário ser de certa forma barrada com a imposição das regras da forma menos sutil, que queria questionar, quando eu cheguei não encontrei esse problema, mas se tivesse sido o meu caso não estaria postando esse questionamento no meta hoje...

Comment: O mais engraçado é que eu percebo ser comum um comentário orientando a pessoa para melhorar a pergunta atrai votos de fechamento :)

Comment: é bem isso, se alguém der down vote ou votar pra fechar o povo vem até do além pra terminar o serviço... kkkk

Answer (score 2):

Isso aconteceu comigo pois sou novato; Estou fazendo um software que será livre e vou dar todos os créditos devidos aos respectivos que estão me ajudando ; Concordo que devemos ter paciencia @bfavaretto já passou isso comigo , pois eu sou novato ainda e sempre vou ser .

Em relação de fechar a pergunta penso que isso não é positivo , pois penso quem vem aqui procurar ajuda e não respostas prontas, uma ajuda já tem muito valor pra mim é o que penso .

Porém penso que existem pessoas que não sabem como lidar com o poder que tem ; Não é o caso do Varetto que aliás foi um ótimo amigo e sensato tb no meu caso . O meu problema não foi resolvido ainda naquela questão da sua intervenção mais eu sempre voltarei ao fórum para ajudar as pessoas. Pois estou recebendo atenção e um pouco de esclarecimento grátis do tempo de alguém isso pra mim vale muito .

Obrigado ao @bacco que tem tirado o tempo dele para me ajudar com o meu software.

Comment: [A partir de 15 pontos](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) qualquer usuário pode sinalizar uma pergunta como "baixa qualidade", a partir de 500 pode votar para fechar e reabrir. Não tem problema nenhum você ser novato, o problema é postar conteúdo que não atende os critérios de qualidade do site. É só você tomar uns minutos do seu tempo para dar uma olhada na **[help]** que está bem explicado lá. E pode pedir assistencia aqui no Meta se tiver dúvidas antes de publicar uma pergunta no site principal. Boa sorte!

Comment: Ah, sim, aqui no Meta os votos negativos também indicam discordância, e no site principal indicam que uma pergunta ou resposta tem problemas de qualidade. A avaliação é encima do conteúdo e não do usuário, por favor, não tome pelo lado pessoal ;)

Comment: muito =], Triste.

Comment: Bom, você está tratando o site como se fosse um fórum **e não é**. Sua [pergunta auto-duplicada e sua resposta lá](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34194/como-deletar-um-arquivo-sem-extens%C3%A3o-pelo-shell/34232#34232) indicam isso...

Comment: Você trocou sua resposta por uma não-resposta? Reverti a edição. A pergunta lá em cima, no título, é meio retórica... Não adianta só responder "sim". Enfim, o brasofilo tem razão quando diz que você está tratando o site como um fórum, aqui as coisas funcionam diferente. Dê uma olhada no [tour] e na [help].

Comment: Vou olhar @bfavaretto