# Como sinalizar um uso incorreto da fila de analise?

Tags: suporte, filas-de-análise

Eu votei em algumas perguntas para fechar na fila e algum tempo depois notei que um usuário votou para deixar aberta:

<kbd>[image: analise]</kbd>

Até então tudo bem, parecia questão de opinião, mas hoje notei novamente uma série de votos para deixar aberta:

<kbd>[image: analise]</kbd>

Vou primeiro justificar os votos de fechamento. Primeiro "fechar" uma pergunta não é deletar ou banir como expliquei aqui:

- [Votos para fechar perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2673/3635)

---

### Lista das perguntas

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/49302

  Votei para fechar pois o pedido do autor é amplo e além disto ele pede um site para estudar, o que é um pouco fora do escopo.
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/49307

  Votei por não ser clara, apesar de uma pessoa ter conseguido responder, não significa que a pergunta seja clara e provavelmente do jeito que esta dificilmente receberá novas respostas se for depender apenas da pergunta
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/49300

  Votei por fechar como **Erro de digitação** pois o próprio AP disse que era um erro de sintaxe.
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/49301

  Votei por fechar, pois além de faltar código não é possível reproduzir o código e também não informa os ambientes.
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/49324

  Votei por fechar pois o AP fala de bootstrap3, mas posta um código php bem confuso ao invés de postar a saída, fora que não da pra entender exatamente o que não esta funcionando.
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/49341

  Este tipo de pergunta já foi feito muitas vezes e existem várias perguntas que ela pode ser duplicada.
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/49344

  Votei por fechar, pois o AP não deixa claro o motivo do +1 no `mysqli_fetch_array`, pois se ele deixar claro poderia surgir uma resposta com um caminho totalmente diferente, mas que solucionaria melhor o problema, fora que do jeito que esta gera mais debate de "por que" do que se consegue uma resposta.
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/49328

  Eu não tenho certeza, mas ao pedir "qual é a melhor linguagem" já é algo baseado em opiniões, independente de entendermos do assunto ou não, o melhor seria *"como começar a desenvolver pln"*. O caso desta pergunta me parece que nem o AP sabe direito o que quer, então votei como baseado em opiniões.

Não votei:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/49322
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/49321

---

### Resumindo

Me parece que o Gabriel não esta entendendo muito bem o uso da *fila de analise*, ou não sabe a diferença de **Fechar** e **Deletar**, talvez ele pense que perguntas fechadas são ruins.

Eu já solicitei uma vez aqui no meta os *audits* (aquela pegadinha pra testar os usuários na fila de analise com solicitações falsas):

- [Por que não temos o "teste" (pegadinha) na fila de análise?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4238/3635)

Mas por enquanto, como devemos fazer se notarmos um mal uso no uso da fila de analise? Devemos entrar em uma pergunta e sinalizar ela para um moderador explicando a situação?

Comment: Acho que não é só um usuário que não está usando as filas de análise corretamente.

Comment: Enquanto ainda não temos _audits_ você pode sinalizar uma pergunta qualquer e explicar o caso. Já tivemos um caso que identificamos uma análise meio robótica por parte de um usuário e lhe tiramos o privilégio de analisar por alguns dias.

Answer (score 2):

De fato, algumas das minhas analises não seguiram o bom senso, o que acontece,

Ainda estou tendo vários conflitos para entender como analisar uma pergunta.

Nestes dois últimos meses estou vendo bastante conteúdo útil sendo reportado  desmotivando os autores da resposta a melhorar.

Vejo também a velocidade com que o pessoal vota para fechar sem tentar ao menos ajudar.

Isto é bem discutido aqui: [Devemos ser mais tolerantes com novos usuários?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2035/devemos-ser-mais-tolerantes-com-novos-usu%C3%A1rios)

Sem falar quando não há comentários: [Sem comentários](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2002/sem-coment%C3%A1rios)

Vejo muitas analises sem conhecimento prévio da linguagem ou do problema serem suspensas!

Este é um exemplo do fechamento de uma pergunta em Delphi,o mais engraçado é ver que nenhum dos que votaram para fechar  possuía contribuição na linguagem. E a resposta conseguiu resolver o problema do usuário.

[Delphi - Fazer uma Thread que toque uma música em loop](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95946/delphi-fazer-uma-thread-que-toque-uma-m%C3%BAsica-em-loop/95952#95952)

Existiria algum tour para analises ou  forma de tentar ser mais sensato na hora de analisar uma pergunta ? eu sempre tento fazer o papel de "Policial Bom". pelo que vejo. cada um analisa com base nas suas opiniões.

Comment: Obrigado por participar, posso lhe dar uma dica, se não tem certeza, "pule" (botão pular). Sobre a parte "Vejo também a velocidade com que o pessoal vota para fechar sem tentar ao menos ajudar." eu discordo, por isto linkei na pergunta isto: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/3635 - Fechar não é pra prejudicar é para evitar a pergunta receber respostas antes de atender aos requisitos de qualidade minima, lembre-se qualquer coisa que foi fechada pode ser reaberta e é isto que o pessoal anda com dificuldade de entender, veja esta outra resposta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2702/3635

Comment: A questão é que se fechar, ela vai ser reaberta, quando o autor corrigir os problemas de entendimento ou remover o que é fora do escopo, se for possivel o autor editar e a pergunta for dentro do escopo ela será reaberta normalmente e seguirá o fluxo. Lendo o Help: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions  - Espero que tenha ficado claro :)

Comment: Sobre a pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95946/3635 eu tenho sim contribuições em Delphi (uma mas tenho), e a pergunta não foi fechada por que os usuários que fecharam não tem conhecimento e sim porque não tinha código algum na pergunta até você edita-la. Não tem essa de *policial bom*, aqui só tem opiniões da comunidade e padrões de qualidade, se não segue o basico do http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ela deve ser fechada, o AP editando e melhorando para facilitar outros usuários o ajudarem então poderá ser reaberta e seguir o fluxo normal :)

Comment: O que o @GuilhermeNascimento falou aconteceu na pergunta do delphi, após a edição que adicionou o código, 5 pessoas votaram para [reabrir](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/95946/revisions) ela. Uma dica é abrir o link da pergunta em outra aba e verificar os comentários antes, as vezes tem algo útil neles.

Comment: Entendi, é uma ótima dica @rray vou seguir ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o Review audit teve algum progresso ou chance de acontecer aqui no sopt?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues muitas coisas dependem da staff do Stack Exchange e infelizmente não tivemos feedbacks :/ - Note que ter o *audit*, não é solução é apenas um treinamento, a solução é entender como e o porque dos fechamentos :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu tento entender, é que as vezes eu não concordo, o treinamento ajudaria bastante, ganhei esse previlegio a pouco tempo e agora que estou tendo a oportunidade de utiliza-lo. vou dar uma lida nos links que você me passou,obrigado.