# Questões mal formuladas, votar para fechar imediatamente ou questionar e dar uma chance?

Tags: suporte, pergunta-específica

A [primeira encarnação desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/279360/1) estava não clara. Fiz um questionamento e aparentemente o AP clarificou um pouco a questão.

Fiz o correto em achar que a pergunta tinha salvação e esperado ela ser alterada antes de dar algum veredito?

Comment: Sim, se você acha que tem salvação, invista na salvação. Se votar pra fechar, vai atrair outros votos de fechamento. Isso se você tiver disponibilidade pra acompanhar o desenrolar da pergunta.

Comment: [Quanto tempo esperar antes de votar para fechar uma pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/537/74)

Comment: Dá pra dizer que tem casos e casos, mas ainda sim eu sempre mantenho a ideia de que algo que foi fechado pode ser reaberto a qualquer momento, então ao fechar você não esta tirando a chance de ninguém, você apenas esta procurando que o AP organize o que precisa ser realmente organizado e após feito isto poderá reabrir a pergunta vai já ter ido para a primeira página e processo segue normalmente.

Comment: @bfavaretto possivelmente esta questão é duplicata da que você linkou. Vou ver melhor

Comment: Eu fico em dúvida porque aquela é bem do início do site, o contexto era outro.

Comment: Só por curiosidade, no desfecho eu votei como "erro de digitação"

Comment: Eu acredito em tentar salvar, exceto nos casos em que a pergunta realmente foge ao contexto do site. Quanto a essa pergunta específica, o que o autor fez me doeu aos olhos. Quando eu tiver filhos eu vou ensinar a eles desde pequenos que indentar código com tabulação dá câncer e faz os genitais apodrecerem.

Answer (score 9):

Por falta de mecanismos melhores eu costumo fechar logo na maioria das vezes. Sempre há casos e casos. Toda pergunta fechada pode ser reaberta.

É comum perguntas ruins serem "respondidas" por novatos e depois não temos muito como lidar bem com isso se acabar se tornando um "lixo".

Mas minha visão hoje é que tudo poderia ficar aberto se não for um absurdo de ruim, precisaria todo mundo concordar com isto e ter maneiras de lidarmos com o "lixo" produzido por ter ficado aberto.

Não vou mudar minha atuação sem a comunidade querer, afinal fui eleito sob certos parâmetros. Ainda estou pensando em como lidar com essa dualidade que tenho agora de forma definitiva.

Obviamente que minha visão mudou quando respondi a pergunta *linkada*  em comentário acima, e mudou de novo agora. Mas ainda tem o problema que deveria ter melhores mecanismos para lidar com o problema. Acho que gastamos tempo demais moderando, tem muita coisa com problema e não chegamos nem perto de obter um resultado bem positivo.

---

Um exemplo prático é esta pergunta: [O que estudar antes de programar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/279412/101).

Ela foi bem fechada, o assunto não cabe no site, mas poderia.

Não temos ferramentas adequadas para lidar com respostas ruins. A dada é péssima e dada porque não consegue responder adequadamente, e ela ficará lá pra sempre.

Eu comentei porque tenho mais de 30 anos de experiência, passei por muita coisa, dei aula, participei ativamente do processo acadêmico, não fui apenas aluno, e achei que poderia contribuir, ainda que em comentário fica mais difícil. Em uma resposta eu poderia fundamental e detalhar algumas coisas.

Se o jogo desse mais pontos para a qualidade do que para a quantidade haverá mais empenho em fazer o bom e menos em fazer mais. Por isso quero começar incentivar a qualidade (preciso arrumar tempo para administrar isso adequadamente, estou em uma fase complicada de tempo e nem deveria estar gastando aqui).

A pergunta deveria ter sido fechada antes. Ou deixar aberta e retirar um resposta que não ajuda nada, apesar da boa intenção.

Estamos enxugando gelo. E a maioria das pessoas não ligam mais, até os mais interessados no que estou falando. Ninguém quer mais pensar nisso, e eu entendo completamente. Eu mesmo cansei um pouco. Vou descansar...

Desculpa o desabafo, tive que aproveitar a oportunidade.

Comment: Eu vejo que comportamento de moderador precisa ser diferente de um usuário comum sem poder para martelar. Justamente porque eu vejo que a responsabilidade de manter a limpeza inerente aos moderadores, atuação incisiva e rápida é algo bom. Mas meu voto é voto orgânico, de toda sorte seria um processo naturalmente mais lento

Comment: Fora que nós moderadores podemos fechar e reabrir sozinhos, isso dá mais tranquilidade pra fechar.

Comment: O que mais desanima é ver respostas "fracas" recebendo enxurradas de votos, enquanto boas e complexas as vezes passam despercebido. Poucos votam pela qualidade, muitos votam como se fosse "like". isso quando não votam em fulano pelo simples fato de que "não gostam dele". Isso tem prejudicado bastante o site e desanimado muita gente. Quantos debates não abrimos no meta desde o ano passado sobre expandir o escopo e ninguém participou? É reflexo do desanimo de muitos resultante do "culto ao ego" que tem ocorrido aqui.

Answer (score 6):

A "regra" é que pergunta inútil (no sentido de não ajudar outras pessoas) deve ser fechada por uma questão de organização. É um jeito de tratar esses conteúdos, mas talvez haja outros, como indicou o @Maniero.

Daí pra frente, se cada um deve ou não votar pra fechar imediatamente eu acho que é uma decisão pessoal. Começa por avaliar se a pergunta "tem salvação". Qualquer pergunta tem salvação de um jeito ou de outro. Mas você tem condições de contribuir com essa salvação? Agora? Quanto? Está disposto a monitorar a evolução da pergunta até decidir se vota ou não para fechar? Se sim, ok, espere. Mas se prefere votar para fechar imediatamente e partir pra outra, tudo bem também. Por isso são necessários 5 votos de fechamento.

Conclusão: não tem certo ou errado, depende da pergunta e do quanto você está disposto a investir nela em determinado momento.