# Incluir sinalização para "Vampiro de ajuda"

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, moderação

Assuntos como malefícios dos 'vampiros de ajuda' e como lidar com eles já foram discutido amplamente aqui, como bem abordados nas seguintes questões, por exemplo:

- [Vampiro de Ajuda : Pergunta -> 26175](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1739/vampiro-de-ajuda-pergunta-26175)
- [O problema dos vampiros de ajuda](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160/o-problema-dos-vampiros-de-ajuda)

E, aparentemente, será uma doença sem cura (pelo menos em alguns casos).
Não que isto seja exclusividade do SOPT, mas a quantidade deste tipo de situação que tenho acompanhado aqui é muito grande!

Mesmo ignorando ou só rebaixando a pergunta, como é recomendado, sempre tem uma boa alma caridosa que atende aos chamados de seres que no final das contas querem somente "colher os frutos de árvores alheias e nunca cultivarem a sua própria árvore".

Já que temos uma comunidade menor (e consequentemente mais gerenciável) seria interessante prezar por conteúdo de qualidade e relevante de fato, pois isso fomenta um **crescimento positivo**.

**Proposta de funcionalidade:**

Seria interessante podermos **sinalizar** posts como ***"Vampiro de Ajuda"*** para a atenção dos moderadores especificamente para esse tipo de conduta.

Posts classificados como tais deveriam ser [removidos e] efetivamente desencorajados. Entendo que uma atenção exclusiva para eles iria contribuir nesse sentido.

Comment: Às vezes penso que alguns usuários desenvolvem um sistema inteiro apenas fazendo algumas perguntas. Mas eu não ligo muito pra essa questão não. Se a pergunta for algo simples, não me importo em responder.

Comment: @dvd também penso. Simples ou não, se eu souber eu até costumo ajudar, desde que haja evidências de bom senso no sentido de "eu tentei e não consegui" ou "estou tendo problemas mas me faltam idéias"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A funcionalidade já está implementada, nos motivos para fechar.

[image: Você não é a zueira, logo você tem limites]

A definição clássica do vampiro de ajuda inclui o aumento do escopo da pergunta. Se isso acontecer, eu recomendo votar para fechar e deixar um comentário.

Quem não tem reputação suficiente para votar para fechar, pode sinalizar. Dentre as opções de sinalização tem a sugestão de fechamento. Aí a pergunta vai pra fila de análise.

Answer (score 6):

Credito ser desnecessário já que existem motivações mais apropriadas e menos pejorativas.

Geralmente essas perguntas são amplas, não claras e até fora de escopo e podem ser fechadas. Provavelmente baixa qualidade suficiente para receber um negativo e ter sinalização indicando isto.

Moderadores com diamante não podem ficar monitorando todas as ações de cada usuário. A comunidade pode fazer um pouco isto. Mas nem deve exagerar.

[Concordo que precisa de uma solução melhor para esses casos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6836/101), mas o mecanismo adequado é muito mais amplo que esse.

Comment: Sim. Concordo que, de fato, "chamar o pessoal do diamante" seja desnecessário. No entanto, acredito que ainda é válido sinalizar isso como "motivo para fechar". A partir daí outras medidas poderiam ser avaliadas, pois entendo que extrapola os limites da razoabilidade um usuário ter, por exemplo, 80% de suas questões fechadas por serem caracterizadas como "vampiro de ajuda".

Comment: Se isto ocorrer ele estará bloqueado para fazer perguntas.

Comment: _Geralmente essas perguntas são amplas, não claras e até fora de escopo_ <- Pode ser uma impressão isolada, mas não acho que esse o termo "Geralmente" seja apropriado - talvez "Muitas vezes" se encaixasse melhor. Além disso, não acho que seja difícil encontrar muitas questões "vivas", antigas e novas, que certamente se enquadrariam. Me refiro a casos que são notávelmente transcrição de enunciados de exercícios, perguntas do tipo "alguém, por favor, faça o meu trabalho por mim!" (mesmo que ainda disfarçadas).