# Tarefas/exercícios de faculdade/curso de graça

Tags: debate, perguntas, comportamento, comunidade

De vez em quando me deparo com a seguinte situação:

1. Um usuário novo posta uma pergunta de programação que é uma tarefa/exercício de faculdade/curso simples e bobo e não demonstra absolutamente nenhum esforço em pesquisar ou tentar uma solução. Ele não posta nada ou quase nada além do enunciado. A quantidade de código existente na pergunta é zero ou próximo de zero.
2. Eu voto para fechar a pergunta e deixo algum comentário para ajudar.
3. Ele insiste demonstrando não ter nenhum interesse em desenvolver a solução ou mesmo de pensar em como fazer isso. Recusa-se até mesmo de tentar entender qualquer explicação sobre o que ele deveria fazer. Quer apenas o código pronto.
4. Percebo que o autor da pergunta é um preguiçoso que não quer aprender, apenas sugar. Dou voto negativo na pergunta dele.
5. Um ou mais outros usuários postam a resposta de graça.
6. Frequentemente (mas nem sempre) essas respostas postadas são de péssima qualidade, mas mesmo assim, uma delas pode acabar sendo aceita.
7. Outros votos de fechamento não são postados e a pergunta permanece aberta. Recebe até votos positivos.

O que fazer nesses casos?

Comment: Vejo algumas perguntas desses tipos. A última (talvez a que você esteja falando) eu observei os comentários do AP, porém ignorei a pergunta. Mas agora, acessando a pergunta mais uma vez, é triste ver que os novatos, para conseguirem reputação, respondem "de graça" como você mencionou. Iria até sinalizar, mas sinalizaria como? "Não está clara o suficiente"?

Comment: @bio para mim é fora de escopo, não é sobre programação

Comment: Bem, quando o usuário simplesmente joga o enunciado no corpo da pergunta e nem se da ao trabalho de elaborar um titulo, eu voto para fechar e dou negativo na pergunta. Muitas vezes eu nem comento, mas há poucos casos que eu comento quando eu percebo certa dificuldade no usuário em elaborar a questão, aí eu tento ajudar ele a deixar a pergunta mais clara.

Comment: Enquanto os que respondem, se a resposta for fraca ou simplesmente para ganhar reputação (sempre tem alguns sinais disto) eu deixo um comentário, porém, se for uma resposta bem elaborada (aquelas que salva a pergunta) eu não faço nada, nem comento e nem dou voto, entretanto, esses casos é difícil de acontecer, são bem raros mesmo.

Comment: É aquela questão de sempre: responde (de graça) quem quiser e o AP vota na resposta que quiser. Não são muitos raros os casos em que o AP vota numa resposta totalmente equivocada, enquanto outras que estão corretas são deixadas de lado. Mas isso é bem comum não só no SOpt quanto no SOen. Muitas respostas no SOen não marcadas, por exemplo, chovem de comentários "this should the accepted answer".... Num sistema de votos onde envolvem pessoas, pode-se esperar de tudo. Acontece muito de o AP leigo aceitar uma resposta de um AR mais leigo ainda.

Comment: Esse tipo de situação me motivou a [levantar uma proposta de funcionalidade aqui no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6842/incluir-sinalização-para-vampiro-de-ajuda), pensando na qualidade do site e no valoroso tempo que profissionais e entusiastas dedicam voluntariamente aqui. Acredito que "o que fazer" é, de fato, uma questão ainda aberta e merece atenção se - e somente se - esses dois pontos (e outros relacionados) for algo que a comunidade entenda como objetivo.

Comment: O que eu vejo muito são usuário em busca de pontuação respondendo pra ganhar uns pontos.. .como em geral são problemas fáceis pra quem sabe programar, são pontos fáceis, isso quando o usuário dá no mínimo um upvote.
Isso só ajuda a distorcer a proposta do SO, formar pessoas sem interesse em pensar e se esforçar, os futuros profissionais do mercado, e pessoas com reputação relevante mas sem uma resposta q realmente expresse um bom conhecimento.

Answer (score 11):

Traz a pergunta pra cá e deixa o [efeito Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect) acontecer. A maior parte do pessoal que frequenta o Meta tem reputação para votar para fechar, então a gente dá conta das perguntas ruins.

Comment: O evento recente que tive foi algo um pouco mais brando e suave em relação ao que descrevi, vez que busquei abranger também coisas que vi em casos mais antigos. No entanto, esse serviu para me fazer postar esta pergunta aqui no meta de uma vez por todas, coisa que já estava há um tempo pensando em fazer. De qualquer forma, aqui vai ele: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/283230/132 - Note que o AP tinha originalmente aceitado uma outra resposta e mudou de ideia depois disso.

Answer (score 7):

Gosto [desse comentário](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6887/votar-contra-e-votar-negativamente?noredirect=1#comment26515_6887):

> De qualquer forma, fica aqui uma oportunidade de negócio: você pode criar o seu próprio site de perguntas e respostas sobre programação, com pontuação semelhante ao Facebook - ou seja, sem a possibilidade de votos negativos. Talvez você faça sucesso com isso ;)

Esta seria mais ou menos a minha resposta. Claro a resposta real não é muito diferente da do Renan.

Fora isto eu acho que meio que temos que aceitar essas limitações e que não vamos conseguir a qualidade que desejamos. Eu temia ocorrer isto desde o início, muitos acharam que eu estava exagerando, até que chegamos no ponto que há mais ruído que informação útil. O que eu não percebi é que não tinha muito o que fazer com o mecanismo que temos.

Há reclamações dos usuários em geral sobre rejeição de conteúdo e dos usuários mais ativos que há muito problema para resolver.

Hoje acredito que o mecanismo e as regras que usamos não são boas para atender os dois públicos. E não acho que algo vá mudar, seja porque quem pode fazer isto não vê da mesma forma, seja porque estão caminhando a passos lentos em tudo.

Se pudéssemos classificar de forma ágil e fácil o conteúdo de uma forma mais rica, poderia resolver o problema de forma melhor e poderíamos aceitar muita coisa, até porque negativar e fechar não tem resolvido o problema. Inclusive boa parte dos argumentos sobre isto já estão em uma [resposta aqui no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6889/101).

Sumir com o conteúdo ruim é não é a solução, só votar ou fechar também não resolve o problema e chega até causar algum problema.

Hoje minha visão é que raramente as perguntas causam problemas reais, e quando causam elas precisam ser fechadas muito rapidamente. Perguntas que são duplicatas, não claras, que não podem ser respondidas e são porque a comunidade ou moderadores chegaram tarde demais são bastante prejudiciais. Fechar depois que o prejuízo ocorreu não resolve nada, no máximo não deixa o problema aumentar. Mas também evita resolver o problema de forma apropriada.

Cada vez mais acho que o problema não é bem a pergunta, mas o fato de não termos como classificar melhor a pergunta alertando quando ela tem problemas, e também forma de classificar de forma mais criteriosa e informativa quando uma resposta é ruim.

Pessoas sem capacidade de classificar algo está classificando e pessoas que poderiam evitar maiores problemas não podem fazê-lo. A gamificação não está funcionando como um mecanismo de promoção da qualidade e sim como incentivo à participação, e isto é o real problema.

Não estou com muito tempo, mas estou disposto a debater mais profundamente o o assunto, ainda que provavelmente não vá mudar nada, por isso comentário *linkado* no início desta resposta se torna algo apropriado, ainda que seja jocoso (incluindo o fato de eu ter o *linkado* :) e é bom explicar isso porque hoje em dias as pessoas estão tão mau humoradas, tão politicamente corretas que não conseguem perceber quando algo não é dito a sério).

Então a solução é comentar sobre o problema, votar, fechar, e chamar atenção no meta ou chat. Tinha época que funcionava muito bem, hoje nem tanto.