# Perguntas sendo fechadas por nada

Tags: debate, fechamento, perguntas-fechadas, razões-fechamento

Sou programador recente, e tenho ainda algumas dúvidas que sempre pergunto neste site. O que acontece é que minhas perguntas sempre são fechadas sem motivos, e já vi várias outras sendo fechadas por nada. A pessoa se esforça para colocar o máximo de detalhes em uma pergunta, informa detalhes sobre seu sistema operacional, a versão da linguagem de programação que está utilizando, e sempre são fechadas por nada. Sinceramente queria saber porque elas são fechadas, já que a ajuda do site diz o que você pode ter feito de errado e não é nenhum desses.

Comment: Mostre pra gente quais perguntas estão sendo fechadas por nada. Nada é um péssimo motivo para fechar perguntas, inclusive oficialmente não tem esse motivo para escolher na hora de fechar, portanto se é isso mesmo estão escolhendo um motivo falso. Se ma gente ver do que está falando fica difícil responder. Se esforçar para colocar o máximo de detalhes e colocar o máximo de detalhes são coisas distintas. As perguntas podem receber negativos por falta de esforço, mas mesmo com ele as perguntas podem ser fechadas. Colocar detalhes demais é um motivo oficial para fechamento.

Comment: Ou seja, esta pergunta aqui no meta carece de detalhes para ser respondida. Será que viu outras assim e não percebeu que faltava detalhes? E está difícil de ler por não usar pontuação (que não é motivo para fechamento, mas cria má vontade das pessoas e passa a impressão de que a pessoa que fez não esforçou tanto assim, ou ainda que não entenderá uma ajuda, porque programação é mais difícil que a gramática do Português. Obrigado pela pergunta ser sincera.

Comment: Sempre tem um motivo, e ele aparece em um box azul logo abaixo do título da pergunta (e geralmente tem links com uma explicação mais detalhada). Antes de achar que é sem motivo, eu sugiro que procure entender melhor como o site funciona, lendo [aqui](/q/8045/112052) e [aqui](/q/7256/112052). Sim, é muita coisa pra ler, mas garanto que se tiver o esforço de ler tudo, vai entender melhor quais são os motivos e porque eles existem. Mesmo que não concorde com tudo, pelo menos terá mais embasamento para argumentar (aí vc pode até [edit] esta pergunta detalhando melhor porque vc acha injusto)

Comment: E sobre fechamentos, leia [aqui](/q/7470/112052) - e se acha que um fechamento foi injusto, precisa colocar o link da pergunta e seus argumentos, para que possamos discutir e ver se foi mesmo injusto. Mas antes eu sugiro que leia os outros links já indicados, para que a argumentação tenha fundamento com base nas regras do site (pois historicamente percebemos que argumentar com base no que você acha que deveria ser e não no que realmente é, geralmente não acaba sendo muito produtivo...)

Answer (score 3):

> *...O que acontece é que minhas perguntas sempre são fechadas sem motivos...*

Então o pode ser feito é a análise de suas perguntas fechadas, pois fui autor do voto de fechamento em uma delas.

- [Não consigo importar o módulo turtle, mesmo com ele instalado no pip [fechada]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/508639/137387)

O texto da pergunta:

> Estou aprendendo novos módulos para utilizar nos meus programas em
> python,e um muito falado que parece ser muito útil é o turtle, porém
> sempre que tento importá-lo com `import turle` recebo a mensagem:
> `no module named turle`. Sei que muitos falarão que é só instalar
> no pip, com `pip install turtle`, mas já fiz isso e sempre diz que
> já está instalado! Desinstalei e reinstalei três vezes e nada. Queria
> saber como posso utilizar o turtle com estes erros. Estou utilizando o
> python 3.8.8.
>
> python

Então o título que você está tentando importar o módulo **`turtle`** e faz uso da instrução:

```
import turle
```

E resultado é sempre o mesmo:

```
no module named turle
```

E alega que já o módulo já foi instalado meio a linha de comando:

```
pip install turtle
```

Então se destacar o que digitou e a mensagem de erro obtida, teremos:

## `import turle`

## `no module named turle`

O deixa claro que se trata de um erro de digitação você queria escrever **`turtle`** mas escreveu **`turle`**, sabendo que [pedido de correção ou revisão de erros de digitação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/514/o-que-fazer-com-perguntas-que-apenas-procuram-code-review-for-typos/559#559) são considerados off topic e devem ser inicialmente fechados e posteriormente removido do site.

- [Número aleatório em uma repetição while em Python [fechada]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/500539/137387)

O texto da pergunta:

> Estava tentando fazer um jogo em Python, onde o computador sorteia uma
> palavra e temos que adivinhar qual é. Mas, quando o código entra na
> repetição while True, a palavra sorteada é sempre a mesma, e eu queria
> que cada repetição sorteasse uma nova palavra. Aqui o meu código:

```
def sortlist():
    words = ['Caixa', 'Computador']
    n = random.choice(words)

n = sortlist()



if n == 'Caixa':
    t1 = input('\033[1;32mObjeto muito ultilizado para guardar coisas\n\033[1;36m')
    if t1 == 'Caixa' or t1 == 'caixa':
        jn = input('\033[1;32mParabéns,você acertou: {}! Digite "s" sem aspas caso queira jogar de novo. Senão, aperte enter   \033[1;36m'.format(n))
    else:
        t2 = input('\033[1;32mVocê errou! Outra dica: este objeto é muito ultilizado como pacote para entregas\n\033[1;36m')
        if t2 == 'Caixa' or t2 == 'caixa':
            jn = input('\033[1;32mParabéns,você acertou: {}! Digite "s" sem aspas caso queira jogar de novo. Senão, aperte enter   \033[1;36m'.format(n))
        else:
            t3 = input('\033[1;32mVocê errou! Última chance: geralmente este objeto é da cor marrom\n\033[1;36m')
            if t3 == 'Caixa' or t3 == 'caixa':
                jn = input('\033[1;32mParabéns,você acertou: {}! Digite "s" sem aspas caso queira jogar de novo. Senão, aperte enter   \033[1;36m'.format(n))
            else:
                jn = input('\033[1;32mVocê errou nas 3 (três) tentativas! A palavra era: {}. Mais sorte da próxima vez... Digite "s" sem aspas caso queira jogar de novo.\nSenão, aperte enter   \033[1;36m'.format(n)) else:
    input('oi')


while True:
    if jn == 's' or jn == 'S':
        n = sortlist()



        if n == 'Caixa':
            t1 = input('\033[1;32mObjeto muito ultilizado para guardar coisas\n\033[1;36m')
            if t1 == 'Caixa' or t1 == 'caixa':
                jn = input('\033[1;32mParabéns,você acertou: {}! Digite "s" sem aspas caso queira jogar de novo. Senão, aperte enter   \033[1;36m'.format(n))
            else:
                t2 = input('\033[1;32mVocê errou! Outra dica: este objeto é muito ultilizado como pacote para entregas\n\033[1;36m')
                if t2 == 'Caixa' or t2 == 'caixa':
                    jn = input('\033[1;32mParabéns,você acertou: {}! Digite "s" sem aspas caso queira jogar de novo. Senão, aperte enter   \033[1;36m'.format(n))
                else:
                    t3 = input('\033[1;32mVocê errou! Última chance: geralmente este objeto é da cor marrom\n\033[1;36m')
                    if t3 == 'Caixa' or t3 == 'caixa':
                        jn = input('\033[1;32mParabéns,você acertou: {}! Digite "s" sem aspas caso queira jogar de novo. Senão, aperte enter   \033[1;36m'.format(n))
                    else:
                        jn = input('\033[1;32mVocê errou nas 3 (três) tentativas! A palavra era: {}. Mais sorte da próxima vez... Digite "s" sem aspas caso queira jogar de novo.\nSenão, aperte enter   \033[1;36m'.format(n))   
        else:
            input('oi')
    
    else:
        input('bye!')
```

> Tentei trocar as repetições por sorteios de números, onde 0 = 'Caixa'
> 1 = 'Computador', mas aconteceu algo muito estranho: quando a
> repetição finalmente chegava em 'Caixa', a partir daí a repetição era
> sempre 'Caixa", mas depois de 3 repetições assim sempre sorteava
> 'Computador', e depois 'Caixa' mais tres vezes e vcs entenderam o
> ciclo. Eu vi uma explicação envolvendo variáveis, mas eu realmente não
> entendi. Gostaria que vocês me explicassem de maneira clara, por
> favor.

Se ignorarmos o [código prolixo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120931/o-dry-%C3%A9-para-evitar-redund%C3%A2ncias-certo/120932#120932) e desnecessário a pergunta é possível ver que trata de um erro de semântica elementar que pode ser verificado depurando o a função `sortlist():`, veja o [Exemplo Mínimo Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
>>>import random

>>>def sortlist():
...    words = ['Caixa', 'Computador']
...    n = random.choice(words)

>>>print(sortlist())
None
```

Ou seja sua função não [retorna](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=return#the-return-statement) valor algum o que implica `n` sempre será `None` e suas declarações de controle de fluxo `if n == 'Caixa':` sempre cairão no bloco `else:` e ficarão indefinidamente repetindo:

```
oi
oi
oi
oi
oi
oi
oi
.
. 
.
```

Como [perguntas sobre o retorno de função em python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Python+return+is%3Aquestion) já foram feitas aos montes, 231 resultados até o momento que escrevo, não fazendo sentido ter mais uma e tão específica. Devendo assim ser fechada e ficar ao critério da comunidade sua remoção.

***Assim não sendo verdadeira a afirmação de que suas perguntas sempre são fechadas sem motivos!***
Respondendo sua outra pergunta:

> ...Sinceramente queria saber porque elas são fechadas, já que a ajuda do
> site diz o que você pode ter feito de errado e não é nenhum desses...

Agora você sabe.

E quanto as:

> ...várias outras sendo fechadas por nada...

Acredito que no momento não esteja em condições de avaliar perguntas de terceiros e que deva se concentrar nas orientações passadas nos comentários da questão que levantou.

Comment: eu não digitei isso no programa, só digitei errado na pergunta

Comment: Então nós trabalhamos com o que está na pergunta e não com o que está na sua máquina. E mesmo assim instalação, configuração, reparo de módulos e pacotes não faz part do [escopo do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic)

Comment: @ArturCarneiroBarroso Se digitou algo errado na pergunta, bastava [editá-la](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing) e colocar a informação correta. Como o Augusto já disse, a única informação que temos - e com a qual podemos trabalhar - é o que está na pergunta, não temos como adivinhar o que não está lá. E se falta alguma informação importante, então a pergunta é fechada por não estar clara (que é [um dos motivos existentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)). Ou seja, não é "injusto" e muito menos "por nada"

Comment: Lembrando que se editar e a pergunta passar a ter todas as informações necessárias - ou seja, um [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - ela pode ser reaberta sem problemas