# Dúvida sobre pergunta duplicada

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

Como já disse em outros tópicos, tenho imensa dificuldade em votar negativo. Entendo o quanto isso é importante ([teoria das janelas quebradas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/44/teoria-das-janelas-partidas?s=1%7C0.4228)), mas se o usuário é novo no site eu simplesmente não consigo.

Daí que ontem achei [uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77147/como-%C3%A9-que-eu-posso-abrir-uma-janela-modal-com-window-open) (de um usuário com 2,7k de rep, 290+ perguntas e mais de um ano de participação) bem vaga, e deixei um comentário:

> E o que você já tentou? Achei bem vago...

E não dei -1, mas foi quase, porque achei que o usuário tinha certa obrigação de apresentar melhor a pergunta...

A resposta (no outro dia):

> Queia entender esse forum. Tem uns caras aqui muito babaca. Se eu
>   abrisse a pergunta e pedisse duas respostas, violaria as regras e
>   mereceria o downvote. Aí abri duas perguntas e mesmo assim recebo. O
>   que me deu o downvote, são duas perguntas distintas. Uma é como abri
>   uma janela modal com window.open(), seja no chrome, IE, opera e etc. E
>   outra é uma janela modal no Chrome, seja com window.open(),
>   ShowModalDialog, pois com javascript(ShowModalDialog) não consigo
>   fazer. Funciona no IE mas não no Chrome.

Então voltei de novo pra página principal (logo após enviar o comentário, antes da resposta acima) e encontrei [esta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77145/janela-modal-no-chrome), do mesmo usuário, postada praticamente no mesmo momento (só consegui ver as horas, já não aparecia mais os minutos).

Aí já achei demais, sinalizei e votei negativo (nas duas),  e deixei outro comentário (e aqui talvez devesse ter sido mais suave...):

> -1 Cara, sério mesmo que você tá abrindo duas perguntas praticamente iguais: pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77147/… ???

A resposta:

> Não ha resposta. La no outro fala do window.open()e aqui pergunto
>   sobre chrome, como fazer uma janela modal. Esse site tá ficando mais,
>   devido uns caras aqui. Isso é que dá ficar permitindo qualquer um para
>   opinar. Podem dar downvote, uns babacas que não sabem discernir a mão
>   esquerda da direita.

Nem vou entrar no fato de um usuário consolidado ainda chamar o SOpt de "fórum" (quase postei um comentário enlatado, tirando o "seja bem vindo ao SOpt", talvez devesse ter feito isso...), o que queria saber é o seguinte: As perguntas são ou não são duplicatas? Eu acho que sim, porque a questão é abrir a janela modal... bastaria colocar os detalhes do que acontece em cada navegador e pronto.

[O Stack Overflow em Português é um fórum?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2068/o-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas-%c3%a9-um-f%c3%b3rum)

Comment: Mas o fato dele ainda não entender que aqui não é um fórum é sintomático para entender porque ele ainda não entendeu o funcionamento do site. Ah, o comentário lá é ofensivo e deveria ser removido.

Comment: Cara, o que você diz do sopt é assunto seu. Tudo onde há interpretação, opiniões e coisas assim, isso é um fórum. Aceite ou não. Vou remover o(s) comentário(s) para mostrar minhas intenções aqui. A questão de ser ou não um fórum não depende do que eu quero. O comportamento é que define o que é ou não.

Comment: @pnet volte ser humilde como era aqui http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1248/off-topic-sobre-pontua%c3%a7%c3%a3o-e-outras-coisas-mais/1252#comment2911_1252 e as coisas vão melhorar para você. Ter a atitude que você está tendo agora só vai te prejudicar.

Comment: @bigown, vou dar por encerrado esse assunto, que está fugindo do objetivo. Errei em alguns casos, mas minha discordância está no fato de dizerem que a pergunta era duplicada. A chamada pergunta "mal feita" apareceu depois. Os votos foram para a pergunta por acaharem duplicada e volto a repetir. A palavra Modal estava nas duas perguntas, mas eram bem diferentes. Uma para o chrome que não aceita Modal, mesmo usando o ShowModalDialog e a outra era para a função javascript, window.open() se podia ser Modal em qualquer browser, mas essa já vi que não dá. Sei que exagerei em alguns pontos.

Comment: @bigown, continuando, sei que exagerei, mas a forma como são os critérios de alguns aqui, realmente fica difícil. Os caras parecem que não lê os posts e vão tomando decisões baseadas em "eu acho". Vou continuar no SOpt, evitar essas brigas bobas que independente de se queimar ou não, não nos leva a lugar nenhum, mas não vou me calar e nem me tolir do direito de protestar.

Comment: Ás vezes exageramos no português, pois ofensa é sempre ruim, mesmo para quem tá certo. Fiquei muito chateado mesmo, ao dizerem que era duplicado o post e continuo não aceitando. Porem, fazemos coisas que nos faz refletir depois, mas o problema é que já fizemos. Soltar um saco de penas no vento e depois recolher todas é impossível. Não me sinto bem ofendendo pessoas, mas já fiz, infelizmente. O que tenho que fazer é me policiar a esse respeito, para que isso não venha a ocorrer. Agora, não levarei essa culpa só. Terminando. Eram 2 POSTS DISTINTOS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gostaria de apenas comentar - mas não posso no momento.
Sou novo no SOpt, e também no stackoverflow original, em inglês, mas já passei por algumas situações "estressantes", e já vi muitas outras acontecerem.

Na minha pouca experiência, o que eu aprendi foi:

1. Confie no sistema

Eu já esperneei algumas vezes apenas para descobrir em seguida que meu problema já havia sido resolvido. O SOpt é uma "comunidade", e é vivo nesse sentido. O fato de tudo acontecer por meio de votos, reduz bastante a chance de erro. Por mais que um ou outro discorde, o bom senso da maioria eventualmente "vence".

2. Não tenha medo de votar (negativo ou positivo)

Baseado no que eu escrevi acima - a participação é muito importante para o sistema funcionar. **Mais importante do que o medo de votar**. Quanto mais pessoas votam, menor é a chance do resultado estar equivocado no final, pois se tem uma amostra melhor de opiniões.

3. Não se estresse!

Karma, pelo visto, é uma realidade nas comunidades do StackExchange. Se você vir, as perguntas citadas já estão com -3 ou -4 votos, e já foram marcadas como duplicatas. Claro, o seu post aqui provavelmente ajudou. Mas de qualquer maneira, o site disponibiliza ferramentas para resolver tais questões. Existem os votos, as sinalizações e os comentários. É um "combo", na minha opinião, praticamente indefensável. Portanto, numa situação dessas, um voto, um comentário, e em última instância, uma sinalização, são mais que suficientes para terem a questão resolvida.

Eu entendo a sua angústia, e eu provavelmente me sentiria igual. Mas acredito que este usuário esteja aprendendo, como todos nós. Eventualmente ele será "moldado" pela comunidade, ou a deixará, por conta própria.

Comment: Excelente resposta. Só pra constar, os votos negativos nas perguntas já estavam -4 e -3 quando criei o tópico aqui. O que acontece é que este usuário já tem muito tempo "de casa", e muita participação, portanto o argumento de que esteja aprendendo é inválido. Mas mesmo assim gostei da sua resposta... +1 E seja bem vindo ao SOpt! :)

Comment: Off-topic: Eu ia sugerir que ele fosse indicado à página de etiqueta do SOpt, mas não a encontrei... Talvez porque ela se chame [be nice](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)?

Answer (score 4):

Concordo com o Gustavo, sim o usuário exagerou ao ofender os colegas.

Eu não negativei (downvote, voto para baixo) a pergunta, porque eu não entendi nada da duvida, não só porque **não está clara**, mas também porque eu realmente não sabia o que ele queria dizer com Modal.

No entanto não discordo de quem votou negativo, o voto aqui não é uma **ataque pessoal** como muitos pensam e acho que não cabe discutir aqui os votos negativos, apenas a falha a da pergunta que levou a estes votos negativos.

### Aonde está o problema da pergunta do usuário

Isto é uma resposta ao @pnet também, as pessoas aqui não dão votos negativos porque é uma pergunta distinta ou não é distinta, elas negativaram porque existe um problema nela que **pra você** parece *claro*, mas para a maioria das pessoas **não é**.

Modal em **tecnologias web** pode ser qualquer coisa para a maioria dos desenvolvedores (não quer dizer que realmente seja um modal), exemplos de situações do que é modal para a maioria dos desenvolvedores, 3 exemplos:

1. Janela Modal pode ser uma janela sem barra de endereços e sem funcionalidades de navegação, apenas com conteúdos e o botão fechar.
2. Janela Modal pode ser uma janela que bloqueia a janela que a chamou e retorna uma resposta pra janela chamadora.
3. Janela modal pode ser um `<iframe>` flutuante que sobrepõe os demais elementos (tá eu sei que está é meio difícil ser a duvida, mas continue lendo que irei explicar)

Estes 3 são os possíveis tipos de modal, mas ainda sim o problema não é só saber o tipo de modal que você quer, o problema é que você não expôs a sua necessidade, tenho certeza que se tive-se escrito perguntas como:

- > **Como fazer o popup bloquear a janela "pai"?**
  >   Gostaria de saber se é possível no momento que abrir um pop-up com `window.open` ele bloqueia a janela que o chamou e quando fecho o pop-up ele desbloqueia?
- > **É possível ocultar a url do pop-up?**
  >   Estou criando um pop-up, mas ele sempre mostra o url da página e gostaria que isto não ocorre-se, é possível?

Apesar de serem perguntas simples, ainda sim elas demostram a sua necessidade e foi isto que faltou na sua duvida, qual a **sua necessidade**:

- A primeira pergunta diz que a necessidade **é bloquear o conteúdo a janela pai**
- A segunda pergunta diz que a necessidade **é ocultar a janela url do pop-up**.

---

### Somos arbitrários?

Não vou entrar na discussão, pois não estou defendendo ninguém e não sei como foi a tal discussão no passado com o @bigown ou qualquer outro usuário. No momento atual ele só esta tentando lhe orientar da melhor maneira possível, não deves levar a mal.

Mas vou comentar a sua resposta:

- > Sei que você gosta de se mostrar responsável pelo sopt.

  Ele apenas está fazendo o que todos (até você @pnet) devem fazer, somos todos responsáveis, ele não está se mostrando o único responsável, ele está colaborando com uma função que todos devemos fazer, apenas isto e não vejo mal algum nisto.
- > Estejam à vontade para negativar minhas respostas.

  Ninguém está negativando porque quer o seu mal, aqui no META os votos negativos são diferentes do SOpt, eles só servem pra entoar a opinião na resolução de um problema, apenas isto.
- > O critério é pessoal. Mas para tristeza de alguns, não vou sair. Se quiserem isso, terão que me tirar.

  Ninguém quer que você saia, por favor não confunda, é muito pelo contrário, as pessoas aqui querem que você fique, eu mesmo até respondi a sua pergunta sobre modal (mesmo não tendo entendido ela) e dei um +1 na pergunta pra lhe auxiliar.

As pessoas aqui só querem que você entenda o funcionamento do site, pois você já tem tempo de casa. Apenas isto, ninguém aqui está fazendo um ataque pessoal, eu mesmo recebi uma vez -5 em uma resposta minha e eu já tinha um certo tempo de casa também. O problema é que a minha resposta estava equivocada, apenas isto.

### Somos um fórum? Porque o fórum mudou tanto?

O site não mudou e também não é um fórum, desde o começo do **beta publico** ouve pessoas que fizeram reclamações iguais a sua, então o site não mudou, ele sempre foi assim, na verdade ouso dizer que entre o SOen e o SOpt, aqui o pessoal negativa bem menos.

No fórum são aceitos problemas sem detalhes, pois nele vamos discutindo até chegar ao entendimento da pergunta e depois sim começamos tentar a responder, o que geralmente é um processo chato e longo.

O SOpt e os demais sites da rede são Q&A, traduzindo ***pergunta*** e **respostas**, então aqui a pergunta já deve ser clara desde o começo e as respostas devem resolver o problema e não servem para debater ou tirar duvidas com o autor da pergunta.

Veja no FAQ o que significa votar contra: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

### Como fazer uma boa pergunta

O link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask dá um bom entendimento de como fazer uma pergunta, a sua pergunta faltou o *Seja específico* e o *Torne-a relevante para outros*, como eu disse antes, você **deve** expor a sua necessidade. Os exemplos estão acima de como a pergunta teria sido melhor elaborada (apesar de simples exemplos).

### Conclusão

Acredito que com isto o usuário entenda e evite desrespeitar os colegas e com as dicas passadas aqui ele consiga formular melhor as duvidas pra sua necessidade.

@pnet espero que a minha resposta tenha lhe ajudado e por favor responda meu comentário lá na sua pergunta, tenho certeza que é possível recupera-la :)

Espero que possamos ser todos amigos.

Comment: Eu concordo com tudo, exceto com a sua definição de modal. Pra mim só a (2) é modal :)

Comment: @bfavaretto Parece ter razão, mas o entendimento também parece variar para cada pessoa, por exemplo o modal do bootstrap não é um modal de verdade é um Div sobreposto. Usei o iframe como exemplo apenas. O primeiro exemplo (ocultar barra de endereço) não é uma definição minha, mas me parece que é o entendimento de várias pessoas e por isto que o citei. No entanto você está correto sobre o modal, vou tentar editar :)

Comment: @bfavaretto edição: *Modal em **tecnologias web** pode ser qualquer coisa para a maioria dos desenvolvedores (não quer dizer que realmente seja um modal)*

Comment: Boa :) O tipo de modal do bootstrap é o que é possível na web, acho que por isso que eles deram esse nome.

Comment: Veja que concordo tanto contigo que o inicio da resposta  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/77331/3635 fala isto: *"... se o que você quer dizer com modal é a nova janela bloquear a janela que chamou este modal ou ocultar a barra de endereços."*. :) Boa noite @bfavaretto, obrigado

Answer (score -4):

Bem, não é a minha preocupação com os votos negativos. Eu fiz duas perguntas distintas. Uma para javascript e outra para o Chrome. Acontece que em ambas há a palavra MODAL. Mas são duas coisas diferentes. Se eu fizesse a pergunta assim: Como eu faço uma janela, frame ou página no Chrome Modal? E também gostaria de saber como eu coloco o window.open() modal em qualquer browser. Seria criticado por fazer uma pergunta com duas respostas distintas. Agora, não vou aqui ficar me debatendo com esse conluio arquitetado, apenas para justificarem o voto negativo. Podem dar quantos quiserem, já disse, não é isso que eu me preocupo, mas sim com o caminho que o SOPT está tomando, dado ao juízo de alguns.
  Outra coisa, pessoal. Dizer que o SOPT não é forum? Bem, recomendo a dar uma olhada no significado da palavra forum e depois postem o que acharam. Podem achar o que quiserem a meu respeito, se querem me cortar do forum, pelo que eu entendi, é a vontade do Daniel Gomes, estejam à vontade, mas apenas gostaria que o forum voltasse a ser o que ele era no seu início. Uma comunidade com o objetivo de ajudar, de fazer das necessidades dos outros a sua própria. Infelizmente não é o que vejo agora, infelizmente. Uma pena o caminho que está sendo tomado, uma pena mesmo. Está na cabeça das pessoas fazer o que querem.

Comment: O problema não é com as perguntas serem distintas ou não amigo, eu não votei negativo pois não entendi a pergunta, mas eu iria votar por fechar, no entanto tentei formular uma resposta, veja lá por favor. O problema é que pra você modal é uma coisa e pra outras pessoas modal pode ser outra coisa, você não colocou a sua necessidade e isto dificultou o entendimento, eu não votaria negativo, apenas fecharia a pergunta até que você arruma-se ela, mas preferi manter aberta pra tentar lhe orientar.

Comment: Aqui não é um fórum e o sistema sempre funcionou assim, se a pergunta é vaga geralmente o pessoal negativa para demonstrar que a pergunta não está compreensível, apenas isto não é por mal. O SOpt é um Q&A, fóruns aceitam perguntas vagas, pois em fóruns podem haver várias postagens até chegar a solução, já o Q&A é só pergunta e respostas se discussão para muitos entendimentos, a diferença aqui é que a pergunta já deve ser clara e objetiva desde o inicio, não me leve a mal por favor, apenas não dá pra entender a sua necessidade na pergunta.

Comment: Espero que compreenda e por favor veja se a resposta lhe ajuda, se for realmente a sua necessidade for bloquear a janela que chamou o modal então editarei a sua pergunta pra ficar mais clara e tenho certeza que irá recuperar alguns pontos após isto.

Comment: @pnet você anda esperneando a toa. Você voltou a ter algumas das suas atitudes do início, vendo coisas onde não tem e se recusando a entender os problemas das suas perguntas. Sei lá se você está passando por um omento ruim, se há algo psicológico que esteja lhe atrapalhando, mas o site, que não é um fórum, você já devia saber disto (recomendo começar pelo [tour], mas leia), não mudou, não apareceram pessoas que são o que você está as ofendendo. Quem está aqui há bastante tempo nota uma mudança no seu comportamento. Talvez por frustração por não conseguir evoluir no seu uso. Entenda o site.

Comment: Pnet, lamento se de qualquer forma você se sentiu ofendido, pode acreditar que não foi minha intenção. Eu até poderia ter dado o voto negativo e não ter dito nada, mas achei que seria covardia. Talvez eu devesse ter sido mais suave no segundo comentário, como disse na pergunta, mas isso não justifica certas coisas que você está dizendo. Ninguém aqui quer te tirar do site. Eu, inclusive, te acho um tipo de usuário muito importante (mais *perguntador* do que *respondedor*, como eu btw :)). Só acho que você precisa entender um pouco melhor o que é o site.

Comment: Ok, mais uma resposta para voto negativo. Meu momento, bigown, é ótimo e ainda não estou frustrado. Sei que você gosta de se mostrar responsável pelo sopt. Mesmo que nunca mais terei resposta nas minhas perguntas, mas não concordei pela forma com o tratamento que minha resposta recebeu. Estejam à vontade para negativar minhas respostas. Sua resposta, bigown, está baseada numa discussão que tivemos no passado e é isso que tenho dito. O critério é pessoal. Mas para tristeza de alguns, não vou sair. Se quiserem isso, terão que me tirar.

Comment: pode ao menos responder estas duvidas minhas... sobre o seu entendimento de modal: Modal pra você é uma janela que bloqueia a janela que chama? Ou modal pra você é uma janela sem a barra de endereços? Ou seriam ambas?

Comment: Veja isto http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4202/3635

Comment: @pnet vou fazer só uma pergunta: Será que somos nós todos que estamos errados e você certo? Pense nisso.

Comment: @JorgeB., ninguém aqui está falando sobre certo ou errado. O que acho às vezes é uma espécie de conluio, ou seja, um diz algo e aí todos vão naquela direção, sem ao menos um juízo sequer, mas como eu disse, gostaria de encerrar esse assunto. Agora, o fato de 100 dizerem alguma coisa e 1 o contrário, isso não garante que os 100 estejam certos. Não estou dizendo que eu estou certo, mas eu fiz dois posts distintos só isso. Bom dia para todos. Quanto mais ficarmos aqui fazendo perguntas, comentários, mais essa situação aumenta. Gostaria de encerrar o assunto, mas dependo da colaboração de todos.

Comment: @pnet eu bem sei que lá por 100 dizerem uma coisa é sinal de estarem certos. Foi só para você pensar nisso. Reparou que desde a minha edição da pergunta ela está com saldo positivo? Eu vou ser sincero as suas perguntas são quase sempre muito confusas de perceber. Quando alguém te dá -1 ou um comentário a dizer que não percebeu a pergunta não precisas enervar, é sinal que tens de ver como podes melhorar a pergunta.

Comment: @JorgeB., agradeço a edição sim. Mas lembre de uma coisa, os downvotes foram devidos a pergunta "Duplicada" e não pergunta mal elaborada. Foi esse o motivo do meu protesto, pois eram dois posts distintos, a pesar de ambos terem a palavra Modal. Mas como eu disse, gostaria que esse assunto ficasse no passado.

Comment: Já está no passado! Bom, o motivo da minha resposta, era dizer que não adianta a gente se irritar uns com os outros. A comunidade é um bicho a parte e é ela quem decide no final. Eu posso reclamar e dizer que minha pergunta ou resposta estão certas - mas se a comunidade não concordar, **não há o que fazer!** A parte boa disso, é que ela normalmente é bem coerente! (Note que eu não disse "certa"). Então se aprendermos a lidar com esse bicho novo, que é a comunidade, tiraremos melhor proveito dela (não dê atenção a mim, eu não sou ninguém - ouça a comunidade!).

Comment: Para dar suporte ao meu ponto, gostaria de compartilhar um link que você provavelmente já conhece - é de um dos _criadores do stackoverflow_. Ele, numa questão complicada, escreveu uma resposta que atraiu **9 votos negativos**. Eu particularmente gosto do fato de que ele, sabendo como o site que ele ajudou a criar funciona, não quis apagar seu post, deixando como exemplo para todos: [Is the language “BrainF_ck” offensive?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24206/251152)