# Comentários enlatados para situações comuns

Tags: suporte, comportamento, comentários

Quando trabalhamos nas filas de análise ou simplesmente navegamos pelo site, é comum vermos o mesmo tipo de problema múltiplas vezes, tanto em perguntas como respostas.

A intenção desta postagem é construir comunitariamente um repositório de comentários úteis para esse tipo de situação. Os comentários devem ser educados e conter orientações ao usuário, para que ele aprenda como funciona o site e não repita o erro.

Fiquem à vontade para editar os comentários abaixo e incluir novos (como Wiki da Comunidade, por favor). Por favor, mantenha a formatação conforme as respostas já existentes. Quem quiser automatizar a inserção desses comentários pode utilizar a [extensão AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) ([disponível na Chrome Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/denkbaalahjlbbfnifkacdigaofcnogg)). Os comentários postados aqui como respostas podem ser importados na extensão usando Node.js, com o código disponibilizado [aqui](https://github.com/bfavaretto/sopt-enlatados).

Se não gostar de nenhum parcialmente e acha que não é questão de melhorá-los aqui faça a sua versão e use.

---

## Índice de comentários enlatados

- [Usuário responde a pergunta somente com links (ou quase).](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/708/28595)
- [Autor da pergunta responde só para agradecer.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/28595)
- [Usuário responde a pergunta para solicitar mais informações.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/709/28595)
- [Outro usuário fazendo pergunta ou dizendo "eu também".](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/712/28595)
- [Pergunta/feedback do OP na área de respostas.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/711/28595)
- [Ajudando o autor a clarificar uma pergunta.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1314/28595)
- [Usuário cria pergunta com saudações e você deseja deixar um recado após removê-las para não parecer tão grosseiro.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1810/28595)
- [Usuário novato cria múltiplas perguntas duplicadas.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3751/28595)
- [Seja mais específico na pergunta (com metáfora).](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1481/28595)
- [Usuário responde a uma pergunta com outra pergunta.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2648/28595)
- [Ajudando o autor da pergunta a aceitar uma resposta.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1311/28595)
- [Usuário cria pergunta em inglês.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1423/28595)
- [A pergunta tem links para o site onde está ocorrendo o problema, em vez de mostrar o código relevante na própria pergunta.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2409/28595)
- [Orientando o autor da pergunta a aceitar a resposta.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6972/132)
- [Ajudando o autor sobreviver no SOpt.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8046/2541)
- [Usuário publica no META uma pergunta que deveria ser feita na página principal.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8290/137387)
- [Autor publicou código e/ou mensagem de erro como imagem.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8434/3774)
- [Usuário responde apenas com código](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8436/100416)
- [Usuário cria pergunta apenas com um enunciado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8445/100416)
- [Pergunta pertence a outra comunidade da rede SE](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8449/3774)
- [O usuário cria uma série de perguntas e ou respostas contendo agradecimentos.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8773/137387)

---

## Observações adicionais ao postar comentários enlatados

- Atenção para não usar links desatualizados:

  Os links começam com `https://pt`, ou `https://meta.pt` e não `https://br`
- Lembrem-se que links do site podem ser simplificados desta forma:

  `https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/707/comentários-enlatados-para-situações-comuns` pode ser escrito como `https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/707/` e para uma das respostas nessa pergunta `https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/ID-RESPOSTA/`.

---

## Para postar resposta a esta pergunta

Para responder a esta pergunta aqui no meta, tenha em mente o seguinte:

- Como fazer para o source ficar copiável sem virar link automático:

  Basta escapar a primeira [do link com uma barra invertida, e o https:// com um &#47; assim:

  ```
    \[Palavra chave](https:&#47;/www.example.com/meu/link.html)
  ```

  (afinal, que tipo de programador você é? ;D )
- O seu preview é usado automaticamente no *script de enlatados* do @bfavaretto, lembre de iniciá-lo com a marcação de nota `>`:

  ```
    >Que bom que você...
  ```

  Caso queira usar o script, o endereço é: https://github.com/bfavaretto/sopt-enlatados/blob/master/app.js
- Ao sugerir uma tradução, lembre-se de verificar se o assunto já está "em pauta" no meta.

Comment: Faltam comentários p/ perguntas. Outro exemplo é algo para isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3935/rest-hateoas-e-java-quem-ja-usou.

Comment: Já havia manifestado a minha concordância com todos os enlatamentos que sugeriste, mas estava agora a ler os mesmos com um pouco mais de calma e devo dizer que chumbava tudo se estivesses a escrever dessa forma em Portugal :P _(Brasileiro, you did it again!)_

Comment: Como assim "chumbava tudo", @Zuul? Se quer dizer que o tom está duro demais, eu concordo, e acho que não é nada simpático nem para os brasileiros. É um defeito que tenho quando tento escrever textos que sejam completos e objetivos. Acabam ficando muito formais e duros. Seu tom é bem mais leve, não quer tentar melhorar?

Comment: @bfavaretto Não é o tom, falava do texto, está mesmo mesmo mesmo à Brasileiro... :( Tem pouco ou nada de Tuga!

Comment: @Zuul, acho que enquanto não nos familiarizarmos mais com uns com os outros, vamos ter esse tipo de problema. A participação de usuários de ambos todos os lados do Português pode ajudar que os textos fiquem imparciais no maior grau possível.

Comment: @EMBarbosa É verdade, todos os dias tempo arranjar um motivo para chatear o bfavaretto com questões divergentes entre o português de Portugal e o português do Brasil :) (Mas fora de brincadeira, concordo que com o passar do tempo os textos vão-se compondo de forma a que façam sentido a ambos os Portugueses.)

Comment: Com a tradução dos motivos oficiais, alguns dos enlatados contidos aqui ficaram obsoletos. Alguns nem tanto porque o daqui pode dar informação melhor. Aí temos que ver se os oficiais podem ser melhorados.

Comment: @bfavaretto que aconteceu ao script que não está a funcionar. Pelo menos aqui...

Comment: Não sei, @JorgeB., pra mim também não está funcionando. Acho que foi alguma mudança no código do site. Não vi nenhuma referência ao problema no bug tracker do projeto (do AutoReviewComments). Mas precisaria testar melhor antes de postar um bug lá, e ando meio sem tempo pra isso.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun Perguntas em inglês devem ser fechadas (até que sejam traduzidas), e tem um motivo de fechamento pra isso.

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu vi que o comentário pra quando o usuário postar uma pergunta em inglês foi excluído porque este virou um motivo de fechamento. Mas, ainda assim, não seria interessante termos o comentário? São necessários 5 votos para a pergunta ser fechada, em momentos "mais calmos" do site, isso pode acabar passando despercebido e eu acho importante alertar o AP por meio de um comentário. Na verdade, mesmo quando a pergunta é fechada eu acho que é melhor comentar, pra parecer mais sútil. Claro que ainda temos a opção de escrever o comentário, mas ainda acho interessante termos ele aqui.

Comment: @jbueno faz sentido, restaurei.

Comment: Acho que o pessoal tem invertido o *preview* com o *source*. Dentro da citação deve estar o *markdown*, não é? @bfavaretto

Comment: Muito bom o plugin, dá uma outra dinâmica aos comentários. Entertanto utilizei nessa pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180108/ajax-pots-em-script-que-usam-echo-varias-vezes e a minha questão é: devo usá-lo e em seguida votar para fechar a pergunta se tratando de um utilizador novo? O voto negativo eu dispenso nesse caso, acho que mais atrapalha do que ajuda, pelo menos para os mais novos, dá uma má impressão pelo fato da pessoa entender que é algo pessoal; o comentário com links é muito mais eficaz.

Comment: @filipe Eu costumo dar um tempo pra pessoa arrumar a pergunta antes de votar pra fechar, especialmente se for um usuário novo.

Comment: Se for publicar algo aqui reflita duas vezes antes de fazer. Leia as regras, leias todas as outras respostas, leia todos os comentários, não o faça por motivos egoístas(pensando nas eleições para moderador por exemplo) ou direcionado a uma única pessoa. Use do bom senso e vamos ser uteis e produtivos para com a comunidade.

Answer (score 25):

#### Usuário responde a pergunta somente com links (ou quase)

**Source:**

Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](https://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)

**Preview:**

> Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)

(Adaptado de comentários deixados pelo @bigown)

Comment: Reparei agora que a pergunta linkada aqui não tem resposta, e foi marcada como duplicata [dessa outra](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/215). Ambas as perguntas estão com a tag `proposta-para-faq`. Qual das duas é a "correta"?

Comment: Ela não tem resposta porque há um tempo fiz merge dela com a outra, que tinha mais votos e mais respostas. Atualizei o conteúdo aqui, e coloquei a tag faq na outra.

Answer (score 21):

#### Usuário responde a pergunta para solicitar mais informações

**Source:**

Legal você querer ajudar, mas você usou o campo de resposta para fazer um comentário. Você poderá postar comentários quando tiver [um pouco mais de pontos de reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor utilize o campo de resposta somente para postar uma solução ao problema de que a pergunta trata.

**Preview:**

> Legal você querer ajudar, mas você usou o campo de resposta para fazer um comentário. Você poderá postar comentários quando tiver [um pouco mais de pontos de reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor utilize o campo de resposta somente para postar uma solução ao problema de que a pergunta trata.

Answer (score 21):

#### Outro usuário fazendo pergunta ou dizendo "eu também"

**Source:**

Se você tem uma nova pergunta, por favor utilize o botão [Faça uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). A área que você usou para postar a pergunta é somente para respostas.

**Preview:**

> Se você tem uma nova pergunta, por favor utilize o botão [Faça uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). A área que você usou para postar a pergunta é somente para respostas.

Comment: Seria bom ter algo para a resposta "mee too", ou seja, "eu vou dizer o mesmo que outra pessoa disse"? Pelo menos avisar a pessoa evitar algo que pode atrair votos contrários para a resposta?

Comment: Você tem visto votarem contra esse tipo de resposta?

Comment: Não muito ainda. Eu queria algo para evitar que esse tipo de comportamento se prolifere :) Antes q vire um problema como é no SO.

Comment: Se você tem uma pergunta, então escolha a opção de [fazer uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Não tente pegar carona na pergunta dos outros. Veja mais sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5509/132).

Answer (score 20):

#### Autor da pergunta responde só para agradecer.

**Source:**

Que bom que você gostou das respostas! Mas a melhor forma de agradecer a quem te ajudou é assinalando "aceite" na melhor resposta e votando em todas que te ajudaram. Assim você garante que quem escreveu a resposta receba algo em troca, além de tornar o site mais limpo e útil para todo mundo. Adicionar uma nova resposta assim (que não é uma resposta pra pergunta e deve ser removida) deixa o site mais confuso e pode atrapalhar.

**Preview:**

> Que bom que você gostou das respostas! Mas a melhor forma de agradecer a quem te ajudou é assinalando "aceite" na melhor resposta e votando em todas que te ajudaram. Assim você garante que quem escreveu a resposta receba algo em troca, além de tornar o site mais limpo e útil para todo mundo. Adicionar uma nova resposta assim (que não é uma resposta pra pergunta e deve ser removida) deixa o site mais confuso e pode atrapalhar.

(inspirado de um comentário do Gabe)

Answer (score 18):

#### Pergunta/feedback do OP na área de respostas

**Source:**

Você usou a área de respostas para adicionar esclarecimentos ou fazer uma pergunta. Em vez disso, é melhor incluir esse conteúdo na própria pergunta. Para fazer isso, basta clicar no link [edit], que fica logo abaixo da pergunta. Assim, o conteúdo fica todo reunido em um único lugar, e quem chegar aqui não precisa ficar procurando informações em várias respostas e comentários para entender o problema.

**Preview:**

> Você usou a área de respostas para adicionar esclarecimentos ou fazer uma pergunta. Em vez disso, é melhor incluir esse conteúdo na própria pergunta. Para fazer isso, basta clicar no link [editar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/707/edit), que fica logo abaixo da pergunta. Assim, o conteúdo fica todo reunido em um único lugar, e quem chegar aqui não precisa ficar procurando informações em várias respostas e comentários para entender o problema.

Answer (score 18):

#### Ajudando o autor sobreviver no SOpt

**Source:**

Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a solução for muito simples ainda é possível que alguém o faça nos comentários.

**Preview:**

> Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a solução for muito simples ainda é possível que alguém o faça nos comentários.

Answer (score 17):

#### Ajudando o autor a clarificar uma pergunta

**Source:**

Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português!
Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

**Preview:**

> Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: **Sugestão:** Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português, talvez queira fazer um **Tour**: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour ou dar uma olhada na **Central de Ajuda**: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour e verificar como efetuar perguntas de uma forma que sejam respondidas rapidamente, tente informar o que você já tentou e poste o seu código, dificilmente alguém fará o trabalho por você. Como você não tem uma ideia de como fazer o que está precisando, inicialmente é melhor fazer uma pesquisa e depois se tiver alguma dificuldade na programação pode voltar a perguntar aqui.

Answer (score 17):

#### Usuário cria pergunta em inglês

**Fonte:**

Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow **em português**. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [site em inglês do Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

**Previsão:**

> Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow **em português**. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [site em inglês do Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

---

**Source:**

Welcome to Stack Overflow **in Portuguese**. As the name implies, the official language used here is Portuguese. So, can you please translate your question? If you prefer, you may also ask this same question in [the English Stack Overflow site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

**Preview:**

> Welcome to Stack Overflow **in Portuguese**. As the name implies, the official language used here is Portuguese. So, can you please translate your question? If you prefer, you may also ask this same question in [the English Stack Overflow site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

---

<sub>Obs: sintam-se a vontade para melhorar, não sou muito bom nisso, apenas quis dar o pontapé inicial pois não aguento mais ver perguntas criadas em inglês e nenhum comentário enlatado para isso.</sub>

Comment: Relacionado: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1513/sugestões-de-frase-pronta-para-fechamento-de-perguntas-em-outros-idiomas

Answer (score 16):

#### Usuário cria pergunta com saudações e você deseja deixar um recado após removê-las para não parecer tão grosseiro

**Source:**

Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações pois costumamos manter o texto o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [chat]. Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [meta] :)

**Preview:**

> Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações, pois costumamos manter o texto o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [Bate-papo do Stack Overflow em Português](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [Stack Overflow em Português Meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/) :)

---

<sup>PS: feedbacks sobre esse comentário são muito bem vindos</sup>

Comment: Criei esse comentário por causa [dessa publicação em específico](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/28199/1), onde aprox metade do texto era desnecessário, e eu decidi que ia deixar uma explicação para o AP informado pq tirei tanto do texto original (mas acabei demorando tanto fazendo o comentário que outra pessoa editou a pergunta). Entretanto, acho que esse comentário não se encaixa em todas as situações, apenas nos casos em que o texto original possui muitas coisas para melhorar, então é melhor deixar um comentário para não ser tão impessoal. Minha humilde opinião.

Comment: `pois costumamos **mantê-las**...`. Manter quem "limpas"? A pergunta ou as saudações? Acho que poderia ficar mais claro essa parte: ou alterar a concordância do verbo no singular para a pergunta, `para mantê-la` ou especificar um pouco mais, `costumamos manter o texto` ou `manter as questões` ou `manter a descrição dela`

Comment: @bio muito bem observado, peguei uma das suas sugestões e modifiquei o texto

Comment: Criei uma segunda versão baseada [nessa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/263773/for%c3%a7ar-a-atualiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-um-elemento-em-html-javascript-asp-net) pergunta: `Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações, agradecimentos e demais, pois costumamos manter o texto o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [chat]. Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [meta] :)`

Answer (score 14):

#### Usuário novato cria múltiplas perguntas duplicadas

**Source:**

Bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Percebi que está criando múltiplas perguntas para um mesmo problema, quando isso na verdade não vai lhe ajudar a conseguir uma resposta mais depressa. Ao invés disso, leia o guia [ask] e faça um [tour] para aprender um pouco mais sobre o funcionamento do site e assim aumentar suas chances de conseguir uma boa resposta.

**Preview:**

> Bem vindo ao [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/). Percebi que está criando múltiplas perguntas para um mesmo problema, quando isso na verdade não vai lhe ajudar a conseguir uma resposta mais depressa. Ao invés disso, leia o guia [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e faça um [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender um pouco mais sobre o funcionamento do site e assim aumentar suas chances de conseguir uma boa resposta.

Answer (score 13):

### Usuário responde a uma pergunta com outra pergunta

**Source:**

Você usou a área de respostas para fazer uma pergunta. Em vez disso, é melhor criar uma nova pergunta. Para fazer isso, basta clicar no link [Faça uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), que fica no canto superior direito do site.

**Preview:**

> Você usou a área de respostas para fazer uma pergunta. Em vez disso, é melhor criar uma nova pergunta. Para fazer isso, basta clicar no link [Faça uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), que fica no canto superior direito do site.

Answer (score 12):

#### Ajudando o autor da pergunta a aceitar uma resposta

**Source:**

Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

**Preview:**

> Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Comment: Talvez o título desse comentário enlatado seria mais adequado se fosse adaptado para quando o autor muda o título para "resolvido", existem outros casos que queremos instruir o autor da pergunta a aceitar uma resposta, [**exemplo**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32847/3117), e esse comentário aqui não cabe naquela situação. Eu posso estar criando o comentário, mas acho que deveríamos mudar o título desse aqui então. O que acha?

Answer (score 12):

#### Seja mais específico na pergunta (com metáfora)

**Source:**

Descrevendo o problema geral você vai conseguir apenas uma resposta geral. Exemplo: "Como construir uma casa?", "Use blocos e cimento, construa paredes sólidas.". Em vez disso pergunte algo específico e respondível de forma útil: "Como levantar uma parede usando esse tipo de bloco com tal inclinação e de tal altura de forma segura?", resposta: "Posicione os blocos no formato tal, execute esse algoritmo de colocação de blocos, não use essa ferramenta pois há o risco tal, aqui tem um exemplo funcionando de uma parede pronta para você ver como faz [link]". Vê? Perguntas muito amplas não ajudam.

**Preview:**

> Descrevendo o problema geral você vai conseguir apenas uma resposta geral. Exemplo: "Como construir uma casa?", "Use blocos e cimento, construa paredes sólidas.". Em vez disso pergunte algo específico e respondível de forma útil: "Como levantar uma parede usando esse tipo de bloco com tal inclinação e de tal altura de forma segura?", resposta: "Posicione os blocos no formato tal, execute esse algoritmo de colocação de blocos, não use essa ferramenta pois há o risco tal, aqui tem um exemplo funcionando de uma parede pronta para você ver como faz [link]". Vê? Perguntas muito amplas não ajudam.

Grande [metáfora do Guilherme Bernal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17669/como-criar-um-jogo-em-actionscript-3-0#comment33448_17669)

Comment: Gosto do conceito, mas acho forçado usar a palavra algoritmo nesse contexto, mas não vou me aventurar a sugerir nada agora. Acho que dá pra usar o excelente exemplo, com melhores palavras. Assim que estiver de cabeça fresca, sugiro algo.

Comment: @Bacco poderia ser processo, procedimento, técnica?

Comment: @Caputo de fato, "procedimento para a colocação dos" no lugar de "algoritmo de colocação de" me soa bem melhor.

Comment: Este comentário não cabe nunca caixa de comentários, se tiver o bem-vindo.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/lgQUH6X.jpg

Answer (score 9):

### Orientando o autor da pergunta a aceitar a resposta

Esse daqui é parecido, mas diferente do ["Ajudando o autor da pergunta a aceitar uma resposta"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1311/132). Esta resposta aqui foca em explicar como e porquê aceitar a resposta e idealmente é colocado em resposta a um comentário do tipo "*resolveu meu problema, obrigado*", enquanto que a outra anterior é para os casos onde o autor põe [resolvido] no título. Há algumas variações possíveis, use a que mais convir.

#### Variação 1

Situação: O autor da pergunta comenta "obrigado" na única resposta recebida (ou no mínimo, a única que não seja porcaria) e você deseja postar uma réplica desse comentário na resposta.

> Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar.

#### Variação 2

Situação: O autor da pergunta recebeu duas boas respostas, comenta "obrigado" em pelo menos uma delas e você deseja postar uma réplica desse comentário na resposta.

> Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se preferir a outra resposta, pode marcá-la como correta/aceita, mas apenas uma resposta pode ser marcada dessa forma. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar.

#### Variação 3

Situação: O autor da pergunta recebeu diversas boas respostas, comenta "obrigado" em pelo menos uma delas e você deseja postar uma réplica desse comentário na resposta.

> Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se preferir uma das outras respostas, pode marcá-la como correta/aceita, mas apenas uma resposta pode ser marcada dessa forma. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar.

#### Variação 4

Situação: O autor da pergunta recebeu uma resposta, comenta "obrigado" na pergunta e você deseja postar uma réplica desse comentário na pergunta.

> Se a resposta abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar.

#### Variação 5

Situação: O autor da pergunta recebeu duas ou mais respostas, comenta "obrigado" na pergunta e você deseja postar uma réplica desse comentário na pergunta.

> Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar.

Answer (score 8):

#### A pergunta tem links para o site onde está ocorrendo o problema, em vez de mostrar o código relevante na própria pergunta

**Source:**

Você precisa demonstrar o problema na própria pergunta (favor [edit]), em vez de postar esses links. Veja [Posso mostrar só um link pro meu site com problemas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1913/) e as [dicas sobre exemplo mínimo](/help/mcve). Obrigado.

**Preview:**

> Você precisa demonstrar o problema na própria pergunta (favor [edit]), em vez de postar esses links. Veja [Posso mostrar só um link pro meu site com problemas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1913/) e as [dicas sobre exemplo mínimo](/help/mcve). Obrigado.

Answer (score 7):

#### Usuário cria pergunta apenas com um enunciado

**Source:**

Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Parece que a sua pergunta contém alguns problemas. Nós não faremos o seu trabalho da faculdade ou lição de casa, mas se você estiver com dificuldade em alguma parte específica, compartilhe o seu código, diga o que já tentou fazer e qual está sendo a dificuldade, assim você aumenta as suas chances em conseguir uma boa resposta. Não deixe de ler o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5486/) para ter uma experiência melhor por aqui.

**Preview:**

> Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Parece que a sua pergunta contém alguns problemas. Nós não faremos o seu trabalho da faculdade ou lição de casa, mas se você estiver com dificuldade em alguma parte específica, compartilhe o seu código, diga o que já tentou fazer e qual está sendo a dificuldade, assim você aumenta as suas chances em conseguir uma boa resposta. Não deixe de ler o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5486/) para ter uma experiência melhor por aqui.

Answer (score 4):

#### Autor publicou código e/ou mensagem de erro como imagem

**Source:**

Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]!
Você colocou uma imagem do código e/ou mensagem de erro. Apesar de parecer uma boa ideia, não é!
Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar o código e alterar algo dentro. Clique no link [edit] e **coloque o código/erro como texto**.
Veja mais sobre isso nesses links - [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/3774), [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774)

**Preview:**

> Bem-vindo ao [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com)! Você colocou uma imagem do código e/ou mensagem de erro. Apesar de parecer uma boa ideia, não é!
> Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar o código e alterar algo dentro. Clique no link [editar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/707/edit) e **coloque o código/erro como texto**.
> Veja mais sobre isso nesses links - [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/3774), [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774)

Answer (score 4):

#### Usuário responde apenas com código

**Source:**

Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Esse código pode ser uma solução para a pergunta, mas sua resposta pode ser melhor se você [edit] e incluir uma explicação sobre os principais pontos do código. O objetivo não é ajudar apenas quem fez a pergunta, mas os próximos visitantes também. Leia mais em [Respostas apenas com código - O que fazer?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7172/).

**Preview:**

> Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Esse código pode ser uma solução para a pergunta, mas sua resposta pode ser melhor se você [editar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/8436/edit) e incluir uma explicação sobre os principais pontos do código. O objetivo não é ajudar apenas quem fez a pergunta, mas os próximos visitantes também. Leia mais em [Respostas apenas com código - O que fazer?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7173/).

Answer (score 3):

**Usuário publica no META uma pergunta que deveria ser feita na página principal.**

**Source:**

Essa pergunta não pertence a esse site. As perguntas feitas aqui no META devem ser sobre o funcionamento do site, perguntas a comunidade, bugs, propostas de melhorias e novos recursos. Leia:  [O que é o "META"? Como ele funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

**Preview**:

> Essa pergunta não pertence a esse site. As perguntas feitas aqui no
>   META devem ser sobre o funcionamento do site, perguntas a comunidade,
>   bugs, propostas de melhorias e novos recursos. Leia:  [O que é o "META"? Como ele funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Answer (score 3):

## Pergunta pertence a outra comunidade da rede SE

Esse comentário enlatado apresenta um conjunto de comentários que visam orientar o usuário que publicou uma pergunta estruturalmente e qualitativamente consideráveis porém [fora do escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para a nossa comunidade, [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com), porém apta ao escrutínio de outra comunidade integrante da [rede Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

#### O usuário apresentou uma pergunta sobre de infraestrutura de TI não relacionada a linguagens de programação.

**Source:**

A sua pergunta parece estar [fora do nosso escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Mas felizmente a rede [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) conta com o site [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) que é um Q&A voltado para administradores de rede e administradores de sistemas. Se preferir você pode encaminhar sua pergunta a essa comunidade, lembrando que é uma comunidade independente da nossa que portanto possui suas próprias regras é gerida em língua inglesa.

**Preview:**

> A sua pergunta parece estar [fora do nosso
> escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Mas felizmente a
> rede [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) conta com o
> site [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) que é um Q&A voltado
> para administradores de rede e administradores de sistemas. Se
> preferir você pode encaminhar sua pergunta a essa comunidade, lembrando que
> é uma comunidade independente da nossa que portanto possui suas
> próprias regras é gerida em língua inglesa.

#### O usuário apresentou uma pergunta específica ao sistema operacional Ubuntu não relacionada a linguagens de programação.

**Source:**

A sua pergunta parece estar [fora do nosso escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Mas felizmente a rede [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) conta com o site [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) que é um Q&A voltado para usuários e administradores do sistema operacional Ubuntu. Se preferir você pode encaminhar sua pergunta a essa comunidade, lembrando que é uma comunidade independente da nossa que portanto possui suas próprias regras é gerida em língua inglesa.

**Preview:**

> A sua pergunta parece estar [fora do nosso
> escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Mas felizmente a
> rede [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) conta com o
> site [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) que é um Q&A voltado para
> usuários e administradores do sistema operacional Ubuntu. Se preferir
> você pode encaminhar sua pergunta a essa comunidade, lembrando que é
> uma comunidade independente da nossa que portanto possui suas próprias
> regras é gerida em língua inglesa.

#### O usuário apresentou uma pergunta específica a sistemas operacionais Unix like não relacionada a linguagens de programação e não específica ao Ubuntu.

**Source:**

A sua pergunta parece estar [fora do nosso escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Mas felizmente a rede [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) conta com o site [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) que é um Q&A voltado para usuários de sistemas Unix like. Se preferir você pode encaminhar sua pergunta a essa comunidade, lembrando que é uma comunidade independente da nossa que portanto possui suas próprias regras é gerida em língua inglesa.

**Preview**

> A sua pergunta parece estar [fora do nosso
> escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Mas felizmente a
> rede [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) conta com o
> site [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) que é um Q&A
> voltado para usuários de sistemas Unix like. Se preferir você pode
> encaminhar sua pergunta a essa comunidade, lembrando que é uma
> comunidade independente da nossa que portanto possui suas próprias
> regras é gerida em língua inglesa.

#### O usuário apresentou uma pergunta sobre Hardware ou Software não relacionada a linguagens de programação.

**Source:**

A sua pergunta parece estar [fora do nosso escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Mas felizmente a rede [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) conta com o site [Super User](https://superuser.com/) que é um Q&A voltado para usuários de Software e Hardware em geral. Se preferir você pode encaminhar sua pergunta a essa comunidade, lembrando que é uma comunidade independente da nossa que portanto possui suas próprias regras é gerida em língua inglesa.

**Preview:**

> A sua pergunta parece estar [fora do nosso
> escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Mas felizmente a
> rede [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) conta com o
> site [Super User](https://superuser.com/) que é um Q&A voltado para
> usuários de Software e Hardware em geral. Se preferir você pode
> encaminhar sua pergunta a essa comunidade, lembrando que é uma
> comunidade independente da nossa que portanto possui suas próprias
> regras é gerida em língua inglesa.

#### Genérica com link no fim. O usuário apresentou uma pergunta de outra comunidade não listada acima.

**Source:**

A sua pergunta parece estar [fora do nosso escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Mas felizmente a rede [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) conta com uma comunidade que parece abordar esse assunto, se preferir você pode encaminhar sua pergunta a essa comunidade, lembrando que é uma comunidade independente da nossa que portanto possui suas próprias regras. Acesse [nome do site](http://www.enderecodosite.com)

**Preview:**

> A sua pergunta parece estar [fora do nosso escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Mas felizmente a rede [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) conta com uma comunidade que parece abordar esse assunto, se preferir você pode encaminhar sua pergunta a essa comunidade, lembrando que é uma comunidade independente da nossa que portanto possui suas próprias regras. Acesse [nome do site](http://www.enderecodosite.com)

Comment: Deem um analisada, editem, deixem opiniões ou façam sugestões. PS: Os textos anteriores podem ser obtidos no [histórico de revisões](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/8449/revisions).

Comment: Ficou muito bom, eu coloquei no final uma sugestão de _genérica_ baseada nas que você criou

Answer (score 2):

## Demonstrações

Esta semi-resposta foi postada apenas para fazer um teste realista dos comentários.

- Se quiser sugerir uma melhoria em comentário, faça-o na respectiva "resposta", e não aqui.
- Favor postar os comentários-teste aqui somente quando estes forem atualizados na própria questão.
- Não poste comentários que não sejam de teste!

  Caso queira sugerir uma melhoria neste procedimento aqui, faça seu comment na pergunta principal, senão mistura com os demos e vira uma bagunça. E lembre de deletar seus comments depois de lidos e/ou respondidos.
- Moderadores e autores de comentários: removam "sumariamente" qualquer comentário desatualizado ou *off-topic*, mantendo apenas a versão atualizada.

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante!  Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade:  [Respostas que apenas contêm links são boas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/705/respostas-que-apenas-contem-links-sao-boas)

Comment: Legal você querer ajudar, mas você usou o campo de resposta para fazer um comentário. Você poderá postar comentários quando tiver [um pouco mais de pontos de reputação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor utilize o campo de resposta somente para postar uma solução ao problema de que a pergunta trata.

Comment: Que bom que você gostou das respostas! Mas a melhor forma de agradecer a quem te ajudou é
assinalando "aceite" na melhor resposta e votando em todas que te ajudaram. Assim você garante
que quem escreveu a resposta receba algo em troca, além de tornar o site mais limpo e útil
para todo mundo. Adicionar uma nova resposta assim (que não é uma resposta pra pergunta e deve
ser removida) deixa o site mais confuso e pode atrapalhar.

Comment: Se você tem uma nova pergunta, por favor utilize o botão [Faça uma pergunta](http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). 
A área que você usou para postar a pergunta é somente para respostas.

Comment: Você usou a área de respostas para adicionar esclarecimentos ou fazer uma pergunta. 
Em vez disso, é melhor editar a sua pergunta e incluir esse conteúdo lá mesmo. Para isso,
existe um link de "editar" embaixo da pergunta. Assim, o conteúdo fica todo reunido em um
único lugar, e quem chegar aqui não precisa ficar procurando informações em várias 
respostas e comentários para entender o problema.

Comment: Descrevendo o problema geral você vai conseguir apenas uma resposta geral. Exemplo: "Como construir uma casa?", "Use blocos e cimento, construa paredes sólidas.". Em vez disso pergunte algo específico e respondível de forma útil: "Como levantar uma parede usando esse tipo de bloco com tal inclinação e de tal altura de forma segura?", resposta: "Posicione os blocos no formato tal, execute esse algoritmo de colocação de blocos, não use essa ferramenta pois há o risco tal, aqui tem um exemplo funcionando de uma parede pronta para você ver como faz [link]". Vê? Perguntas muito amplas não ajudam.

Comment: Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois está ampla demais a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Comment: Se essa resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se preferir uma das outras respostas, pode marcá-la como correta/aceita, mas apenas uma resposta pode ser marcada dessa forma. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 

Answer (score 2):

Use comentários aqui preferencialmente se o usuário criou uma série de perguntas e ou respostas contendo saudações, cumprimentos e agradecimentos.

#### O usuário cria uma pergunta contendo agradecimentos.

**Source:**

Evite agradecer e cumprimentar nas publicações pois aqui no [pt.so] são considerados ruído de comunicação. Boas perguntas são descritivas, detalhadas e diretas. Dê o máximo de informações possíveis sobre o que você quer fazer, erro encontrando e que já tentou, quem vai o ajudar não pode (nem quer) ficar conversando. Veja [Que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), [Saudações e Agradecimentos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/846/137387) e [Como se portar ao perguntar/responder?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/38/137387).

**Preview:**

> Evite agradecer e cumprimentar nas publicações pois aqui no Stack Overflow em Português
> são considerados ruído de comunicação. Boas perguntas são descritivas,
> detalhadas e diretas. Dê o máximo de informações possíveis sobre o que
> você quer fazer, erro encontrando e que já tentou, quem vai o ajudar
> não pode (nem quer) ficar conversando. Veja [Que tipo de comportamento
> é esperado dos usuários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior),
> [Saudações e
> Agradecimentos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/846/) e
> [Como se portar ao
> perguntar/responder?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/38/).

#### O usuário cria uma resposta contendo agradecimentos.

**Source:**

Evite agradecer e cumprimentar nas publicações pois aqui no [pt.so] são considerados ruído de comunicação. Boas respostas são descritivas, detalhadas e diretas. Ofereça o máximo de informações possíveis sobre a solução, aqui os usuários não podem (nem querem) ficar conversando. Veja [Que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), [Saudações e Agradecimentos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/846/) e [Como se portar ao perguntar/responder?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/38/).

**Preview:**

> Evite agradecer e cumprimentar nas publicações pois aqui no Stack Overflow em Português
> são considerados ruído de comunicação. Boas respostas são descritivas,
> detalhadas e diretas. Ofereça o máximo de informações possíveis sobre
> a solução, aqui os usuários não podem (nem querem) ficar conversando.
> Veja [Que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos
> usuários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), [Saudações e
> Agradecimentos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/846/) e [Como
> se portar ao
> perguntar/responder?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/38/).

Comment: O preview [pt.so] do magic link foi ligeiramente modificado pois no [meta] os magic links não funcionam adequadamente e fiquei hesitante. Mas acabei descobrindo que esse  em específico funciona por aqui.