# Posso mostrar só um link pro meu site com problemas?

Tags: suporte, faq, apenas-link

Posso fazer uma pergunta que contenha somente um link para meu site? Ou seja, descrever o problema e mostrar o link da página onde ele acontece.

Ou então simplesmente colocar o código num JSFiddle?

[Retorne para o índice da FAQ](/q/699)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Não.

A intenção do Stack Overflow em Português é ser um repositório de problemas e soluções. Se por acaso acontecer de:

- o site mudar o código,
- o link morrer,
- o domínio deixar de existir,
- algum [cabo transatlântico de alta velocidade quebrar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_submarine_cable_disruption),
- houver uma [balkanização da internet](http://web.archive.org/web/20140828141830/http://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/nov/01/nsa-revelations-balkanisation-internet) por conta da espionagem do NSA,
- o JSFiddle tiver uma de suas baixas mensais:

  [image]

  [image]

tudo isso vai deixar a pergunta inservível para o visitante presente e futuro.

**Então, por favor, inclua todo o código relevante na sua pergunta.** <sup>*(também vale para respostas)*</sup>

> <sup>Relacionado: [**Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)</sup>