# FAQ não seguindo as próprias definições de como devem ser as páginas da FAQ

Tags: debate, meta

Na página de abertura da [faq](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/64969), temos um "capítulo" dedicado especialmente a como fazer postagem da FAQ:

> - Pergunte só o fundamental do que você deseja de forma clara e simples.
>     E responda separadamente como uma resposta.
> - Coloque um link para esta página no final da pergunta. Cole o código:
>
>   ```
>   ---
>   [Retorne para o índice da FAQ](/q/699)
>   ```
> - Coloque as tags [suporte](/questions/tagged/suporte) e [proposta-para-faq](/questions/tagged/proposta-para-faq). Quando o post estiver maduro o suficiente, um moderador colocará a tag
>     [faq](/questions/tagged/faq).
> - Sinalize para um moderador marcar a pergunta como *Community Wiki*. Todos posts da FAQ precisam ser CW.
> - **Após** a pergunta receber a tag [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), edite este post para colocar um link para a pergunta na seção adequada.
>
> Não tente fazer de outra forma, precisamos manter a organização.

Porém andando pela FAQ percebi que diversas entradas não *manteve essa organização*.

Por exemplo:

- [Posso mostrar só um link pro meu site com problemas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1913/64969); logo a primeira entrada não é CW
- [Quando se deve colocar o nome da linguagem no título?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297/64969); não é CW, não possui a régua horizontal antes do marcador "Retorne para o índice do FAQ"
- [Posso fazer crosspost entre o SO em Inglês e o SO em Português?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/125/64969); não tem nem a tag [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)!!
- [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/64969); não tem link de volta para o índice, CW

E tem também outras inconsistências nesse mesmo naipe em outras páginas da FAQ.

Então...

- Devemos mudar as perguntas da FAQ e deixar todas no padrão pedido?
- Ou devemos mudar qual o padrão desejado
- E as demais perguntas que estão como [proposta-para-faq](/questions/tagged/proposta-para-faq), elas serão analisadas e julgadas e caso passem o teste de fogo virão para cá?

Comment: Corrigir nós devemos corrigir sim, mas isso requer uma atenção mais específica dos moderadores, ou dos usuários específicos citados, já que não conseguimos (eu, pelo menos) transformar em *Community Wiki*. Sobre o padrão, acho que é interessante manter no que já temos, e todos os próximos deveriam passar pela prova de fogo antes de serem publicados. Devemos sempre prezar pela organização.

Comment: @Stormwind, flag flag flag

Comment: E também podemos botar a barra horizontal e o "volte para o FAQ", qqr coisa. Creio que a tag [meta-tag:faq] seja protegida (ela é até vermelha), então creio que não consigamos alterar isso

Comment: Agir é a parte mais fácil, mas acho que antes é interessante discutirmos se o formato está adequado, me dá a impressão de que o FAQ não tem tido muito atenção até então, temos a oportunidade de debater sobre isso agora. Para debater podemos inclusive ver como está sendo feito nos demais sites da rede para verificar se não houveram melhorias e modificações, uma vez definido uma força tarefa para resolver isso levaria poucos minutos

Comment: @Math, então essa questão ficaria suspensa até decidirmos o formato do FAQ? Ou colocaríamos como respostas os formatos?

Comment: Como assim "colocar como resposta os formatos"? De qualquer forma é algo que a comunidade pode estar participando (na minha opinião), as pessoas podem debater nas respostas postando opiniões, estudos de uma forma boa de se manter um faq, link das outras comunidades da rede ou até mesmo fora da rede, etc.. se não houver muito o que ser debatido é só questão de agir mesmo, daí eu faço aqui rapidinho, mas antes eu realmente gostaria de olhar essa questão mais a fundo, ver como é feito em outros sites principalmente, nesse meio tempo alguém pode ter alguma ideia melhor, se alguém tiver é só falar

Comment: @Math "colocar como resposta os formatos": adicionar uma resposta a esta atual publicação-pergunta com o formato usado por fulano/sicrano na rede XYZ, ou então uma sugestão levando em base a rede XPTO e seus criticismos

Comment: Ah sim, legal assim

Comment: Parece que esse é o formato seguido na rede mesmo, aparantemente 100% dos faq no [**meta exchange**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq?page=1&sort=newest&pagesize=15) estão seguindo o padrão, já no [**SOen**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq) achei uma ou outra q estão fora do padrão, até mesmo uma [pergunta que foi criada por um funcionário da SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326374/1964435)

Comment: @Math, pode ser preciosismo meu, mas na faq do meta exchange não tem a régua horizontal [no modelo] antes do "retorne ao índice". Ficou até bonito, quiçá elegante também

Comment: Alguns dos nossos também não tem, como por exemplo [esse](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1186/3117) e [esse](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3882/3117). Opinião anotada, se ninguém mais se manifestar eu faço as mudanças em breve.

Answer (score 1):

Editei 3 perguntas que faltavam o `retorno para o índice`, editei 6 perguntas para remover o `---` entre o corpo da pergunta e o link do índice e transformei 6 perguntas para wiki da comunidade.

Com relação as perguntas listadas no FAQ que na verdade ainda são propostas de FAQ, quando percebi que eram a maioria preferi criar um post para esclarecer sobre as tags [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) e [proposta-para-faq](/questions/tagged/proposta-para-faq) antes de tomar uma ação quanto a elas. Ver em: [Quando um post deve ser uma proposta de FAQ e quando ele está maduro para se tornar um FAQ?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6536/3117)