# Quando um post deve ser uma proposta de FAQ e quando ele está maduro para se tornar um FAQ?

Tags: suporte, proposta-para-faq

Estava eu revisando as perguntas listadas no [índice de FAQ](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/3117) do nosso meta graças ao post [FAQ não seguindo as próprias definições de como devem ser as páginas da FAQ](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6526/3117) que alertava para problemas de formatação definidos no próprio post do FAQ, quando então percebi que a maioria das perguntas listadas no FAQ são na verdade propostas de FAQ.

Eu acabei corrigindo apenas o `retorno ao índice` nos posts que faltavam e convertendo para CW, mas não sabia bem o que fazer com as propostas de FAQ lá listadas.

De acordo com as definições do post propostas de FAQ são convertidas para FAQ quando estiverem maduras o suficiente:

> - Coloque as tags suporte e proposta-para-faq. Quando o post estiver maduro o suficiente, um moderador colocará a tag faq.

Quem decide que o post está maduro o suficiente? Nós moderadores individualmente podemos tomar essa decisão ou deveria haver uma votação ou alguma forma de saber se há consenso nessa escolha?

Além do mais, nas definições está:

> - **Após** a pergunta receber a tag faq, edite este post para colocar um link para a pergunta na seção adequada.

Isso significa que elas já estão maduras o suficiente para fazerem parte da FAQ e basta apenas editar os post com a tag apropriada ou foi um equívoco ao listá-las precipitadamente e deve-se removê-las da lista enquanto ainda são apenas propostas?

Por último, ao tagear essa pergunta aqui fiquei em dúvida se está correto tageá-la como [proposta-para-faq](/questions/tagged/proposta-para-faq), pois também não achei uma orientação para isso.

Answer (score 4):

> Quem decide que o post está maduro o suficiente? Nós moderadores individualmente podemos tomar essa decisão ou deveria haver uma votação ou alguma forma de saber se há consenso nessa escolha?

Acho que deve ser moderadores, senão vira bagunça. E de fato só moderadores podem fazer tudo o que é necessário para virar FAQ.

O que pode ser feito é a comunidade instigar os moderadores a analisar algum caso que já pareça maduro.

Idealmente os moderadores deveriam fazer isto automaticamente sempre olhando para a *tag* [meta:proposta-para-faq].

Admito que até eu tenho negligenciado isto.

Acho que a função da comunidade é colocar esta *tag* pra gente analisar.

Claro que o moderador pode abrir discussão privada com outros moderadores, com a comunidade no chat ou postar no meta se achar que precisa um debate. Só não sou fã de abrir debate para tudo. Vira [*design by committee*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_committee) que nunca é bom.

Muitas das pontas "soltas" deixadas no meta é porque ficamos discutindo muito para parecer democrático.

É mais importante entender, e respeitar, as necessidades da comunidade e agir.

E comunidade não é nem 3 ou 4 pessoas muito ativas, nem milhares de pessoas que postam alguma coisa no site.

O bom senso de poucas pessoas (moderadores) baseando-se no que já foi estabelecido como maduro acho que é suficiente para determinar o que é maduro.

Se algo sair errado dá para arrumar.

Me lembro que algum bom trabalho do bfavaretto no começo. Provavelmente teve outros que não me recordo.

> Isso significa que elas já estão maduras o suficiente para fazerem parte da FAQ e basta apenas editar os post com a tag apropriada ou foi um equívoco ao listá-las precipitadamente e deve-se removê-las da lista enquanto ainda são apenas propostas?

Acho que foram listadas equivocadamente ali, a não ser que a intenção fosse instigar a oficializar como FAQ.

Como não houve discussão, acho que qualquer moderador pode tomar a iniciativa de fazer se achar que deve. Se alguém tem algo a dizer sobre elas pode dizer lá ou abrir outra discussão.

> Por último, ao tagear essa pergunta aqui fiquei em dúvida se está correto tageá-la como proposta-para-faq, pois também não achei uma orientação para isso.

Acho o uso errado da *tag*, mas não vejo um problema, as alternativas (deixar sem assunto ou criar uma nova) talvez fossem piores.

## Adendo

Aproveitando para dizer que ando com menos tempo que o usual, mas quero dar uma revisada em toda a FAQ e as propostas.

2¢