# Sobre o tópico de comentários "enlatados"

Tags: debate

Não sei se todos utilizam com frequência, mas eu sempre procuro utilizar os comentários "enlatados" inclusos como resposta [neste tópico do meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/707/coment%C3%A1rios-enlatados-para-situa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-comuns), mas há duas coisas que gostaria de fazer, porém não o fiz porque parece que o tópico é referência para plugins.

As sugestões seriam:

- Assim já ocorre no [manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/28595), linkar as respostas daquele tópico na pergunta, assim fica mais fácil localizar na hora que alguém quiser usar;
- se tem algum problema adicionar outros comentários enlatados ou até mesmo atualizar os já existentes.

Preferi perguntar pois, como já mencionei, aquele tópico parece ser uma espécie de repositório para plugins de autoreview.

Tem algum problema em fazer isso? Algum cuidado que devo tomar em relação ao tópico ser reposítório de autoreview?

Comment: Não sei se eu "editaria" algum comentário já existente. Porém, não vejo problemas em criar novos.

Answer (score 6):

Eu criei aquele post e coloquei como wiki para que fosse um trabalho coletivo. Se achar onde melhorar, pode sim editá-los, sem problemas. Também pode acrescentar novos.

Quanto à integração com o plugin AutoReviewComments, não tenho certeza se ainda funciona. Eu mesmo não uso mais. É outro ponto aberto para colaborações, o código está no github (link no post dos comentários enlatados).

Comment: Então pode alimentar sem problemas? Eu não consegui fazer nenhum plugin de autoreviewcomment funcionar, então só me restou copiar manualmente

Comment: Fique à vontade!

Comment: @bfavaretto não usas porquê? Usas o que em vez disso?

Comment: @JorgeB. Nada :) Escrevo os comentários um a um. Ou faço um "crowdsourcing" e deixo pra comunidade resolver.