# Como instruir o usuário que pergunta "alguém pode me ajudar?" ou "ajuda a criar um programa, por favor"? ou "É possível?"

Tags: debate

Procurei nos [comentários enlatados](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/707/75104) e não encontrei algo especificamente para esta situação.

Pois [ao procurar por esta frase](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=algu%C3%A9m+pode+ajudar), 51 páginas aparecerão. E muitos outros sinônimos e situações similares podem ser encontrados.

No SOen há o meta [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). Porém é sobre o SOen e uma tradução não me parece o correto para a realidade do SOpt.

#### Como instruir o usuário que pergunta "alguém pode me ajudar?" ou "ajuda a criar um programa, por favor"?

Pois para o usuário, a pergunta parece correta e adequada. Muitas vezes o usuário leva bastante tempo para criar uma pergunta bem estruturada e clara.

Mas ao pedir ajuda ou para criar um programa, a maioria das vezes a pergunta é negativada. Porém nenhum comentário é realizado. **Como podemos fazer para explicar ao usuário como ele pode melhorar a pergunta sem ofendê-lo?** Além de [ser mais específico na pergunta, pois muitas vezes o usuário até é bem específico.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1481/75104).

Uma maneira engraçada que vejo em grupos de Whats é passar o contato escrito Alguém. Mas acho que esta não é a maneira correta.

#### É possível?

Creio que o é possível deixa a pergunta muito ampla, pois uma resposta `Sim`, poderia responder a pergunta...

Ou devemos deixar comentários com mais informações?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De certa forma uma parte dos problemas colocados no SO quer seja ele EN ou PT, 
vão sempre cumprir um dos critérios do género destas perguntas. 
Afinal de contas, as perguntas são colocadas de forma a que as pessoas possam obter ajuda. 
Sem perguntas, não há respostas, nem há SO.

Eu posso estar enganado, 
mas parece ser práticamente impossível estabelecer um critério especifico que se possa ser aplicado a 100% das perguntas.
Eu não acho isso necessariamente mau nem bom. É o que temos e provavelmente continuaremos a ter.

O problema em estabelecer este tipo de critério, é porque poucos conseguem concordar com todos os aspectos do critério.
Então você entra em negociação, mas sempre haverá alguém que vai discordar.
Mesmo que o [SE seja uma meritocracia](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/320/what-form-of-government-does-stackexchange-resemble/321), 
os usuários pertencentes ao topo da hierarquia terão diferenças de opinião, e nem entre menos elementos da comunidade conseguirão estipular um critério.

Um exemplo disto, pessoalmente, eu creio que a comunidade beneficia de **algumas** destas perguntas. 
Encontrei algumas perguntas deste género, que são bastante interessantes e onde voce pode obter algum conhecimento.
Eu não sigo a tag [css](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), mas apostava que pelo menos 1 em 4 das perguntas são deste tipo.
Normalmente as pessoas tem dificuldade em atingir determinado efeito nas suas aplicações web e vem aqui perguntar.
Mais uma vez, isto não é bom nem mau. Mas de certeza que se isso nao fosse autorizado, existiriam muito menos perguntas no tópico.

E então, qual é a solução? A solução na minha perspectiva é deixar a comunidade atuar tal como ela atua agora. Ou seja, votos de fechamento, se achar que for necessário fechar. Ou não atuação por ser indifirente á pergunta. Ou voto positivo caso ache a pergunta boa e ou interessante.
O melhor seria mesmo criar uma pergunta no meta e dirigir todas as perguntas que estejam nessa situação para o meta.

Essa pergunta deve informar o usuário dos seguintes aspetos:

1. Esta comunidade é para programadores mas alguns tópicos não são aceites. Veja quais são os tópicos que nos aceitamos
2. Se não completou o tour faca o tour.
3. Agradecimentos são feitos através de votos
4. Aceite a resposta que melhor atendeu o seu problema. Aceitar uma resposta pode levar a que a sua pergunta receba menos respostas, por isso certifique-se que está satisfeito com a resposta
5. Se não consegue obter uma resposta para a sua pergunta, ofereça uma recompensa
6. Se sua pergunta foi fechada analise criticamente, veja os aspetos em falha e edite-a. Seja critico na sua edição. Espere 3 dias para re-abertura ou mais comentários.
7. Se a sua pergunta não foi re-aberta e você pensa que deveria ter sido, você pode e deve colocar uma pergunta aqui no meta para esclarecer os motivos que levaram ao fechamento.
8. Geralmente nós não fazemos o código por si, e colocar uma pergunta do género pode levar a que ela seja fechada. 
   Se você fez uma pergunta deste género o melhor que pode fazer é extrair a unidade de trabalho mais pequena possível do seu problema.
   Ou seja, em vez de perguntar "Como posso fazer uma loja online com bando de dados SQL e Angular", pergunte "Como posso gravar os items do carro de compras no bando de dados?". Você tem obrigatoriamente mostrar trabalho, mostrando qual foi o seu esforço para cumprir essa funcionalidade.
   Isto não garante que a sua pergunta será aceite, mas terá um pouco mais hipóteses. Se sua pergunta foi fechada e você pensa que deve ser re-aberta siga o ponto 7.

Por outras palavras, eu acho que a solução não é restringir os perguntadores ou as perguntas que podem ser feitas, mas sim dar-lhes mais poder e opções na re-abertura das suas perguntas.
Se eles realmente pensarem que a sua pergunta deveria ser re-aberta eles tem que demonstrar esse esforço colocando uma nova pergunta aqui no meta.
E se a pergunta não puder ser re-aberta pelo menos eles saberão quais são exatamente as coisas que terão que fazer melhor na sua próxima pergunta.