# O que fazer com perguntas do tipo "quero fazer isto"?

Tags: debate, fechamento, qualidade, escopo-do-site

De certa forma [esta pergunta já foi feita quando o site começava](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/105/101), o problema não era grande e eu até me posicionava favorável a dar uma certa margem. Hoje temos muitas perguntas nesse estilo, sem muita informação, é só um enunciado do problema e quem for responder tem que fazer tudo, preenchendo as lacunas, especulando em como deve fazer.

Entendo que se a resposta é dizer que tem uma função pronto, uma resposta curta, simples, que não tem muitas opções, ou combinações possíveis, até faz algum sentido responder.

Porém a maioria é bem aberta, é um "faz tudo pra mim" mesmo que o texto não deixe isso claro. Estou falando das perguntas que são puro enunciado, em grande parte das vezes pior que um enunciado de exercício, só não está claro que seja um exercício, mas é a mesma coisa que fosse. Na verdade pode ser pior porque o exercício dá para responder sem fazer tudo para a pessoa, quando a pessoa pede a solução só entregando o código é que se responde.

Muitas vezes a pergunta até está clara, há um problema bem definido, tem um enunciado, que pode não ser perfeito, mas que define quase tudo o que é necessário para sair uma resposta, mas ainda não é um problema específico, é um pedido para fazer tudo. Tem caso que talvez a pessoa não quer a solução, mas a pergunta não deixa claro isto, e dá margem a interpretar que ela quer. Tem caso que se pergunta se ele quer e quase sempre a resposta é que não quer, mas ela ainda não deixa claro, dizer que não quer e ter a atitude de não querer são coisas distintas.

Porém uma resposta que explique pode não ser suficiente, e a pessoa pode nem gostar porque não era intenção só ter uma explicação.

O fato é que algumas pessoas respondem estas perguntas, mesmo quando nem dá para saber bem o que a pessoa quer. Alguns casos são usuários novatos que não entende bem a filosofia do site, em outros são usuários experientes que gostariam de dar a resposta ou mesmo ganhar os pontos. Será comum que o AP goste porque para quem não tem nada qualquer coisa é alguma coisa. Outras pessoa podem gostar também. Pode não ser bom. Dependendo de quem responde pode ser trágico.

O entendimento sempre foi que perguntas abertas assim, que não tem esforço, a pessoa só está terceirizando o serviço, não eram boas para a comunidade. Este entendimento mudou?

A comunidade precisa definir se essas perguntas podem ou não, e aí elas serem fechadas ou deixadas para serem respondidas. Se puderem, não podemos discriminar quem claramente quer a solução para um exercício, é a mesma coisa, tem as mesmas vantagens e desvantagens para a comunidade, e nem estou analisando o fato da desonestidade da pessoa pedir para outo fazer por ela, porque não faz diferença se é um exercício da faculdade, ou que ela pegou na internet, se é um teste para uma seleção empregatícia, se um trabalho remunerado que ela pegou e não dá conta ou se é um *hobby* dela.

Se é aprendizado ela não pede a solução, ela pede explicação do conceito, ou dá muitos detalhes e pede explicação do que precisa fazer deixando claro que ela não quer que faça para ela, ou ainda ela só expõe um problema específico que ela está tendo quando vai tentar fazer aquilo, ou seja, ou a pergunta é conceitual, ou é específica, tem código, tem tentativa.

Uma coisa ruim é ter dois pesos e duas medidas, a comunidade precisa decidir o que quer e "todos" procederem da mesma forma.

Isto é uma forma mais específica de tratar disto: [O que deve ser fechado?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6207/101).

## Edit

Estou colando em destaque porque não houve uma resposta satisfatória e isto é importante pra mim, porque estou com dificuldade para decidir quando fechar certas peguntas com essas características. Precisa saber qual é o limite do "faz para mim" e o que dá para ajudar mesmo sem a pessoa ter uma dúvida conceitual que dá uma resposta canônica mesmo sem detalhes e sem ter uma dúvida específica, provavelmente com um código feito com problema pontual.

Comment: Você hoje pegou nos dois exemplos que me afastaram de responder no site. Por mim era fechar tudo que demostre ser um "faça por mim". Afinal é um site de perguntas e respostas para esclarecer dúvidas ou de prestação de serviços grátis? Obrigado por pegar nestes temas, já há bem mais de 1 ano que estes temas são um problema, pelo menos na minha cabeça ;)

Comment: Talvez a abordagem "sua pergunta foi fechada, agora me mostre porque ela deveria ser reaberta" seja válida nesta situação.

Comment: Admito que tinha outra visão do Stack antes de começar a participar da comunidade e muitas pessoas também tem uma visão errada, não sabem o objetivo do Stack. Não seria o caso de deixar o objetivo do site mais claro? Evitar perguntas desse tipo deixando explícito que essas perguntas não serão validas ao invés de esperar que elas apareçam aos montes.

Comment: @K4L1 mais claro que o [tour] nem desenhando. O problema é que muitos caem de para-quedas aqui sem nem da uma passadinha. O tour deveria ser obrigatorio ao fazer o primeiro post no site, mas a SE nao parece muito interessada nisso.

Comment: @ArticunoL, não estou falando do fato de deixar o  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour mais claro/detalhado e sim deixar ele mais visivel ou até mesmo criar novos métodos além do tour para mostrar os usuários qual o principal objetivo do Stack, pensando assim, nós podemos evitar o problema ao invés de esperar ele aparecer para concertar(excluir). Obs: eu nem lembrava que tinha um tour.

Comment: O que eu penso mesmo é que deve deixar a comunidade funcionar como ela funciona hoje em dia. Se há pessoas a votar para fechar a pergunta é provável que ela mereca ser fechada. Se há pessoas a responder, é provavel que elas estejam interessadas na pergunta e ou queiram ajudar no problema indicado. Se a pergunta for fechada, o AP pode sempre contestar o seu fechamento no meta. Acho que isso deveria ser indicado em todas as mensagens automáticas de fechamento.

Comment: [Relacionada](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7079/75104)

Answer (score 7):

Pode parecer mal começar a resposta desta forma mas acho que se calhar convém começar por responder a "O que **não podemos fazer** ...".

As perguntas são colocadas por utilizadores de perfis totalmente diferentes.
Iniciantes, não iniciantes, conhecem a comunidade ou não, etc...

O que isto quer dizer é que este tipo de perguntas vão continuar a aparecer, 
uma vezes por desconhecimento, outras por descuido, outras por má vontade.

---

É claro, eu não sou a favor que todas as perguntas sejam deixadas abertas.
Agora se você me perguntar qual é o critério que você deve seguir para decidir
se a pergunta deve ser fechada ou não, eu não lhe sei dizer e duvido que alguém saiba.

É por isto que existe uma comunidade, uma fila de analise de perguntas. 
Essas são as ferramentas disponibilizadas para que a comunidade possa tomar conta destas situacoes.

A comunidade tem que entender que não há nada que pode ser feito para resolver a fonte do problema, então tem que aprender a lidar com ele. 
Não é necessário nem ficar ansioso, nervoso, impotente (sem saber o que fazer), ou qualquer outra coisa.
Simplesmente vá a pergunta que acha que deve ser fechada e chegue lá e vote para fechar, se é isso que você acha que deve ser feito.

Na [minha outra resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7468/35970) a 
[Como instruir o usuário que pergunta “alguém pode me ajudar?” ou “ajuda a criar um programa, por favor”? ou “É possível?”](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7079)
eu expliquei que a "bola" deve ser deixada do lado do perguntador.

Se ele estiver interessado em melhorar a sua pergunta ele editará. 
E se ele vir que a pergunta continua fechada ele poderá vir ao meta contestar o fechamento e conhecer melhor os motivos.
Ás vezes quem coloca as perguntas necessita de olhos terceiros para identificar exatamente o que está errado com as suas perguntas.

É claro, para isso, é necessário fornecer um link para uma pergunta do meta que explique o motivo de fechamento neste tipo de perguntas,
o que AP pode fazer para tentar salvar a sua pergunta, e no fim tentar contestar o fechamento no meta, caso seja necessário.

---

> estou com dificuldade para decidir quando fechar certas peguntas com
>   essas características. Precisa saber qual é o limite do "faz para mim"
>   e o que dá para ajudar mesmo sem a pessoa ter uma dúvida conceitual
>   que dá uma resposta canônica mesmo sem detalhes e sem ter uma dúvida
>   específica, provavelmente com um código feito com problema pontual.

Se você está com dificuldades em tomar uma decisão o melhor mesmo é discutir com outros usuários ou moderados no chat. Lembre-se que o trabalho de fechar perguntas não é só seu e você não tem que tomar uma decisão sobre todas as perguntas. Se você não consegue chegar a uma conclusão e outros moderadores também não a alternativa menos penosa é deixar a pergunta aberta.

Lembre-se também do tópico de ajuda [o que não perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Se a pergunta não se enquadrar no texto descrito é para fechar. Se tiver dúvidas pergunte a outras pessoas. Se enquandrar deixe aberta.

Comment: Apoiado. Acho que o caminho é esse mesmo.

Comment: Eu achei interessante na sua outra resposta o que você mencionou sobre a tag css, aqui do SOpt, eu sei que o que vou dizer parece meio contra produtivo, mas por que ao invés de uma regra geral, que englobe todas as tags mas que não tem como funcionar muito bem, não é aplicado uma regra que seja mais focada a cada tipo de tag?

Comment: @DiegoFerreira  Não percebi muito bem. Quer dar um exemplo mais concreto? Qual foi essa resposta/Pergunta? Deveria ter feito o seu comentário lá

Comment: Peço perdão, tive a impressão de que esse debate estava em destaque no meta.

Comment: Mas já que o erro já foi cometido, apenas para complementar, a resposta que mencionei no comentário anterior, é a que você lincou, ***Como instruir o usuário que pergunta alguém pode me ajudar? ou ajuda a criar um programa, por favor? ou É possível?***, lá você menciona que se for decidido o veto dessa questões, haveria bem menos perguntas com a tag css, por exemplo. Daí a minha sugestão para que complementando as regras que já estão em vigor, fosse criado um conjunto de regras, focadas nas tags sobre o que é, e não é permitido.

Comment: @DiegoFerreira Eu diria que pode ser possível tentar arranjar uma solução/abordagem diferente consoante a técnologia usada. Contúdo da minha opinião é que se você fizer isso com várias tags existenstes você vai acabar por ter um processo confuso e não coerente e díficil de implementar/gerir. Por esse mesmo motivo eu considero que uma abordagem que pode ser seguida de forma geral é mais eficaz.

Comment: @DiegoFerreira Relacionado ao mesmo assunto eu também escrevi [a Minha pergunta foi fechada e agora](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7470). Com a intenção de providenciar a informação que especifiquei na minha respsota à pergunta [Como instruir o usuário que pergunta alguém pode me ajudar? ou ajuda a criar um programa, por favor? ou É possível?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7079)

Answer (score 1):

Eu não acho que todas as perguntas desse tipo devem ser fechadas, apenas as que forem amplas demais ou que tenham outros tipos de problema. Acabei de ver uma, postada recentemente e fechada, que tem uma resposta simples e útil:

> ## [Como alterar o favicon dinamicamente? [pendente]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/390507/)
>
> Gostaria de saber como faço para alterar o favicon da determinada página dinamicamente com Javascript.
>
> - Isto é possível?
> - Caso seja possível, como fazer?

Ver [Resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/260876/), são poucas linhas.

Isso é só um exemplo com o qual esbarrei agora, sei que não é nenhuma ótima pergunta, e tenho certeza de que tem exemplos melhores no site. O ponto é que perguntar como fazer algo, sem postar código, não é por si só motivo de fechamento, pra mim. Queria saber se os outros concordam. Às vezes parece que a comunidade age como se fosse sempre problema.

Comment: Mas a discussão não é se ele é ampla, ela não é, se fosse ampla ela seria fechada por ser ampla, existe um motivo para isto. A questão é se está no escopo porque ou a resposta é sim ou não ou a resposta é fazer para a pessoa, e todo o debate aqui tem a ver com a linha que separa uma coisa da outra. São poucas linhas, mas é fazer para a pessoa. O que isso tem de diferente do pedido de solução do exercício da faculdade? Quem garante que isso não é um exercício de faculdade? Então a análise deveria ser no conteúdo e não na intenção. Se pode isso porque o exercício de faculdade não pode?

Comment: A provocação do debate e insistência é justamente pra ter parâmetros, porque ser a favor ou contra esse tipo de pergunta é fácil, difícil e estabelecer uma linha de corte. E aparentemente as pessoas não estão muito interessadas em debater isto, houve baixíssimo interesse aqui mesmo tendo colocado em destaque duas vezes.

Comment: Pegando um exemplo (espero não ter entendido errado a pergunta por ser uma assunto que não domino): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/390531/101. Aqui parece uma pergunta muito boa com código e tudo. Mas o que o AP quer não tem nada escrito (salvo eu ter entendido errado), ela quer que pegue esse código todo para quem for responder estudar isso e escrever um código que faça o que ele pediu, o que está no enunciado que ele deu. Quantas linhas terá essa solução? 1? 50? 1000? Faz diferença para decidir se fecha ou não? E como vou saber quantas linhas serão? Tem que analisar se é fácil ou não?

Comment: Encontramos um https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat? Eu estou perdido no que é uma coisa ou não, então estou fazendo o que parece certo até que alguém consiga dar uma diretriz mais clara, até porque deixar pra lá e não analisar esses casos por não ter algo claro é uma decisão, eu preferi decidir fazer algo, porque sem a clareza qualquer ação, até inércia será errado. Outro exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/390526/101 mais difícil de decidir porque beira o conceitual que aceitamos e isto é bem claro, achei melhor não fechar por isso, mas não tenho certeza se estou certo.

Comment: Concordo que ninguém parece interessado em debater isso, também postei a resposta (e a outra pergunta, lá nos primórdios) pra tentar estimular o debate. Talvez isso, se a pergunta é do tipo que quer saber um procedimento, não seja um bom critério de classificação das perguntas. Se o problema são os trabalhos de faculdade, a maioria é fácil de identificar, e muita coisa é duplicada. E é fácil proibir se for o caso.

Comment: [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/402269/criar-um-aplicativo-de-envio-de-sms) o gato está claramente morto. Já em casos como [este](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/402256/como-extrair-a-parte-decimal-de-um-n%c3%bamero-flutuante) está mais pra vivo, embora esteja numa sobreposição de estados.