# Pergunta mal avaliada, como posso melhora-la?

Tags: debate

[Como criar/utilizar o schema builder?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/358811/como-criar-utilizar-o-schema-builder)

Tentei fazer a pergunta o mais claro possível para que as pessoas pudessem entender, coloquei o código, coloquei a documentação da biblioteca, porém não foi bem aceita pela comunidade.

O que eu estranhei é que ninguém comentou no código onde eu poderia melhorar a pergunta, ou querer saber mais algum detalhe.

Então acho que aqui é o lugar correto para fazer este tipo de pergunta, já que eu não participo muito da comunidade. Mas esta pergunta que fiz não tem nada de diferente de outras perguntas que foram bem aceitas, com diferença talvez da dificuldade de a pessoa conhecer algumas coisas a mais como o padrão de projeto builder.

O que eu vejo muitas vezes é gente caindo em cima para criticar, porém não propõe uma melhoria e não é isto que quero, apenas quero melhorar esta pergunta ou futuras perguntas para ser bem aceitas pela comunidade.

Comment: Olhando a sua pergunta, achei muito boa. Só acho (e isso é uma observação pessoal) que poderia melhorar na parte gramatical. Por ex., colocar pontuação adequada quando uma oração termina, coisas desse tipo. Desculpe mas eu sou bolado com o fato de que programadores "não precisam" saber escrever (a maioria não sabe). Não que seu texto seja de todo ruim, é até bom, mas acho que falta usar algumas pontuações para separar as orações no texto. Ex. mesmo nesta pergunta: "_para que as pessoas pudessem entender, coloquei o_".. após essa vírgula começa uma nova oração, portanto não cabe vírgula. ;)

Comment: Assim foi o caso da minha pergunta no [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/360536/mysql-consulta-em-tabelas-relacionadas) que foi negativada e nenhuma sugestão de melhoria na elaboração da pergunta ou comentários relacionados.

Answer (score 10):

Me parece que melhorou na segunda edição, mas ainda pede um exemplo. Isso é bem aberto, parece que quer algo pronto, mesmo que não seja a intenção. Poderia até ser considerada fora de escopo ou ampla (não estou dizendo que é, se eu tivesse certeza que é eu teria fechado). A terceira edição colocou um novo erro de sintaxe e sequer falou qual é (me parece bem não clara, e estou propenso a fechar por isto). Você tem que fazer perguntas específicas sobre o que quer. E os *links* de fechamento te levam para locais que dão boas dicas. [Veja a ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking). E também "teve uma discussão" sobre o assunto leia mais em [O que fazer com perguntas do tipo "quero fazer isto"?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7464/101).

Não posso ajudar muito porque desconhecer a tecnologia, mas faz um diferença enorme pedir por uma ajuda e dizer exatamente o que quer. Vou deixar para a comunidade avaliar melhor e quem sabe responder, ou te orientar melhor aqui se ainda precisar melhor. Mas de qualquer forma se puder pensar em algo mais que possa acrescentar para mostrar que tentou tudo, que pensou em tudo, que realmente precisa de algo mais, pode ajudar a levantar a pergunta. Lembre-se que pessoas aleatórias na internet não entendem seu problema é sua responsabilidade fazê-las entender, até porque elas não têm obrigação alguma de te ajudar.

Informações básicas não foram colocadas. O que isto indica? Em geral duas coisas: ou que a pessoa não se preocupou o suficiente com seu próprio problema; ou que a pessoa está tentando programar quando ela não consegue nem entender técnica básica de programação e o que é necessário para resolver um problema. Não estou afirmando que é isto, mas sempre passa a intenção.

Lamento que ninguém tenha comentado, mas entendo o lado deles também. Tem aparecido uma quantidade absurda de perguntas ruins onde as pessoas não se esforçam em nada. Elas mostram que não tem paciência nem para lidar com seu próprio problema e quer tudo "na boquinha" sem esforço. Isso vai minando a vontade das pessoas de ajudar,, fica desproporcional, quem precisa de ajuda não se ajuda, e transfere a responsabilidade de ficar ajudando em cada detalhe para quem vai ajudar, que não ganha nada com isso. Uma hora as pessoas vão cansando, porque é enxugar gelo, e "ninguém" mais recebe ajuda específica. Isto acaba filtrando e quem tem mais vontade, como você demonstrou agora, acaba tendo mais chance de receber atenção.

Na verdade as pessoas cansaram de criticar e na maioria das vezes nem dá certo, não faz nada melhorar, então as pessoas começam só negativar. Se você entender isso pode se dar melhor, se achar que é responsabilidade das pessoas doarem seu tempo para te ajudar mesmo quando elas não consideram que você se ajudou o suficiente, aí é provável que terá problemas.

Da mesma forma que você está criticando as pessoas não ajudarem, você criticou o fato das pessoas criticarem sem ajudar e você não está se ajudando, então é uma metacrítica.

[image: Seja você a mudança que tanto procura nos outros. As pessoas não mudam por cobranças, mudam com exemplos e pelo que vale a pena!].

Seria legal ter, mas não espere por ajuda específica, se vier, melhor, se não, faça sua parte, melhore o máximo que der, bote recompensa se achar que pode resolver.

Comment: Então o código é o mesmo que está no manual, no caso o erro de sitaxe acontece na linha 5. Não acho necessário um print screen pois o código já está lá para as pessoas verem. Levando em conta que o manual está lá, acredito que é só ajeitar a sintaxe pois acredito que o manual esteja errado. Apenas isto

Eu consegui fazer funcionar, mas não sei se seria o correto eu responder minha própria pergunta pois eu não sei se alguém poderia responder melhor a minha própria pergunta.

Comment: @FelipeJorge exatamente por esse tipo de atitude as pessoas negativam, você acaba de comprovar o que eu disse, você quer que as pessoas corram atrás da informação para te ajudar. Assuma a responsabilidade da sua pergunta, não transfira para outras pessoas.

Comment: Bom dei uma melhorada de onde está o erro, e porque ele ocorre. Acredito que melhorou bastante... Agora eles tem o manual, a linha de onde ocorre o erro, o código que deve ser mudado muito pouco, o Json que vai ser utilizado para comparação do builder. 

Acredito que agora tem o que faltava, ou será que ainda falta algo?

Talvez a versão da biblioteca que estou utilizando.

Comment: Acredito que agora a pergunta não está mais tão na boquinha, pois para ter o trabalho de mostrar o manual, de pegar o mesmo código do manual, de mostrar qual biblioteca tem que importar, de mostrar os erros e as possíveis causas do problema, do código já implementado.

Já dei praticamente tudo, agora se tiver mais alguma sugestão eu agradeço. Não acho que a pergunta está querendo tudo na boquinha pois para testar a pessoa só precisa saber o básico de Java e saber compilar um código simples, e responder uma pergunta sem testar é no mínimo um descuido muito ousado.

Comment: Nem mais nem menos @Maniero.

Comment: @JorgeB. ela ainda acha que as pessoas devem pegar o programa dele, compilar, testar, fazer tudo o que for necessário parta ajudá-lo, que não é obrigação dele entregar tudo isso feito e com todas informações necessárias só para quem for ajudar dar a informação que ele precisa. As pessoas se acostumam tanto em depender dos outros que não percebem quando estão pedindo demais. Eu me arrependi de ter respondi aqui.

Comment: @Maniero respondeu e muito bem, esta sua resposta, ou outra do género, devia estar no site, para poder linkar quando uma pessoa visse esse tipo de pergunta. Faz-me lembrar quando as pessoas me pedem para ajudar no dia a dia (para instalação de SO, etc) achando que não me custa nada ajuda-los, como se eu não tivesse contas para pagar e o meu tempo não fosse valioso. Mas o deles já é.

Comment: De fato é necessário compilar o código para responder, ninguém deve em hipótese alguma responder uma pergunta sem testar antes a não ser que tenha certeza de que irá funcionar.  Mas de fato não dependo da comunidade, pois se eu dependesse não me daria bem.

Eu fiz esta pergunta pois sei que terá gente que algum dia terá o mesmo problema que eu, e será facilmente achada no google, ou o manual irá arrumar seu erro.

Por mais que a pergunta pudesse ser melhorada, eu falei qual era o possível erro, dei o manual, o código, o json esperado. Agora o mínimo é a pessoa compilar o código.