# Postar mensagem de erro como imagem

Tags: suporte, como-perguntar

Tem problema em postar mensagem de erro como imagem? Se sim, quais as desvantagens?

O [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/132) não deixa explícito mensagem de erro ser diferente de código.

Caso: [Problema na hora de fazer push no GitHub](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/388005/problema-na-hora-de-fazer-push-no-github).

Comment: Só de não poder copiar e colar numa pesquisa já é motivo suficiente pra não ser desejável. Fora isso, no exemplo citado, gastou um espaço imenso para pouca informação, tanto visualmente quanto em bytes. Tem mais uma série de problemas, alguns mencionados na resposta dada, mas não só aqueles. Simplificando: imagem não é adequado para informação textual, e sim para conteúdo em que o visual é relevante.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Segue alguns **ÓTIMOS** motivos para **NÃO** postar **códigos**, **erros** e **logs** como imagens ou fotos:

### Bloqueio do domínio imgur.com

Alguns usuários usam *"proxy de rede"* que bloqueia certos sites, como o `imgur.com` (site de compartilhamento de imagens que os [sites da rede Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) usam), inclusive um participante bastante ativo no site tinha este problema, pois na empresa que ele estava muitos sites eram bloqueados. Se postar imagem de log ou código será impossível de ler o erro.

### Sites de busca (Google, Bing, etc.)

Deve compreender que muita gente chega no site pelos buscadores (google, bing, etc), pesquisando pela *"mensagem de erro"* ou *"trecho de código"* e se você postar assim não terá como o buscador adivinhar o "texto" da sua "imagem" e indexar a pergunta com aquilo.

Precisamos de bom senso, imagem não é texto, para nós humanos pode ser fácil de entender um texto em uma foto, mas para o computador não é, logo usar imagens  dificuldade em procurar a solução para o problema.

### Graus de deficiência visual

Apesar de ser um pouco incomum existem programadores com algum grau de deficiência avançado, aqui no site conheci 2 programadores com tal situação, eles utilizam [leitores de tela](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leitor_de_tela) para poder ler as postagens no site, se postar uma imagem simplesmente não será possível ler com os leitores de tela, impossibilitando a pessoa de ajudar com sua pergunta.

### Para testar o código somos obrigados a transcrevê-lo

É preciso compreender que na maioria das vezes vamos testar o código, nem sempre de só de olhar iremos notar o problema, muitas vezes temos que testar antes de responder, sendo uma imagem ao invés de texto acabamos obrigados a digitar manualmente caractere por caractere da imagem, isto faz com que:

1. Percamos um longo tempo
2. Nem sempre consigamos ver o que esta escrito (não só por questões de deficiência visual, mas por simples fatos de imagens de baixa qualidade)
3. As pessoas percam interesse na sua pergunta e desistam

O principal motivo em usar texto é poder depurar/analisar mais breve possível.

Comment: As pessoas não se importam com as outras e o pior é que tem gente que defende que isso é certo.

Comment: So para acrescentar + 1 problema, o zoom. Muitas das vezes a imagem só da para ver bem com zoom, o que implica abrir num separador a parte, dando ainda mais trabalho.

Comment: @Isac isso se enquadra na legibilidade e qualidade. Sinceramente, não vejo nenhuma vantagem em usar imagens puramente verbais em qualquer contexto da publicação. Atrasa o carregamento da página, torna ilegível o conteúdo, dificulta a resposta e compreensão da pergunta, etc.

Comment: No caso de código: pra reproduzir é muito ruim. Se alguém quiser fazer um teste com o código terá que transcrevê-lo.

Comment: @LINQ +1, vou elaborar um pouco mais sem tornar a resposta um "monstro"

Comment: mas se a pergunta tiver o comando e erro como imagem e escrito na pergunta ao mesmo tempo?  não deveria remover a imagem? @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: @RenatoC.Francisco sim, mas algumas edições ficam confusas quando chegam pra aprovação, foi confusão do meu entedimento do markdown, pareceu outra coisa, de qualquer forma editei em seguida ajustando como você enviou a primeira edit. ps: a pergunta, sobre git, em si é basicamente erro, logo o fechamento é o mais adequado.