# O que fazer diante de uma pergunta duplicata que não tem resposta e de má qualidade?

Tags: debate, perguntas-duplicadas

O cenário que enfrentei hoje é o seguinte:

- O usuário fez uma pergunta que teve que ser fechada por não atender os critérios do site.
- O mesmo usuário fez a mesma pergunta, sem melhorias na qualidade da mesma.
- A maioria dos usuários que votaram para fechar o fizeram marcando a anterior como duplicata.

Nesse caso, considerando que a pergunta ruim foi fechada e foi simplesmente repostada com a mesma qualidade da anterior:

- Marco como duplicata?
- Fecha pelo motivo da anterior?

Isso gera mais uma dúvida: A pergunta que fechei não chegou a ter respostas (e nem tinha como ter :p).

Sendo assim:

- O recurso de marcar como duplicata deveria ser usado apenas para o caso onde leva o usuário a uma resposta?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *O recurso de marcar como duplicata deveria ser usado apenas para o caso onde leva o usuário a uma resposta?*

Eu entendo que sim.

A ideia de marcar como duplicata - pelo menos a [ideia original de um dos fundadores do site](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) - é de que duplicatas sirvam para indicar: "*olha, aqui já tem a resposta para a sua pergunta*".

Então se apontamos para uma pergunta sem resposta, perde-se o propósito original. Até porque a mensagem atual do *box* azul de fechamento é "*Essa pergunta já tem respostas aqui: [lista de dups]*", então até mesmo a UI fica incoerente se apontarmos para uma pergunta sem respostas (obs: apontar para uma com respostas ruins também é prejudicial, o ideal é que o *dup target* seja algo com qualidade aceitável).

---

No caso específico, quando o mesmo usuário faz a mesma pergunta várias vezes (e ela é *off topic*), acho que devemos fechá-las usando-se os motivos usuais (fora do escopo, não-clara, etc), em vez de indicar uma duplicata. Em caso de abuso (alguns chegam a postar 3 vezes, mesmo recebendo comentários em todas elas), acho que caberia até sinalização (tem que ver caso a caso).

Eu costumava deixar comentários dizendo para não postar de novo e em vez disso editar a pergunta original, mas como sempre a grande maioria ignorava e não fazia nada. Hoje eu só voto pra fechar e pronto.

Answer (score 3):

O ideal é que só devemos marcar como duplicada quando ambas perguntas **puderem coexistir**.

Por exemplo, a pergunta "duplicada" tenha boas resposta e também seja uma pergunta que ajude as pessoas a encontrar nos "buscadores", titulo e conteúdo, dessa forma para que é proveitoso em questão de qualidade para o site, pois nem toda pergunta duplicata é útil ou vai ajudar as pessoas se "encontrarem" no meio das soluções (respostas), então tem que ver caso a caso, não tem como ter uma resposta única do que fazer.

Se a pergunta duplicada quase exata é do mesmo autor, que eventualmente ocorre quando uma pessoa tem sua pergunta fechada ela tenta contornar refazendo a pergunta, nesse caso você não deve votar para fechar como duplicada, mas sim com o mesmo fechamento da pergunta original.

Devo reforçar que perguntas mal elaboradas devem usar o fechamento apropriado pois é improvável que sirvam como "duplicada", afinal o objetivo (ao menos era) da comunidade e site é ter conteúdo útil/proveitoso a futuros visitantes e que não sejam apenas puro helpdesk.

---

Eu costumo trabalhar no **preventivo**, ao invés de ficar tentando remediar depois que o usuário repete a pergunta para tentar contornar um fechamento, uso um comentário "enlatado" com orientações mais claras possíveis e tentando ser o mais educado possível, o texto é mais ou menos esse:

> Olá <nome do usuário>. É importante você **edit** e adicionar **um [mcve] do problema**, com um passo a passo do que já fez e explicar de forma clara e objetiva o que precisa. **Não delete e não repita a pergunta**, basta editar e aguardar o processo de reabertura (que vai passar por uma auditoria). Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Obrigado por compreender.

Exemplo para uso:

```
Olá <nome do usuário>. É importante você **[edit]** e adicionar **um [mcve] do problema**, com um passo a passo do que já fez e explicar de forma clara e objetiva o que precisa. **Não delete e não repita a pergunta**, basta editar e aguardar o processo de reabertura (que vai passar por uma auditória). Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Obrigado por compreender.
```

Antes dessa mensagem eu tentei 6 diferentes mensagens semiprontas que para orientar os novos usuários, mas essa foi a que teve mais efeito positivo. Claro que volta e meia tem um ou outro que insisti em não seguir as orientações, mas são exceções, antes desse comentário eu tinha que fechar uma média de 15 a 20 perguntas por dia, agora ficou na média do 10 a 15, 5 geralmente eram repetições.

Vale notar que eu nunca uso o nome completo do usuário ou se for um nickname nunca uso o `@usuario`, uso sempre como `Olá Maria. É ...`, porque tem que ficar claro que estou dando atenção a postagem e entendo que ali do outro lado é um ser humano e a mensagem não pode soar como algo genérico e automático, pois acredito que a pessoa no momento do fechamento ainda sim precisa entender que estamos tentando apoia-la a melhorar a pergunta e queremos ajudar.

Pessoalmente acho que qualquer membro do site pode atuar como "moderador voluntário" e comentar algo parecido orientando desde cedo os novos participantes, mais "moderadores", melhor para o site e para todos.

---

Alguns novos usuários costumam colocar fotos de logs e códigos ao invés de simplesmente copiar o texto, isso complica fazer testes e fazer pesquisas, fora que também atrapalha a indexação em motores de busca ou a própria busca no site, para esses casos uso o comentário a seguir:

> Olá <nome do usuário>. É importante você **edit** e adicionar **um [mcve] do problema** ([evite mostrar códigos e logs como imagens](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/)), com um passo a passo do que já fez e explicar de forma clara e objetiva o que precisa. **Não delete e não repita a pergunta**, basta editar e aguardar o processo de reabertura (que vai passar por uma auditoria). Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Obrigado por compreender.

Exemplo para uso:

```
Olá <nome do usuário>. É importante você **edit** e adicionar **um [mcve] do problema** ([evite mostrar códigos e logs como imagens](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/)), com um passo a passo do que já fez e explicar de forma clara e objetiva o que precisa. **Não delete e não repita a pergunta**, basta editar e aguardar o processo de reabertura (que vai passar por uma auditoria). Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Obrigado por compreender.
```

Answer (score 0):

Um caso concreto relacionado a isso foi eu que reportei.

Segue as perguntas do mesmo usuário.

- 1ª [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/492860/ola-preciso-que-este-codigo-ao-rodar-defina-de-qual-pais-a-pesoa-%C3%A9-mas-n%C3%A3o-es)
- 2ª [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/492871/alguem-pode-me-ajudar-preciso-desenvolver-um-codigo-que-me-retorne-o-pais-de-o?noredirect=1#comment915992_492871)

A duplicata que eu gostaria de me referir.

- A [duplicata com respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/490926/qual-o-erro-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo/490933#490933)

Problema é que eu não consegui encontrar esta pergunta que eu havia respondido por causa da maneira como o usuário postou a pergunta, eu não consegui encontrar devido ao SEO por que o conteúdo estava muito diferente em todas as perguntas.

Quando eu fiz o flag da pergunta duplicada indiquei o link errado, tem como desfazer o flag e corrigir os links para apontar pra os recursos corretos?

## edit

O problema é que quando eu fiz a flag, por padrão ele adicionou um comentário:

> Isto responde à sua pergunta? ola preciso que este codigo , ao rodar
> defina de qual pais a pesoa é, mas não estou encontrando onde esta o
> erro

Que está nos comentários da segunda pergunta, é como se fosse uma automação da ação de flag para perguntas duplicadas.

Mas isso é uma dúvida sim. Porque no momento eu fiquei sem saber como proceder, aí deve ter gerado até esta pergunta no meta.

Comment: Quando a flag tá incorreta, a moderação pode marcar como rejeitada a flag.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, acho que ele quer acrescentar [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/490926/137387) a lista de duplicadas [dessa outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/492860/137387). Danizavtz, se for isso você poderá fazer somente quando tiver a medalha de [ouro na linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold).

Comment: @AugustoVasques que engraçado... As perguntas são bem parecidas, porém de usuários diferentes    

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, Sim são de usuários diferentes mas respondem a mesma questão.

Comment: Sim, de fato, na verdade, o fato de o usuário ter feito vários posts (perguntas e respostas) com a mesma coisa, acabou confundindo tudo.

Comment: Mas eu estou achando que a resposta do Danizavtz tá parecendo mais uma pergunta aqui no meta. Se for isso, favor abrir uma questão no meta, para podermos ajudar, caso haja alguma dúvida. Até porque responder aqui nos comentários é meio complicado...

Comment: Concordo... é uma pergunta sobre procedimento.

Comment: Como eu não modero acho melhor deixar apenas um caso concreto para análise.

Comment: "*é como se fosse uma automação da ação de flag para perguntas duplicadas*" - sim, quando vc indica uma dup, o sistema coloca esse comentário automático. Mas vc pode apagar se quiser, pois a pergunta já foi fechada mesmo...  -  "*eu não modero*" - na verdade o papel de moderar o site [é de todos](/q/8437/112052), e ao indicar duplicadas (ou sinalizar para fechar uma pergunta, por qq motivo), vc já está ajudando a moderar :-)

Comment: Nas últimas eleições eu bati muito nesse ponto, todos somos moderadores e você @Danizavtz é atuante na comunidade.

Comment: Olá Danizavtz. Bem a dica que dou foi a mesma da minha resposta, para duplicar algo tem que ser bom ou ser mais que um helpdesk, porque perguntas dups irão coexisitir, se não for para coexistirem e as perguntas q pretendia marcar como dup forem meros helpdesks (o que parece ser o caso de ambas) então o ideal é só fechar como questão de qualidade e não marcar como dup. Para marcar como dup, o coexistir precisa ser útil para a comunidade e busca de perguntas.