# Guia de sobrevivência do SOpt - Versão curta

Tags: debate, perguntas, comunidade

Você é o maior interessado em ter sua pergunta respondida, então tem que fazer todo esforço possível para melhorá-la para ser reaberta. Pode ser fácil ou não. Nós queremos reabrir mas apenas se tiver qualidade suficiente.

Aqui **não somos um fórum** ou rede social, ou grupo de WhatsApp como você conhece. Você chegou aqui porque a qualidade do conteúdo é reconhecido, e para manter assim precisamos ser rígidos com o que pode ser perguntado, senão matamos a galinha dos ovos de ouro e deixamos uma galinha comum.

Você precisa ter capacidade para **entender instruções**, saber se comunicar e entendimento básico de matemática para fazer isso. Também precisa esforço, persistência e comprometimento. Se não tiver essas características não será fácil para você programar, que exige muito de uma pessoa, não é tão fácil como parece. Podemos estar te poupando de uma grande desilusão.

- Se sua pergunta é **só um enunciado**, mesmo que disfarçado e pede para fazer o código para você, ou dar uma explicação muito extensiva, então será difícil ajudar. Só se você colocar um problema mais específico salva sua pergunta.

  Se a pergunta permite uma resposta do tipo "sim/não", ou ela é simples demais ou na verdade quer que a pessoa explique tudo sobre isso para você. Não dá para responder isso mantendo a qualidade, mesmo que você ache que dá. Nós temos experiência aqui e sabemos que não dá, nunca deu.
- Se sua pergunta pede **tutorial, material, indicação** de algo externo ou pede opinião do que usar também não deve ser fácil salvar.
- Se a pergunta **falta informações**, tais como: parte do código ou todo ele, ou qual é o erro e todos detalhes relevantes dele, ou de como reproduzi-lo, ou a pergunta está solta demais, aberta, até está colocando o que é necessário, mas não explica bem o objetivo e qual o erro específico então a pergunta precisa melhorar nesse ponto. Mesmo que você ache que tem tudo se uma pessoa experiente vê que falta, não adianta insistir, apenas leia novamente o terceiro parágrafo.
- Se você colocou tudo, mas **colocou demais**, temos que olhar todo seu código, se não tem apenas **um** problema determinado, está só pedindo ajuda, procure um modo de reduzir o código para só reproduzir o que precisa. Podemos responder outros pontos mas em perguntas diferentes. Tem dicas e mais detalhes na versão longa.
- Se você só quer **dicas, luz, norte, ajuda genérica** ou algo do tipo, aqui não é um bom lugar, precisamos ajudar todo mundo com algo mais claro e específico, e que possa ser aproveitado por outras pessoas.

**Se não consegue entender** essas coisas provavelmente ainda não está preparada(o) para programar ou usar este site. Se não ligar para nada disto, não tem o comprometimento que esperamos de você. Se não vai fazer sua parte não exija que nós façamos.

**Se está começando, faça perguntas simples**, de novatos, um ponto só por pergunta, é muito fácil fazer isso, se concentre nisso, capriche e você terá uma resposta.

Se está fazendo uma pergunta mais complexa não está começando, então não use o argumento que está. Ou se está começando mesmo, está cometendo um erro de tentar fazer o acabamento de uma casa sem um alicerce, isso não dá certo e você não consegue melhorar sua resposta porque pulou o básico, volte um pouco para trás.

E por favor, não insista para mantermos aberta uma pergunta que não atende esses critérios, é como ir em um açougue e exigir que te vendam uma caneta. Cada site tem um objetivo, **o nosso é responder o que tem qualidade**, até perguntas simples de novatos. Gaste energias para melhorar a pergunta em vez de reclamar que não aceitamos te entregar o que não é o que fazemos aqui.

Quer ajuda melhor? Não tem jeito, tem que [**ler a versão completa**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101). Se não entender, releia, com calma, com mente aberta, prestando atenção, e siga os *links* (sim, dá trabalho). Se ainda não conseguir, não sei se será capaz de participar do site ou programar, lamentamos por isso. Já falei que precisa de esforço e comprometimento para programar? Comece exercitar isso. Um passo de cada vez.

E na dúvida leia de novo sua pergunta, com atenção. Provavelmente ali está claro porque ela foi fechada mas quando estava escrevendo não percebeu, principalmente porque depois de ler o guia te dá mais base.

Comment: Editei o comentário padrão para incluir a versão curta, atualize com ele: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8046/101.

Comment: Não sei se vale de alguma coisa, mas deixo o meu registro de que prefiro o guia completo.