# Entendendo motivo de fechamento "erro de digitação"

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, perguntas-fechadas

### Título original: Pergunta atende todos os requisitos do site foi fechada

Fiz uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/491581/13561) com resposta para tratar uma mensagem de erro nova no PHP 8.

A questão foi fechada e assinalada como:

> Esse problema *não pode ser reproduzido*, ou é um *erro de digitação*. Mesmo dentro do escopo do site, sua solução dificilmente seria útil a outros usuários no futuro. Problemas assim podem ser evitados com a criação de um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável.

Minha pergunta atende todos os requisitos do site:

- tem um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável e pode ser reproduzido
- é útil, no futuro alguém vai pesquisar a mensagem de erro no Google e encontrar a solução
- **não** é um erro de digitação - erro de digitação é quando uma palavra é digitada **incorretamnete**

A pergunta assinalada como "relacionada" não trata a mensagem de erro.

Qual a sua avaliação dessa situação?

---

Outras perguntas com a mesma estrutura (só porque estão (estavam) abertas não significa que são "boas"):

- [Como corrigir o erro no PHP - Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Curl error (code 77)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/420932/13561)
- [Como solucionar “Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Usuario' not found”](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/341320/13561)
- [Erro no PHP … Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function modify() on boolean](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/340162/13561)
- [Erro Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getList()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189527/13561)

---

### Edição

Após debate nos comentários percebi que o debate trata mais sobre a definição de "erro de digitação", se foi erro de tradução, se "erro de uso" ou "erro de sintaxe" se encaixam na categoria.

Na minha interpretação há uma grande diferença entre faltar um `;` e faltar algum trecho de código na implementação de uma api. Se tem uma mensagem de erro, um exemplo de código verificável, não é duplicada a pergunta deveria ficar aberta. Acho que deveríamos estar mais preocupad@s em manter perguntas com a estrutura com código reproduzível, do que julgar e classificar erros.

Comment: A minha é que foi fechada corretamente, pois se trata de um erro mesmo (o fato de ser intencional não muda o fato). Perigosa essa premissa, pois tem muitas outras maneiras de gerar erro em PHP, seriam infinitas perguntas, muitas delas bem mais importantes do que o erro mencionado. Note que é diferente de situações como o "undefined index", que tem toda uma fundamentação (é um erro bem comum, não precisa forçar artificialmente).

Comment: Sobre as que apontou, já estou fechando algumas. Lembre-se: o fato de uma pergunta estar aberta não significa que ela seja boa (simplesmente pode ter "passado batido"). E ainda, teve uma época que houve uma tentativa de ampliar o escopo do site (mal sucedida, por sinal), então tem coisas antigas que são referências ruins (não estou me referindo especificamente aos seus links)

Comment: Olá Pedro, ali é erro de digitação ao meu ver, o uso como é indicado dos Attributes é sempre, conforme doc: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.attributes.overview.php. Errar um `;` ou quantidade de parametros de um método nativo não valida existir uma pergunta, a situação aqui é a mesma.

Comment: Ainda, uma outra questão: Perguntas fechadas como erro de digitação, com votos positivos em boas respostas, ficam no site servindo de referência. O fechamento não atrapalha a utilidade dela no Google e outros buscadores (o fechamento é organização, não "demérito" pra boas respostas, bem fundamentadas). Só pra constar, dos links passados, já fechei todos (e positivei uma resposta que achei boa) - se tiver outros casos assim, pode usar a sinalização nos posts que a gente avalia.

Comment: Outro detalhe, que já informei no META outras vezes, não é pq tem uma pergunta aberta antiga que ela deveria estar de fato aberta, entenda que são centenas de perguntas por dia, o apoio da comunidade É BAIXO, pouquissimos usuários ajudam na moderação comunitária, então algumas perguntas passam batido, teve pergunta de 2015 q votei pra fechar por ser erro de digitação que acabou ficando aberta por mais de 4 anos depois, os moderadores diamante não tem como acompanhar 100% das perguntar criadas, por isso o apoio comunitário é tão importante.

Comment: @PedroSanção o que pode acontecer no caso concreto é, se possível, elaborar mais a teoria da resposta, sobre o fundamento, além de mera correção, e ver se positiva. Isso faz com que a longevidade do post mude completamente. Não vou palpitar muito sobre o teor, pois é um recurso do PHP que eu realmente não tenho interesse, então não estudei adequadamente para poder palpitar na resposta. Em resumo: até dá pra fazer o que vc tentou, mas tem como melhorar o conjunto todo. Pergunta fechada com resposta bem votada não atrapalha o seu objetivo.

Comment: Note que tem perguntas antigas que eu até cheguei a responder, mas a maioria na época votei para fechar, eu não era moderador e não tinha poder de fechar, e tentava ajudar as pessoas, mesmo que off-topic, não quer dizer q as perguntas ali atendiam aos requisitos, era mais uma atitude "helpdesker" que eu possuia na época e que muitos usuários possuem até hoje. Não quer dizer que seja certo.

Comment: Entendi sobre a irrelevância de citar perguntas antigas. Desde sempre a minha impressão sobre o StackOverflow é justamente ajudar pessoas desenvolvedoras com erros de programação. A definição de "erro de digitação" é meio "borrada" e está sujeito a interpretação. A minha interpretação é diferente e respeito a posição de vocês, mas deveríamos estar mais preocupado em manter perguntas com a estrutura com código reproduzível, do que classificar erros.

Comment: @PedroSanção e com certeza, mesmo com post fechado, pode ajudar muito (o segredo está na elaboração da resposta) - insistindo no ponto, mesmo uma da sua lista, com resposta minha (que fechei hoje, como moderador) - vai continuar podendo receber votos e servir de referência - o fechamento não atrapalha a utilidade :) - o tempo que investi na resposta não foi perdido, ela continua lá pra quem buscar o erro.

Comment: @PedroSanção errar um `;` ou quantidade de parâmetros de um método nativo não valida existir uma pergunta, a situação aqui é a mesma. Ontem teve uma pergunta de uma pessoa que não conseguia usar forEach com objeto normal (não iterável), `causando undefined function`, é erro de digitação, pq objetos normais nunca foram iteráveis (apesar de funcionar em `for..in` e `for..of`, mas .forEach é uma função estendida de `Array.prototype.forEach`, logo não é para todos "objetos', ou seja, erro de uso (digitação). O mesmo vale para o Attributes, desde a primeira versão php8 tem q definir na classe

Comment: @Bacco vou descrever melhor a resposta e incluir detalhamentos, entendi o seu ponto

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento exatamente ai a discussão caminha para "erro de uso é considerado erro de digitação"

Comment: @PedroSanção tem um problema de tradução, eu não gosto do termo "digitação" pq dá impressão de mero "typo", e o sentido verdadeiro do fechamento é mais amplo. Isso é generalizado na nossa UI, as mensagens são meio engessadas - temos ferramenta de tradução, mas não liberdade total pra editar o teor das mensagens "built in" (em outra ocasião até dá pra elaborar isso, mas aqui vai ficar extenso).

Comment: @PedroSanção é mais questão de tradução como disse o Bacco, trabalhamos muito em meados de 2018 para traduzir o site, mas tem problemas ainda e muita coisa fica complicada. De qualquer forma é erro de digitação pq "faltou algo" que no minimo é o básico, erro de digitação não é só digitar uma palavra totalmente errada, é "faltar com coisas" essenciais para que algo execute.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento minha interpretação é justamente nesse sentido de "typo", e acho que a raiz da questão que trago aqui

Comment: Exatamente o que o @Bacco disse no comentário acima. O recurso "erro de digitação" eu vejo mais como "erro de sintaxe" e coisas do tipo. A maioria das perguntas do site que vejo como erro de sintaxe geralmente são causadas por desatenção do usuário, falta de consulta prévia à documentação, desconhecimento da versão utilizada, e afins... O que **na maioria das vezes** faz com que essas perguntas ajudem somente o autor, e não beneficiaria outra pessoa.  Eu confesso que, como regra pessoal, ou fecho ou voto negativo, ou faço os dois ao mesmo tempo, quando vejo esse tipo de caso.

Comment: @PedroSanção se fosse "erro de sintaxe" ou "erro de parse (do 'analisador')" poderia até ser o q disse, mas não é, é erro do que "foi digitado", q podemos considerar como algo mais amplo, claro que concordo totalmente q o texto poderia ser mais claro, o q entra nos problemas de tradução q o Bacco citou, mas acho q temos tantos outros problemas q esse é dos menores e cabe a comunidade ter bom senso de compreender q aquilo serve amplamente e não tem nada especifico, é um fechamento que serve para erros sobre "parse" e "runtime", ou seja, escrita mesmo ou até uso incorreto de alguma API/sintaxe.

Answer (score 4):

Como eu já [comentei](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8544/discuss%C3%A3o-sobre-defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-erro-de-digita%C3%A7%C3%A3o-na-tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-site-para-pt#comment34117_8544), a mensagem não esta afirmando que o fechamento é por `erro de parse (do analisador)` ou `erro de como foi escrito uma API e falhou em runtime`, a mensagem é genérica: **erro de digitação**, ela serve perfeitamente para qualquer coisa que foi escrita, não precisamos nos apegar a detalhes, o que importa é que simplesmente na pergunta:

- [O que define uma classe de atributo no PHP 8?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/491581/3635)

Foi erro de uso, e desde a primeira versão do PHP8 disponível o `class` tem que receber `#[Attribute]`, se a pessoa não colou é porque ou esqueceu ou não esta usando algo que não sabe como funciona, o que é algo bastante trivial, não passa de 13 caracteres (12 + quebra de linha).

> ... Acho que deveríamos estar mais preocupad@s em manter perguntas com a estrutura com código reproduzível, do que julgar e classificar erros.

Não estamos classificando erros, ao contrário, estaríamos "classificando erros" se começássemos a enumerar todos tipos de erro ou mau da linguagem ou APIs uso **na hora de escrever um script**, não temos que fazer um cavalo de batalha porque "erro de digitação" pareceu outra coisa de começo, é uma frase genérica e serve para:

- Erro de uso da linguagem
- Erro de uso de uma API
- Erro de parse por algo que escreveu errado

Não há julgamento ou classificação, o motivo é basicamente esse, usou incorretamente algo, que é bem simples, se todo ponto e vírgula em uma sintaxe nova (a cada nova que aparecer) que eu esquecer vale-se uma pergunta, o site estaria forrado de perguntas assim.

Uma pergunta sobre `attributes` do PHP8 seria mais útil a comunidade se ela (a pergunta) fosse focada no funcionamento técnico e não em "mau uso" (escrita incorreta).

Comment: só achei exagero "cavalo de batalha"

Comment: Olá @PedroSanção. Também acho exagero, fazer um "cavalo de batalha" quando temos problemas muito mais graves, focar em algo que não é de fato um problema, mas uma questão de entendimento e adaptação é fazer o tal cavalo de batalha (insistir na importância de algo que não é realmente um problema). Por isso toda a orientação e o pedido de bom senso, não só para você, isso vale para qualquer usuário do site sobre o entendimento do tipo de fechamento. Obrigado por ler e compreender ;)

Comment: Agradeço pelo seu tempo despendido aqui, estou buscando entender o que a comunidade considera motivo para fechar, pois a fila de análise nunca acaba e tenho tentado ajudar a moderação por lá.

Comment: @PedroSanção na verdade acaba sim, se o seu voto de reabertura sumir da pergunta é pq a maioria dos usuários votou em "deixar fechada", mais detalhes em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/reviews-intro / https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/review-reopen  ... de resto recomendo a todos que leiam o [guia](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/3635)

Comment: mas eu tava falando da fila de "votos para fechar" https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/, entendi perfeitamente os motivos para fechar a minha questão, deixa ela fechada, o voto coloquei antes de conversar aqui

Comment: @PedroSanção a fila de votos para fechar é parte da "fila de analises", está tudo interligado ;)