# Perguntas sobre erro de sintaxe são proveitosas?

Tags: debate

Aqui no site, eu costumo usar a opção de fechamento *"Esse problema não pode ser reproduzido ou é um erro de digitação..."* para assinalar perguntas que possuam "erro de sintaxe" e coisas do tipo. E perguntas desse tipo tem aparecido por aqui com frequência .

Como comentei em uma pergunta feita aqui no meta a pouco tempo atrás, *a maioria das perguntas do site que vejo como erro de sintaxe geralmente são causadas por desatenção do usuário, falta de consulta prévia à documentação, desconhecimento da versão ou da linguagem utilizada e afins.*

Isso geralmente faz com que essas perguntas ajudem somente o autor da mesma, caso tenham uma resposta.

Nesses casos que citei, eu geralmente, ou fecho a pergunta, ou voto negativo, ou faço os dois ao mesmo tempo.

Mas, como estamos em uma comunidade, me preocupo um pouco sobre estar sendo *mente fechada* demais, e gostaria de saber:

- Existe algum caso onde perguntas que apresentam erro de sintaxe possa ser proveitosa para o site?

Comment: Minha opinião não está nem tanto a mar nem tanto a terra. Sempre que vejo uma pergunta dessas me pergunto se ela pode ser útil para alguém chegando no Stack Overflow ou se aquilo será útil para o próprio usuário. Quando é útil apenas para o usuário ainda assim gosto de deixar um comentário ou uma resposta, mas concordo com o fechamento. Por exemplo, [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/490409/números-vermelhos-no-visual-studio/490411#490411) você esteve corretíssimo em fechar a resposta - mas fico feliz de ter chego lá e respondido o usuário antes disso.

Comment: Por outro lado existem perguntas envolvendo erros de sintaxe mais "populares", *corner-cases* de uma linguagem de programação ou até mesmo erros do usuário envolvendo o IDE ou ambiente de programação. Eu vejo bastante valor nesse tipo de questão. Na era de ouro do SOen algumas dessas perguntas receberam centenas ou até milhares de voto. Eu mesmo tenho uma resposta super *low effort* que explodiu no SOen: [*why can't I set up a breakpoint in eclipse?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8748136/664577). Da mesma forma, vejo problemas como uso de `=` ao invés de `==` como úteis para a comunidade.

Comment: É claro que isso é difícil de moderar, em especial é difícil não deixar com que várias perguntas cometendo o mesmo erro de sintaxe se propaguem. Dito isso, se o erro é popular o suficiente para atrair dezenas de milhares e dezenas / centenas de *upvotes* eu diria que ela é útil para a comunidade e passa do meu crivo. Em alguns casos talvez ainda valha fechar uma questão assim e criar um par questão/resposta canônicas para o problema; fechar como duplicado é melhor do que não reproduzido pois quem chegar no site graças a pergunta vai encontrar sua resposta.

Comment: TL;DR (isso deveria ter sido uma resposta e não um comentário :D): Eu fecharia sem dó questões onde estão faltando aspas, ponto e vírgula e coisas do gênero usando esse critério de erro de digitação. Já questões do tipo usuário tentando usar `List<int>` em Java ou confundindo `=` com `==` podem gerar respostas interessantes e ajudar muita gente; nesse caso penso que só vale a pena fecharmos a pergunta como duplicada, e isso apenas se existir uma pergunta canônica para o problema.

Comment: Não tenho muito tempo de elaborar uma resposta, porque parte seria dito sobre experiências que já tive no site e outra sobre "teoria", mas o que posso resumir é alguns [erro de digitação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8545/3635) ou *"especificamente de sintaxe"* podem sim ter proveito, mas é algo eventual, por isso é bom analisar caso a caso, não tem como criar uma "regra geral". Eu poderia citar alguns exemplos (quando me sobrar um pouco mais de tempo) que me recordo que entrariam em possíveis exceções, mas já adianto que são pouquissimos casos.

Comment: **Quero lembrar a todos** que nem sempre fechamento é "exclusão eterna", a dica é simples, se você vê potencial na postagem você pode perfeitamente votar para reabrir e também trazer o assunto para o META, mas tem que ter consciência de que você pode estar equivocado e tem que estar aberto a ouvir a explicações ou opiniões contrárias e ter paciencia ao argumentar, porque muita gente que talvez venha a discordar do seu ponto de vista talvez tenham muita experiência em avaliar esse tipo de caso e estão lhe contrariando simplesmente porque estão lhe orientando.