# Guia de sobrevivência - Clique aqui para entender este site

Tags: debate, perguntas, comunidade

O SOpt é um site com foco em fazer perguntas e respostas. Ele não é um fórum ou mural de *helpdesk*.

Se a sua pergunta **ajudará a coletividade aprender algo sobre programação**, ela é boa para o site.

Se a sua pergunta serve exclusivamente para resolver o seu problema, a pergunta não é boa. Não se chateie se ela não for bem recebida.

Se isto não for suficiente, tem o [Guia de sobrevivência do SOpt - Versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101). Siga os *links* lá.

Comment: Versão super simplificada, vamos ver se agora é suficiente para o pessoal não dizer que não vai ler. è o único motivo de ter criado este *post*. Se a pessoa realmente quiser entender porque a pergunta foi fechada/negativada tem que ler mais. Se ela não quiser está deixando claro que não gosta do SOpt.

Comment: Guia de sobrevivência do SOpt - for dummies.

Comment: Deveria algo como um comentário automático pra perguntas fechadas. Talvez um botão "saiba mais" que abre um modal com esse texto

Comment: Quem discorda(votou negativo) poderia nos esclarecer se a discorda sobre o *SOpt ser um site com foco em fazer perguntas e respostas* ou se discorda do *SOpt  não ser um fórum ou mural de helpdesk* ou se  discorda de que *perguntas que ajudam a coletividade são boas para o site* ou se discorda que *problemas individuais específicos não geram boas perguntas no site*? Afinal essa é a [visão do criador do site](https://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/) e nós estamos a seguindo, se sabe algo de que não sabemos por favor faça sua contribuição para a comunidade e nos esclareça.

Comment: @AugustoVasques vai ver que  a mensagem está "atingindo" o público alvo :D

Comment: Poderia traduzir `helpdesk` como `suporte técnico` destacar em parêntesis para deixar mais claro. Ou se tiver algum sinônimo mais representativo.