# Como deixar claro para o AP o motivo do "Fora de Escopo"

Tags: debate, razões-fechamento

A pergunta [PHP cortando minutos e segundos de retorno de data em SQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/544175/php-cortando-minutos-e-segundos-de-retorno-de-data-em-sql) que é sobre formatação de Data/Hora no Oracle foi fechada como fora de escopo, porém a pergunta está bem escrita apesar do fato do AP ter confundido achando que era o PHP que estava formatando a data dele, e na verdade era o banco de dados.

Na primeira vez que você mexe com formatação de data no oracle parece ser bem complicado, o que gera uma dúvida bem frequente nos iniciantes com esse banco de dados. Então eu entendo que é uma pergunta que [**ajudará a coletividade**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8725/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-clique-aqui-para-entender-este-site) e merece mais respostas enriquecendo o post.

Houve um comentário na pergunta pedindo pro AP postar o código PHP e talvez a pergunta tenha sido fechada por falta do código PHP, porém o problema é o oracle e o AP postou as *queries*, mas não dá pra saber se esse foi o motivo do fechamento já que ninguém postou um comentário explicando a razão da pergunta ser fechada.

Comment: A discussão virou um misto de assuntos já tratados em outras postagens, basicamente nada sobre a pergunta fechada (exceto poucas observações iniciais já lidas). Quando fica extenso e é sobre o tópico, movemos para um chat. Aqui no caso se estendeu com assuntos colaterais, então o espaço foi desativado e o ruído removido. Para assuntos colaterais ja há o chat geral da rede, que segue código de conduta, mas não é restrito a um tópico específico. Segue link: [Estouro de Pilha](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha).

Answer (score 5):

### Sobre "como deixar claro para o autor o motivo de estar fora de escopo":

Primeiro, entender o site, senão não tem como você ajudar o autor (sim, você que está lendo, isso aqui é uma comunidade). Um bom começo são estes links:

- [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256)
- [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089)
- [Visão geral do funcionamento do sistema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)
- [Guia rápido sobre como fazer perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [Assuntos e tipos de perguntas permitidos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Em geral, o importante é entender e repassar o conhecimento, orientando os outros usuários.

Isso é o básico do site, mas melhor pecar pelo excesso do que pela falta, então repito:

O site tem um formato de "pergunta e resposta", mas não é para criar soluções individuais. As postagens tem que deixar muito claro o problema (inclusive para leigos), sempre com exemplos mínimos e verificáveis quando envolver código, para que futuros visitantes com o mesmo problema identifiquem que é o mesmo caso, e encontrem a solução.

O que implica em **não restar dúvida sobre a causa do problema** - entre várias outras coisas. A "certeza" de quem responde não basta (até porque, quem responde pode estar enganado também, acontece muito).

### Sobre o fechamento:

Tem um quadro (atualmente azul) no topo com um link para o que o autor pode fazer. Praticamente de todos os fechamentos que participo, quando entendo que o quadro não basta, deixo comentários e links extras conforme o fechamento, ali não entendo como necessário.

O autor da pergunta tem acesso ao campo de comentários de sua própria postagem, se ele estivesse em dúvida e perguntasse algo, com certeza teria um feedback.

### Sobre os argumentos do meta:

Esta pergunta aqui foi vista 131 vezes, a de lá 95 vezes, teve comunidade suficiente visitando para reabrir a pergunta dezenas vezes, independente de moderação.

Isto não ocorreu, com toda essa exposição, e o sistema automático fez a remoção baseada nos votos (prazo generoso para corrigir eventuais enganos).

Acredito que esses números sejam mais do que suficientes e democráticos para deixar claro que a comunidade não entendeu como sendo uma boa pergunta, e não optou por sua reabertura.

O sistema é autogerenciável pela comunidade, e o destino da postagem foi escolhido pela comunidade, conforme os critérios da rede

Para quem ainda não entendeu: de 95 visitas não teve sequer três pessoas que achassem que era o caso de reabrir a ponto de votar - mesmo tendo a discussão aqui no meta. Para piorar, os poucos esclarecimentos pedidos não foram sanados pelo autor, então não tinha muito como ser diferente.

Comment: A conversa se estendeu e foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134778/discussion-on-answer-by-bacco-como-deixar-claro-para-o-ap-o-motivo-do-fora-de-e) - quem quiser ler ou acrescentar algo pode usar o link fornecido