# Por favor nos ajude a traduzir os artigos da central de ajuda sobre as filas de análise

Tags: debate, status-pronto, filas-de-análise, central-de-ajuda

Muito obrigado pela tradução para [Cesar M](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/144721/cesar-m) e [@JNat](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/23291/jnat).

---

Esse ano nós começamos a trabalhar em [melhorar as filas de análise](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346901/improving-the-review-queues-project-overview) e um importante passo é criar uma nova secção na central de ajuda sobre as filas.

#### Por que isso é importante?

A maior parte das informações sobre as filas de análise está em publicações wiki no MSE. Essas publicações são bem detalhadas e contém todas as nuances de como as filas funcionam, porém pode ser muita coisa para um novato. O objetivo dessa iniciativa é criar um local para onde nós possamos direcionar os usuários que acabaram de começar a utilizar as filas de análise para que eles rapidamente possam entender o básico de cada uma delas.

#### Por favor, nos ajude a traduzir os artigos da central de ajuda sobre as filas de análise para português.

Há algumas semanas nós criamos os rascunhos iniciais dos artigos e [postamos eles no MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356120/274323) para feedback. Após incorporar as sugestões nós [adicionamos eles à central de ajuda de cada site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/review-queues), inclusive no [Stack Overflow em português](/help/review-queues)

Eu respondi essa pergunta com as versões atuais dos artigos em inglês nessa pergunta. Por favor, nos ajudem a traduzi-las para português. Acreditamos que os usuários aqui poderão criar uma melhor versão da tradução para que outros usuários do Stack Overflow em português possam entendê-los. Irei adicionar as traduções ao centro de ajuda quando elas estiverem prontas.

Por favor, sinta-se livre para melhorar as traduções existentes! Se necessário, pode mudar a escrita para que o texto fique mais claro e natural, e eu tentarei manter a central de ajuda atualizada com as respostas a essa pergunta.

#### Artigos da central de ajuda sobre as filas de análise

- [O que são as filas de análise?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8513/17539)
- [Por que eu fui suspenso das Filas de Análise??](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8514/17539)
- [Como analisar a fila de Publicações baixa qualidade?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8515/17539)
- [Como analisar a fila de Primeiras publicações?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8516/17539)
- [Como analisar a fila de Edições sugeridas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8517/17539)
- [Como analisar a fila de Votos para fechar?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8518/17539)
- [Como analisar a fila de Votos para reabrir?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8519/17539)
- [Como analisar a fila de Respostas tardias?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8520/17539)

Atenção: não mexa nos *placeholders* (como por exemplo `$Privilege-AccessReviewQueues`), pois estes são substituídos automaticamente pelo sistema.

---

Os artigos da Central de Ajuda estão no ar. Obrigado a todos que ajudaram a traduzir as páginas!

Comment: O que acham de usar *publicação* ao invés de *postagem* / *post* nas traduções? Tenho feito isso em algumas no Traducir e reparei essa situação aqui.

Comment: Penso que na UI há um uso consistente de "publicação" (posso estar errado), e só no Meta é que usamos "post" ou "postagem" de vez em quando. Dito isto, sim, consistência é preferível de qualquer modo.

Comment: @RafaelTavares É, eu costumo usar "postagem" ou "*post*", e - não sei porque - ignoro completamente a tradução da UI, que é "publicação". Bom, mas talvez seja melhor usar "publicação" mesmo, para ficar consistente com o restante do site - lembrando que tem o termo "postagem" em alguns lugares ainda (seria o caso de mudar também?): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=postagem

Comment: Encontrei dois deles traduzidos em pergunta-resposta (como aqui): [1](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5316/traduções-de-páginas-e-links-da-central-de-ajuda/6876#6876), [2](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5316/traduções-de-páginas-e-links-da-central-de-ajuda/6935#6935). Não sei se seria para "editar e aguardar"

Comment: Nicolas, when will the pages be translated? I believe the community had enough time to review the translations, and if nobody else added anything so far, I guess we're good to go.

Comment: @hkotsubo hi! Thank you for pinging me. I was planing to do it over the week. Since the community is already finished translations, I went ahead and updated all help center articles. It seems we are missing translation only of [one string](https://pt.traducir.win/strings/13938).

Answer (score 4):

#### O que são as filas de análise?

Uma das formas da comunidade moderar o site é analisando perguntas e respostas que os usuários ou o sistema identificaram como "*alguém precisa dar uma olhada*". Com isso, pode-se verificar se aquela será uma boa contribuição para o site. Uma vez que você atinge $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues pontos de reputação, passa a ter acesso às primeiras filas de análise - e você ganhará acesso a outras, conforme sua reputação for aumentando.

As filas de análise mostram uma publicação (seja pergunta ou resposta) por vez, para que você possa avaliá-la, e se for o caso, tomar alguma ação. Cada fila possui opções diferentes para que você tome as ações adequadas - em uma, por exemplo, você pode ver as primeiras publicações feitas por novos usuários. Em outras, é possível verificar edições sugeridas por usuários com menos de $Privilege-PostEditing pontos de reputação ou analisar perguntas para decidir se devem ser fechadas ou reabertas.

Cada fila tem um propósito específico, e as páginas da Central de Ajuda listadas abaixo te ajudarão a entender melhor como cada uma dessas filas funciona:

- [Primeiras publicações](/help/review-first-posts) - $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues pontos de reputação. A fila de Primeiras publicações contém a primeira publicação (seja uma pergunta ou resposta) feita por novos usuários. Estas publicações podem precisar de uma atenção especial, já que novos usuários não estão acostumados aos [requisitos de qualidade do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045).
- [Respostas tardias](/help/review-late-answers) - $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues pontos de reputação. Esta fila contém respostas que foram postadas muito tempo depois da pergunta. Analisá-las garante que as boas respostas serão vistas e as que têm problemas serão removidas.
- [Publicações de baixa qualidade](/help/review-low-quality) - $Privilege-PostEditing pontos de reputação. Esta fila contém publicações que foram consideradas de baixa qualidade, baseado em uma pontuação determinada pelo sistema e/ou por sinalizações de usuários.
- [Edições sugeridas](/help/review-suggested-edits) - $Privilege-PostEditing pontos de reputação. Editar publicações de outros usuários requer $Privilege-PostEditing pontos de reputação. Quando usuários que não tem esta pontuação editam uma publicação, a edição é enviada para esta fila.
- [Votos para Fechar](/help/review-close) - $Privilege-CloseQuestion pontos de reputação. Quando uma pergunta não se encaixa no modelo do site e é fora de escopo, precisa ser fechada. Perguntas com votos de fechamento pendentes ou que foram sinalizadas para serem fechadas aparecem nesta fila, para que você possa analisar e decidir se deve mesmo ser fechada.
- [Votos para reabrir](/help/review-reopen) - $Privilege-CloseQuestion pontos de reputação. Se uma pergunta fechada é editada, ou se alguém discorda do fechamento, ela pode ser reaberta. Perguntas com votos de reabertura pendente ou que foram editadas em até 70 dias depois do fechamento aparecem nesta fila.

Obs: As filas de Primeiras publicações e Respostas tardias não existem no [Meta](/help/whats-meta).

---

> Texto original:
>
> #### What are review queues?
>
> One of the ways that the community moderates the site is by
> reviewing posts that have been identified by users or the system as
> needing review to help determine whether the contribution is
> beneficial to the site. Once you have achieved
> $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues reputation, you have access to the first
> set of Review queues – and you’ll gain access to more as your
> reputation increases.
>
> Review queues show you posts one at a
> time, so that you can evaluate what, if any, action is needed. Each
> queue is equipped with distinct options so that you may take
> appropriate action – in one, you may be looking at the first posts by
> new users. In another, edits suggested by lower-reputation users or
> assessing questions to determine if they should be closed or
> reopened.
>
> Each queue has a specific purpose and each of the
> following Help center pages will help you learn more about how to
> review in each queue:
>
> - [First posts](/help/review-first-posts) -
>   $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues reputation. The First Posts queue
>   contains the first posts made by users. These posts may need special
>   attention because the users are not familiar with site quality
>   rules.
> - [Late answers](/help/review-late-answers) -
>   $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues reputation. This queue contains answers
>   that were posted much later than the question. Reviewing these posts
>   makes sure that great new answers get seen and problematic answers get
>   removed.
> - [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-triage) – Stack
>   Overflow only - 500 reputation. The primary goal of Triage is to
>   quickly sort questions into groups: good as is, needs community
>   editing, or should be closed/flagged.
> - [Help
>   and improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-help-and-improvement) - Stack Overflow only - 2,000 reputation. This
>   queue lets you edit questions that were flagged in Triage as needing
>   community editing.
> - [Low
>   quality posts](/help/review-low-quality) - $Privilege-PostEditing reputation. This queue
>   contains posts that were determined to be of low quality based on a
>   system-generated quality score and/or user flags.
> - [Suggested edits](/help/review-suggested-edits) -
>   $Privilege-PostEditing reputation. Editing other people's posts
>   requires $Privilege-PostEditing reputation. When users without enough
>   reputation submit an edit, their proposed changes go into this
>   queue.
> - [Close votes](/help/review-close) -
>   $Privilege-CloseQuestion reputation. When questions aren’t a good fit
>   for our format or scope, they need to be closed. Questions with active
>   close votes or close flags show up in this queue so that others can
>   review whether they should be closed.
> - [Reopen votes](/help/review-reopen) - $Privilege-CloseQuestion
>   reputation. When closed questions get edited, or if others disagree
>   with the closure, they can be reopened. Questions with active reopen
>   votes, as well as questions whose bodies have been edited during the
>   first 70 days since they were closed appear in this queue.
>
> Note: The First posts and Late answers queues do not exist on [Meta sites](/help/whats-meta).

Answer (score 4):

#### Como analisar a fila de Publicações de baixa qualidade?

*Accesso obtido com $Privilege-PostEditing pontos de reputação*
Perguntas e respostas entram na fila de Publicações de baixa qualidade quando são [sinalizadas pelos usuários](/help/privileges/flag-posts)
como sendo problemáticas, ou detectadas pelo sistema por serem potencialmente de baixa qualidade. Isso inclui:

- perguntas ou respostas muito curtas, em idioma diferente do português, ou que dizem coisas sem sentido.
- perguntas escritas no campo de respostas.
- respostas que não respondem de fato à pergunta, ou contém somente *links*, ou não explicam nada.
- respostas que na verdade deveriam ser comentários (como um "palpite" qualquer ou pedidos de mais informações sobre a pergunta), ou que são simplesmente ruído desnecessário ("Estou com o mesmo problema" ou "Obrigado, funcionou!").

É importante salientar que, de acordo com esta definição, uma resposta incorreta não é de "baixa qualidade". Nestes casos, você deveria deixar um comentário explicando porque ela está errada e/ou dar um voto negativo, em vez de sinalizá-la.

### Fluxo básico

Primeiramente, verifique se a publicação é uma pergunta ou resposta; no topo aparecerá escrito "Pergunta" ou "Resposta".

- Escolha **Parece OK** para perguntas dentro do escopo, com detalhes suficientes e que não sejam amplas demais; ou para resposas que respondam ao que foi perguntado, mesmo que não estejam corretas.
- Escolha **Editar** se a publicação tem boa qualidade, mas há espaço para melhorias. Evite editar perguntas que devem ser fechadas ou respostas que devem ser removidas, pois a edição as retira da fila.
- Escolha **Recomendar exclusão** ou **Remover** se você acha que a resposta não tenta responder à pergunta, ou tem apenas *links*, ou é incompreensível. Não vote para remover se elas só estiverem erradas. Nesses casos, você pode deixar um comentário explicando os problemas da resposta, ou escolher um dos comentários predefinidos.
- Escolha **Recomendar fechamento** ou **Fechar** se você acha que a pergunta deve ser fechada (Veja [O que significa se uma pergunta está "fechada" ou "pendente"?](/help/closed-questions)).
- Escolha **Pular** se você ficou em dúvida sobre o que fazer.

O conteúdo desta página foi adaptado do [FAQ do Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029), que também contém informações mais detalhadas sobre esta fila.

---

> Texto original:
>
> #### How do I use the Low-quality posts queue?
>
> *Access earned at $Privilege-PostEditing reputation*\  Posts entering
> the Low-quality posts queue have been [flagged
> as](/help/privileges/flag-posts)  problematic by users or recognized
> by  the system’s quality checks to be potentially low quality. This
> may  include:
>
> - questions or answers that are very short, in the wrong    language or gibberish.
> - new or follow-up questions written as answers.
> - answers that do not attempt to answer the question asked or contain    only links and no explanation.
> - comments entered as answers (“I have the    same question” or “thanks for the great answer”).
>
> It’s important to  remember that an incorrect answer is not “low
> quality” by our  definition. Incorrect answers should get a comment
> explaining any  issues or be downvoted, not flagged.
>
> ### Basic workflow
>
> First, check to see if the post is a question or an answer; it will
> be labeled as "Question" or "Answer" at the top. The  majority of
> posts in this queue will be answers.
>
> - Choose **Looks OK** for questions that are on-topic, sufficiently detailed    and not too broad. Use this option for answers that answer
>   the    question as asked, even if they may be incorrect.
> - **Edit** if the post is good quality, but you can improve the post to make it better. Avoid editing posts that should be closed or
>   deleted, as it will remove the post from review.
> - **Recommend deletion** or **Delete** if you think that an answer does not address the question at all, is link-only, or is
>   incomprehensible. Do not vote to delete answers that are simply wrong.
>   You may leave a comment explaining the issues with the answer, or
>   choose one of the provided canned comments.
> - **Recommend close** or **Close** if you think that a question should be closed (See [What does it mean if a question
>   is](/help/closed-questions) “closed”?).
> - **Skip** if you’re unsure about the post’s quality.
>
> Some of the content of this page is adapted from information in our
> [Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029),
> which also contains more in-depth guidance if you are interested in
> reading more about this queue.

Answer (score 3):

#### Por que eu fui suspenso das Filas de Análise?

*Leia: [O que são as filas de análise e como elas funcionam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work).*

Ser suspenso das filas de análise não é uma penalidade, apenas um "cancelamento" temporário do seu acesso a elas. O objetivo é te dar um tempo para aprender corretamente como analisá-las. Análises mal-feitas afetam negativamente a comunidade e o conteúdo do site. Se você tomou a ação errada em várias análises, você será temporariamente suspenso e não terá acesso às filas durante o período em que durar a suspensão.

Se você foi suspenso, verá uma mensagem no menu superior. Outra mensagem, mais detalhada, será mostrada na página inicial das [Filas de Análise](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review) e nas próprias filas, durante todo o período de suspensão.

[image: Imagem do menu para as filas de análise em 2 situações: primeiro, durante a suspensão, quando a mensagem é visível mas as filas não; segundo, quando a suspensão já terminou mas a mensagem ainda é visível]

Pode acontecer de você ter sido suspenso entre uma visita e outra ao site. Embora sua suspensão tenha terminado, você ainda será notificado que ela ocorreu. Tome ciência da mensagem, e a notificação sumirá.

### O que eu posso fazer enquanto estou suspenso?

Leia atenciosamente a mensagem de suspensão. Revisite as análises que levaram à suspensão, para entender qual deveria ter sido a ação mais apropriada em cada caso. Caso tenham sido fornecidos *links*, leia-os. Durante sua suspensão, você ainda terá acesso ao histórico de cada fila. Se você tem alguma dúvida sobre as análises que levaram à sua suspensão, crie uma pergunta no Meta e use a tag `[filas-de-análise]`, lembrando de incluir as seguintes informações:

- Um *link* para a revisão que causou a suspensão,
- Explique porque você tomou a ação feita na análise (importante se você acha que a suspensão foi indevida),
- Pergunte qual seria a ação correta neste caso e porquê.

Futuramente, faça as análises com calma, sem pressa, e dê a atenção devida a cada caso. Se você está em dúvida sobre qual deveria ser a ação correta a ser tomada, use o botão "Pular" e deixe que outros façam a análise.

---

> Texto original:
>
> #### Why was I suspended from the Review Queues?
>
> *Learn more about [what the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work)
> are and how they work.*
>
> Review suspensions are not penalties, but temporary holds on your
> reviewing privilege. The purpose of this is to give you time to learn
> more about how to review correctly. Poor reviews negatively effect the
> community and the site’s content. If you take incorrect action on
> multiple tasks, your reviewing privilege may be temporarily suspended
> and you won’t have access to the Reviews Queue during this time
> period.
>
> If you are suspended, you will see a suspension message in the Review
> Queue navigational dropdown. A more detailed message will be available
> to you in the [Review Queue dashboard](/review) and in the queues.
> This message will remain for the duration of your suspension.
>
> [image: Screenshot of the Review Queue dropdown in two states, first, during a suspension where the review suspension message ("Notice Review privileges suspended - Your review privileges are suspended until Jul 24. Click to learn more.") is visible but none of the review queues are and second after the suspension is over but the review message ("Notice Review privileges suspended - Your review privileges were suspended for 7 days. Click to learn more") is still visible.]
>
> You may have been suspended between visits to the site. Although your
> suspension has expired, you will still be notified that the suspension
> occurred. Review and acknowledge the message and the notification will
> be dismissed.
>
> ### What can I do in the meantime?
>
> Read the suspension notice carefully. Revisit the tasks that led to
> your suspension to understand the more appropriate action. Review
> resource links that may have been provided with your suspension.
> During your suspension, you will still have access to each queue’s
> Stats and History pages. If you have any questions about the review
> tasks that led to the suspension, post a question on Meta
> and use the `[review-suspension]` tag. In your post, be sure to
> include the following information:
>
> - A link to the review that caused your suspension,
> - An explanation of why you made the choice you did (particularly important if you feel the suspension is in error),
> - A request to understand what the correct choice should have been and why.
>
> In the future, take your time while reviewing and make sure each task
> is given adequate attention. If you're not certain what the correct
> action is, make use of the "Skip" feature and let someone else handle
> that review.

Answer (score 3):

#### Como analisar a fila de Primeiras publicações?

*Acesso obtido com $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues pontos de reputação*
A fila de Primeiras publicações contém a primeira publicação (seja pergunta ou resposta) feita por usuários novos,
que podem não saber a melhor forma de perguntar ou responder, além de não entender o que faz parte do escopo do site.
O objetivo desta fila é dar atenção especial a estes usuários, que podem precisar de orientações
neste sentido, e às suas publicações, que provavelmente precisarão ser melhoradas.

### Fluxo básico

Ao analisar, você pode tomar uma ou mais ações, ou não fazer nada. Tome todas as ações que achar necessárias.
Por exemplo, uma pergunta pode estar bem feita e dentro do escopo, mas precisa que a formatação seja melhorada.
Neste caso, edite-a e - caso ache apropriado - vote positivo, e a seguir clique em "Terminei".

- Escolha **Nenhuma ação é necessária** se nada precisa ser feito.
- Escolha **Terminei** se você fez pelo menos uma dessas ações:

  - **Votou** positivo ou negativo.
  - **Editou** (ou sugeriu uma edição), no caso da publicação estar dentro do escopo e a edição foi somente para melhorar a gramática ou formatação.
  - **Comentou** (ou votou em algum comentário já existente) para indicar algo que poderia ser melhorado. Esses comentários podem ser úteis tanto para o autor quanto para outros usuários que forem analisar a publicação.
  - **Sinalizou** por ser *spam* ou rude/abusivo, ou por ser uma resposta que não tentou responder à pergunta (ou que contém apenas um *link*).
  - [Usuários confiáveis](/help/privileges/trusted-user) também podem **votar para remover** respostas que não tentam responder à pergunta, ou que contém somente *links*, ou são cópias de outras respostas.
- **Pular** se você não sabe ao certo o que fazer.

Uma análise feita por uma pessoa é o suficiente para retirar a publicação da fila,
então analise com cuidado para que a pergunta ou resposta esteja de acordo com os critérios
de qualidade do site. Aqui estão algumas orientações para te ajudar a analisar e decidir quais ações tomar:

#### Para todas as publicações (perguntas e respostas)

- Se contém *spam* ou *links* que parecem apenas promover algum produto, sinalize como "spam".
- Se for ofensivo, sinalize como "rude ou abusivo".

#### Para perguntas

- Verifique se as partes principais da pergunta estão no próprio texto da mesma, e não em outro site. Se há *links* para outros sites, a pergunta deve fazer sentido mesmo se os *links* não estiverem funcionando.
- A pergunta deve:

  - estar clara.
  - ter toda a informação necessária para que seja respondida.
  - estar dentro do escopo do site.
  - solicitar respostas baseadas em fatos.
  - demonstrar esforço/pesquisa.
  - estar com as *tags* apropriadas.
- Se achar necessário, comente e peça que sejam fornecidas as informações faltantes, ou sugira que a pergunta seja reescrita de forma a se encaixar no escopo.
- Se parece que esta pergunta já foi feita anteriormente, verifique se ela não é duplicada.
- Vote positivo em perguntas bem feitas e dentro do escopo, para encorajar e motivar os novos usuários.
- Às vezes a pergunta precisa ser fechada, e isso pode ser feito por meio de [sinalizações](/help/privileges/flag-posts) ou
  votos de fechamento. Você pode ler mais a respeito de fechamentos [aqui](/help/closed-questions).

#### Para respostas

- Verifique se o autor da resposta realmente tentou responder de maneira focada, em vez de apenas colocar um comentário qualquer (uma "dica" que não responde de fato, por exemplo), ou se na verdade ele colocou outra pergunta.
- A resposta deve ser única: não pode ser uma cópia de outras respostas já existentes.
- A resposta não deve ter *links* quebrados, e também [não deve ter apenas links](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/42/).

Para saber mais sobre como editar adequadamente, por favor veja [esta página da Central de Ajuda](/help/editing).

O conteúdo desta página foi adapatado do [FAQ do  Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180030),
que também contém informações mais detalhadas sobre esta fila.

---

> Texto original:
>
> #### How do I use the First posts queue?
>
> *Access earned at $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues reputation*    The First Posts queue contains the first few posts created by new users,
> who may  not fully understand the best way to ask and answer
> questions, or  what's on- and off-topic on this site. The purpose of
> this queue is to  give special attention to users who may need to be
> educated on some  aspect of our model, and to posts that are more
> likely to need  improvement.    ## Basic workflow     When reviewing,
> you may do one or more of several actions or you may do none. Perform
> all actions that you deem  necessary. For example, a question may be
> complete and on-topic but  need formatting help. In this case, edit to
> improve the formatting and - if you wish - upvote it before clicking
> "I'm done".
>
> - Choose **No action needed** if the post requires no intervention.
> - Select **I’m done** if/when you’ve completed any  of the following:
>
>   - **Vote** up or down.
>   - **Edit** (or suggest an edit) if the  post is clear and within guidelines, but could use some editing help to  improve grammar,
>     spelling, or formatting.
>   - **Comment** (or upvote existing comments) to point out content  that is missing or may need adjusting. These comments can be useful to
>     both the post author and other reviewers.
>   - **Flag** posts that are spam or rude, as well as answers that don't attempt to answer the question or are link-only.
>   - [Trusted users](/help/privileges/trusted-user) may also **vote to delete** answers that don’t attempt to answer the question, are
>     link-only, or are duplicates of other answers.
> - **Skip** if you’re unsure about what to do.    One review from a user is enough to dismiss the task, so review  carefully to ensure
>   that this question meets site expectations. Here  are some guidelines
>   when reviewing and deciding which actions to take  on new posts:
>
> #### For all posts
>
> - If the post is spam or contains promotional links, flag it as "spam".
> - If the post is offensive, flag as "rude or abusive".     ### For questions
> - Check that the main part of the question is in the post itself and not hosted off-site. If there are links to other  sites, the question
>   should be written so that it makes sense even if  the links break or
>   change.
> - The question should:
>
>   - be clear.
>   - have all necessary information required to answer it.
>   - be on-topic for the site.
>   - solicit fact-based answers.
>   - show research.
>   - be appropriately tagged.
> - If appropriate, comment and ask for the missing information to narrow the  scope of the question, or reword the question so it fits
>   the site  scope.
> - If the question seems like a question you have seen before,  check if the post is a duplicate.
> - Upvote good, well-written questions  to encourage new users.
> - Sometimes a question will need to be closed,  which can be done by [flagging](/help/privileges/flag-posts) or  voting to
>   close it. You can read  more about
>   when questions should be closed  [here](/help/closed-questions).
>
> #### For answers
>
> - Check that the post author attempts to provide a focused answer, and not a simple comment or new question post.
> - The post should be unique from other answers provided.
> - The post should  not have broken links or be exclusively made up of links.    For more information on how to edit effectively, please see
>   our [Help  center article about editing](/help/editing).    Some of
>   the content of this page is adapted from information in our  [Meta
>   Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180030), which
>   also contains more in-depth  guidance if you are interested in reading
>   more about this queue.

Answer (score 3):

#### Como analisar a fila de Edições sugeridas?

*Accesso obtido com $Privilege-PostEditing pontos de reputação*
O objetivo principal da fila de Edições sugeridas é revisar as edições feitas por usuários que possuem menos que
$Privilege-PostEditing pontos de reputação e decidir se a sugestão
foi benéfica para a publicação. Edições sugeridas devem focar na melhoria da gramática, ortografia e formatação,
ao mesmo tempo em que não alterem a intenção do autor.

Para usuários com mais de $Privilege-ApproveTagWikiEdits pontos de reputação, você também verá nesta fila sugestões de edição em wikis de tag.
Para mais informações sobre este tipo de edição, veja [esta página](/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits).

### Fluxo Básico

Comece lendo o comentário da edição e veja quais são as diferenças entre o conteúdo original e o editado.
Verifique também se houve mudanças no título (e nas tags, caso seja uma pergunta), e veja nos comentários
se há alguma informação que o autor só colocou lá.

A seguir, escolha uma das opções:

- **Aprovar** se a edição melhora a publicação e não precisa que mais nada seja mudado.
- **Melhorar** se a edição é boa porém incompleta, e use o editor para consertar o que falta.
- **Rejeitar** se a edição é supérflua, piora a publicação ou altera a intenção original do autor.
- **Rejeitar e Editar** se a edição piora a publicação ou não resolve o problemas dela. Esta opção abrirá o editor
  para que você mesmo melhore a publicação.
- **Pular** se você não tem certeza se a edição melhora ou piora a publicação.

### Motivos mais comuns para Aprovar

- Coloca informações adicionais ou deixa a publicação mais clara.
- Melhora a gramática, ortografia ou formatação, ou corrige outros problemas menores.
- Adiciona informações que estavam nos comentários.
- Atualiza uma resposta, caso mais informações estejam disponíveis ou algum detalhe tenha mudado.
- Adiciona *links* para outras fontes ou citações.

### Motivos mais comuns para Rejeitar

Ao rejeitar uma edição, você pode escolher o motivo:

- *Spam* ou vandalismo

  - adiciona *links* irrelevantes ou contendo propaganda "disfarçada" ou faz menção à produtos.
  - prejudica ou destrói o conteúdo da publicação.
- Não apresenta melhorias

  - muda o conteúdo ou a formatação de maneira desnecessária ou deixa a publicação mais confusa.
  - muda a gramática, ortografia ou [estilo de escrita](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12/) de maneira desnecessária.
- Tags irrelevantes

  - tags servem para indicar o assunto da pergunta; rejeite edições que adicionam tags erradas.
- Não representa a intenção do autor

  - muda o conteúdo para dizer o oposto ou algo muito diferente do que estava anteriormente.
- Tentativa de resposta

  - pede por mais informações ao autor (algo que deveria ser feito por comentário).
  - coloca uma resposta no corpo da própria pergunta (muito frequente em casos de perguntas fechadas)
- Prejudica a publicação

  - Este motivo pode ser usado quando uma sugestão deve ser rejeitada mas nenhum dos outros motivos se encaixa (ou mais de um é aplicável). Você deve explicar porque está rejeitando a edição, assim as outras pessoas que forem revisar poderão entender os motivos.

O conteúdo desta página foi adaptado do [FAQ do Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155539), que também contém informações mais detalhadas sobre esta fila.

---

> Texto original:
>
> #### How do I use the Suggested edits queue?
>
> *Access earned at $Privilege-PostEditing reputation*\  The primary
> purpose of the Suggested edits queue is to review edits contributed by
> users who have less than  $Privilege-PostEditing reputation and
> determine if the suggested edits  are beneficial to the post.
> Suggested edits should focus on improving  grammar, spelling, and
> formatting, all while maintaining the author’s  original intent.
>
> For users with $Privilege-ApproveTagWikiEdits reputation, you may
> also see tag wiki edit suggestions in this queue. For more information
> about handling these reviews, see the [approve tag wiki
> edits](/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) privilege page.
>
> ### Basic workflow
>
> Start by reading the edit summary and looking at the differences
> between the original post and the edit. Be sure to check  the title
> (and tags, if a question) to see if they were edited, and  check the
> comments section for any information that the author may  have
> included only in comments.
>
> - **Approve** if the edit improves the post and doesn’t need any additional edits.
> - **Improve edit** if the edit is good but incomplete, and use the edit window to fix any outstanding issues.
> - **Reject** if the edit is unnecessary, destructive, or counter to the    original author’s intent.
> - **Reject and edit** if the suggested edit makes    the post worse or doesn’t solve critical issues with the post. Then add    your own
>   edit - this will open an edit window allowing you to improve    the
>   post.
> - **Skip** if you’re unsure whether the post was improved or not
>
> ### Common reasons to Approve
>
> - Adds additional information or clarifies existing answer.
> - Improves grammar, spelling or formatting of the post    or other minor mistakes.
> - Edits in information found in comments.
> - Updates an answer if more information is available or something has    changed.
> - Adds links to sources or citations.
>
> ### Common reasons to Reject
>
> When rejecting an edit, you’ll need to choose a rejection reason.
> These are a good outline for the reasons you may need to reject a
> suggested edit:
>
> - Spam or vandalism
>
>   - adds irrelevant or unattributed promotional links or
>     mentions of products.
>   - damages or destroys the content of the post.
> - No improvement whatsoever
>
>   - changes to content or formatting that are
>     unnecessary or make the post more confusing.
>   - changes to grammar,
>     spelling,  or style that are unnecessary.
> - Irrelevant tags
>
>   - tags should
>     clearly indicate the subject of the question; reject edits that add
>     tags that are tangential or incorrect.
> - Clearly conflicts with author’s    intent
>
>   - changes a post to say the opposite, or something very different
>     from what the original post read.
> - Attempt to reply
>
>   - introduces a request for clarification or question to the post’s author that should have been a comment or answer.
> - Causes harm
>
>   - This reason can be used in cases where a suggestion should be prevented but none of the above or several of the above apply. You
>     should explain why you are rejecting the suggestion so that other
>     reviewers can understand your action.
>
> Some of the content of this page is adapted from information in our
> [Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155539),
> which also contains more in-depth guidance if  you are interested in
> reading more about this queue.

Answer (score 3):

#### Como analisar a fila de Votos para fechar?

*Accesso obtido com $Privilege-CloseQuestion pontos de reputação*

A fila de Votos para fechar inclui perguntas que outros usuários sinalizaram para fechamento. Mas antes de analisá-la, você deve se familiarizar com os tipos de perguntas que devem ou não ser fechadas. Para encontrar estas informações, leia as seguintes páginas:

- [O que significa se uma pergunta está "fechada" ou "pendente"?](/help/closed-questions) – um guia geral para os principais motivos de fechamento. Uma pergunta geralmente é fechada nestes casos:

  - é [duplicata](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) de outra pergunta já existente no site.
  - precisa de mais informações para ser respondida.
  - precisa ser mais focada, pois da forma atual, as respostas seriam amplas demais.
  - é baseada em opiniões, e por isso não terá respostas objetivas.
- [A respeito de quais tópicos posso fazer perguntas aqui?](/help/on-topic) – um guia mais específico, que descreve os tipos de perguntas que estão dentro e fora do escopo do site (cada site da rede tem suas próprias definições).

### Fluxo básico

No topo da página de análise, você verá os motivos pelos quais as perguntas foram sinalizadas ou receberam votos de fechamento. Mas se você discorda, pode escolher outra opção. O motivo que receber mais votos será indicado na pergunta, caso esta seja fechada. Analise todo o conteúdo da pergunta e só depois escolha uma das opções abaixo:

- **Fechar** a pergunta caso ela seja duplicata, ou não tenha detalhes suficientes,
  ou seja muito ampla, ou baseada em opiniões, ou fora do escopo, ou se encaixe em algum
  dos motivos específicos que aparecem se você escolher a opção "Um motivo específico da comunidade".
  Escolha a opção que melhor se aplicar ao caso. Você também tem a opção de escolher "Outros" caso nenhum dos motivos acima se aplique.
- **Deixar aberta** caso a pergunta não deva ser fechada.
- **Editar** deveria ser feito apenas se a pergunta, na forma atual, deve ser fechada, mas você acredita que com uma edição é possível deixá-la dentro do escopo. Isso inclui adicionar detalhes que o autor deixou apenas nos comentários, ou fazer pequenos ajustes de forma que uma pergunta baseada em opiniões se torne mais objetiva. Não faça pequenas correções se elas não ajudarem a deixar a pergunta dentro do escopo. Basta pensar: "se eu editar desta forma, ela ainda poderá ser fechada?" - se a resposta for "sim", não edite, já que uma edição a removerá da fila.
- **Pular** caso você não tenha certeza se a pergunta deve ser fechada. Não tenha receio de usar o botão "Pular"! Foque nas perguntas que você tem certeza sobre o que fazer, e deixe as que você ficou em dúvida para os demais analisarem.

**Dica:** Você pode filtrar as perguntas que são mostradas na fila. Por exemplo, é possível filtrar por tags, para que apareçam apenas perguntas cujos assuntos você conhece. Para isso, basta clicar em "Filtro" no topo da análise.

[image: Close votes filters]

Atenção: se você escolher duas tags, poderão aparecer perguntas que contém apenas uma delas, ou ambas. Não há como filtrar por perguntas que contém apenas as duas tags.

O conteúdo desta página foi adaptado do [FAQ do Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180032), que também contém informações mais detalhadas sobre esta fila.

---

> Texto original:
>
> #### How do I use the Close votes queue?
>
> *Access earned at $Privilege-CloseQuestion reputation*
>
> The Close votes  queue includes questions that other users have
> flagged as needing to  be closed. Before reviewing in this queue, you
> should be familiar with what sorts of questions should and should not
> be closed. To find that information, see the following two pages:
>
> - [Closed question help article](/help/closed-questions) is a network-wide guide for the primary reasons questions should be closed.
>   This generally happens when a question:
>
>   - is a [duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) of an existing question on the site.
>   - needs additional details or clarity to be answered.
>   - needs to be more focused, as the existing question is too broad.
>   - is an opinion-based question that doesn’t have an objectively correct answer.
> - [On topic article](/help/on-topic) is a site-specific guide to what types of questions are on and off topic on this site. This page will
>   differ on each site on the Network.
>
> ### Basic workflow
>
> At the top of the review task page, you’ll find the reasons others
> flagged or voted the question to be closed, but if you disagree, you
> may choose a different option. The close reason that gets the most
> votes will be indicated on the post if it is closed. Review the
> question content completely and then make a decision from one of the
> options:
>
> - **Close** the question if it is a duplicate, lacks sufficient detail,    needs to be narrowed in scope, is opinion based, is off
>   topic, or if    it meets one of the other community-specific reasons
>   to close. Choose    the applicable close reason based on your
>   assessment. You also have    the option to enter a custom reason if
>   none of the existing ones    apply.
> - **Leave open** if none of the above is the case.
> - **Edit** should be reserved for when the question is close-worthy as written, but when you believe you can rescue the question to make
>   it fit the scope. This may mean adding in details the asker left in
>   comments or making slight adjustments to an opinion-based question so
>   that it's objective. Don’t make minor edits if the question would be
>   closed even with these changes, as it will remove the question from
>   review.
> - **Skip** any time you’re not certain - don’t be afraid to use the skip button! Focus on reviewing posts you’re certain of rather than
>   ones you need to guess how to handle.
>
> **Tip:** You may want to restrict which questions you are shown to
> subjects you are familiar with by filtering reviews by tags you have
> experience in. You can do this by clicking “Filter” in the top section
> of a review task. When in doubt, choose Skip.
>
> [image: Close votes filters]    Note:
> If you choose two tags, you will find all reviews with one or both
> tags. Filters will not restrict to reviews with both tags only.
>
> Some of the content of this page is adapted from information in our
> [Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180032),
> which also contains more in-depth guidance if you are interested in
> reading more about this queue.

Answer (score 3):

#### Como analisar a fila de Votos para reabrir?

*Accesso obtido com $Privilege-CloseQuestion pontos de reputação*
Qualquer pergunta fechada que recebeu um voto de reabertura é colocada nesta fila,
assim como qualquer pergunta editada em até 70 dias depois do fechamento.
Mas antes de analisar esta fila, você deve se familiarizar com os tipos de perguntas que devem ou não ser fechadas. Para encontrar estas informações, leia as seguintes páginas:

- [O que significa se uma pergunta está "fechada" ou "pendente"?](/help/closed-questions) – um guia geral para os principais motivos de fechamento. Uma pergunta geralmente é fechada nestes casos:

  - é [duplicata](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) de outra pergunta já existente no site.
  - precisa de mais informações para ser respondida.
  - precisa ser mais focada, pois da forma atual, as respostas seriam amplas demais.
  - é baseada em opiniões, e por isso não terá respostas objetivas.
- [A respeito de quais tópicos posso fazer perguntas aqui?](/help/on-topic) – um guia mais específico, que descreve os tipos de perguntas que estão dentro e fora do escopo do site (cada site da rede tem suas próprias definições).

### Fluxo básico

Avalie a pergunta da forma que ela está atualmente. Revise as edições que foram feitas depois que ela foi fechada e quaisquer comentários feitos nela. Se as edições não forem suficientes para reabri-la, você pode deixar um comentário explicando o motivo.

- Escolha **Deixar fechada** se os motivos de fechamento ainda se aplicam. Não reabra se um motivo específico não servir mas a pergunta ainda deva ser fechada por outro motivo. Considere deixar um comentário explicando porque a pergunta deve permanecer fechada, principalmente se o motivo for diferente daquele que levou ao fechamento.
- Escolha **Editar e reabrir** se você pode consertar os problemas da pergunta, e a edição é suficiente para que ela seja reaberta. Evite editar detalhes menores que não façam a pergunta estar boa o suficiente para ser reaberta.
- Escolha **Reabrir** se os problemas da pergunta foram resolvidos, ou se ela foi fechada indevidamente.
- Escolha **Pular** se você não tem certeza se a pergunta deve ser reaberta.

**Dica:** Você pode filtrar as perguntas que aparecem, por exemplo, escolhendo as tags dos assuntos que você conhece mais. Basta clicar em "Filtro" no topo da página de análise.

[image: Reopen votes filter]

O conteúdo desta página foi adaptado do [FAQ do Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180450), que também contém informações mais detalhadas sobre esta fila.

---

> Texto original:
>
> #### How do I use the Reopen votes queue?
>
> *Access earned at $Privilege-CloseQuestion reputation*\  Any closed
> question that has received one reopen vote gets added to this queue,
> as well as any question edited within 70 days since its closure.
> Before reviewing in this queue, you should be familiar with what sorts
> of questions should and should not be closed. To find that
> information, see the following two pages:
>
> - [Closed question help article](/help/closed-questions) is a    network-wide guide for the primary reasons questions should be closed.
>   This generally happens when a question:
>
>   - is a duplicate of an existing question on the site.
>   - needs additional details or clarity to be answered.
>   - needs to be more focused, as the existing question is too broad.
>   - is an opinion-based question that doesn’t have an objectively correct answer.
> - [On topic article](/help/on-topic) is a site-specific guide to    what types of questions are on and off topic on this site. This page
>   will differ on each site on the Network.
>
> ### Basic workflow
>
> Evaluate the question as it is now. Review any edits that may have
> been made after the question was closed and any comments  on the
> question. If edits were made but are insufficient to reopen the
> question, consider leaving a comment explaining why.
>
> - **Leave closed** if close reason(s) still apply. Do not reopen if the    specific reason for closure no longer applies, but the question
>   should    still be closed. Consider leaving a comment to explain why
>   the question should remain closed, particularly if the reason is
>   different than what appears in the banner.
> - **Edit and reopen** if you can resolve issues with the    question yourself, and these edits are sufficient for the post to be
>   reopened. Avoid making minor edits that don’t impact whether the post
>   should be reopened.
> - **Reopen** if issues with the question have been    resolved, or if it was incorrectly closed.
> - **Skip** if you're not sure    whether the question should be reopened.
>
> **Tip:** You may want to restrict which questions you are shown to
> subjects you are familiar with by filtering reviews by tags you have
> experience in. You can do this by clicking “Filter” in the top section
> of a review task. When in doubt, choose Skip.
>
> [image: Reopen votes filter]
>
> Some of the content of this page is adapted from information in our
> [Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180450),
> which also contains more in-depth  guidance if you are interested in
> reading more about this queue.

Answer (score 3):

#### Como analisar a fila de Respostas tardias?

*Accesso obtido com $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues pontos de reputação*
A fila de Respostas tardias contém respostas que foram publicadas por novos usuários
muito tempo depois que a pergunta foi feita. Respostas tardias tendem a ser vistas
por poucas pessoas, se comparadas àquelas escritas logo depois que a pergunta é feita,
e esta fila de análise assegura que as respostas tardias tenham os mesmos critérios de qualidade
das demais.

Muitas respostas tardias são apenas um "Obrigado, funcionou!", ou são
outras perguntas relacionadas ao mesmo assunto ("Também estou com esse problema"),
e por isso devem ser apagadas. Há também os casos que requerem um conhecimento específico
do assunto, e caso você fique em dúvida se a resposta é ou não uma tentativa genuína de
responder a pergunta, use a opção de "Pular".

### Fluxo básico

Ao analisar, você pode tomar uma ou mais ações, ou não fazer nada. Tome todas as ações que achar necessárias.
Por exemplo, uma resposta pode estar completa e de fato responde à pergunta, mas precisa de melhorias na formatação.
Neste caso, vocè pode editá-la e - caso ache-a útil e com boa qualidade - dar um voto positivo, e em
seguida clique em "Terminei".

- Escolha **Nenhuma ação é necessária** se nenhuma ação deve ser tomada
- Escolha **Terminei** caso tenha feito algumas das ações abaixo:

  - **Votou** positivo ou negativo.
  - **Editou** (ou sugeriu uma edição), caso a resposta esteja clara e dentro dos critérios de qualidade,
    e a edição serviu para melhorar a gramática e/ou formatação.
  - **Comentou** para indicar que algo está faltando ou que o conteúdo pode ser melhorado.
    Estes comentários podem ser úteis tanto para o autor quanto para outros usuários que forem analisar a resposta.
  - **Sinalizou** como *spam* ou rude/abusivo, ou porque a resposta não é uma tentativa de responder, ou contém apenas *links*.
  - [Usuários confiáveis](/help/privileges/trusted-user) também podem **Remover** respostas que não são tentativas de responder, ou contém apenas *links*, ou são cópias de respostas já existentes.
- **Pule** se você não está certo quanto ao que fazer

### Casos comuns de respostas tardias

- *Spam* ou auto-promoção

  - Se a resposta se encaixa nos [critérios de auto-promoção válida](/help/promotion), coloque um comentário
    mencionando isso para reduzir a chance de outros usuários marcarem-na como *spam*. Caso não se encaixe,
    coloque um comentário com o *link* já mencionado e encoraje o autor a editar a resposta para que ela se encaixe nos critérios.
    Caso ela se pareça com *spam*, sinalize.
- Não-respostas

  - Respostas agradecendo o autor da pergunta ou de uma das respostas, ou fazendo uma nova pergunta, ou dizendo que está com o mesmo problema, ou pedindo mais detalhes ao autor, todas essas devem ser removidas.

Para mais informações sobre como editar adequadamente, veja [esta página da Central de Ajuda](/help/editing).

O conteúdo desta página foi adaptado do [FAQ do Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180031), que também contém informações mais detalhadas sobre esta fila.

---

> Texto original:
>
> #### How do I use the Late Answers queue?
>
> *Access earned at $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues reputation*\  The Late Answers queue contains answers that were posted by new users much
> later than when the question was asked. Late answers tend to be seen
> by fewer people than answers posted soon after the question was asked,
> so the review queue helps ensure that these answers meet the same
> quality standards as all other answers.
>
> While many late answers are merely saying “Thanks!” or are attempts
> to  ask follow-up questions and should be deleted, in other cases it
> may  require specific knowledge of the topic. If you’re unsure whether
> the  answer actually attempts to answer the question, use the “Skip”
> option.
>
> ### Basic workflow
>
> When reviewing, you may do one or more of several actions or you may
> do none. Perform all actions that you deem  necessary. For example, an
> answer may be complete and do a good job of  answering the question,
> but need formatting help. In this case, edit to  improve the
> formatting and - if you wish - upvote it before clicking "I'm done".
>
> - Choose **No action needed** if the answer requires no intervention
> - Select **I’m done** if/when    you’ve completed any of the following:
>
>   - **Vote** up or down.
>   - **Edit** (or
>     suggest an edit) if the answer is clear and within guidelines, but
>     could use some editing help to improve grammar, spelling, or
>     formatting.
>   - **Comment** to point out content that is missing or may need
>     adjusting. These comments can be useful to both the post author and
>     other reviewers.
>   - **Flag** posts that are spam or rude, as well as answers that don't attempt to answer the question or are link-only.
>   - [Trusted users](/help/privileges/trusted-user) may also **Delete** answers that don’t attempt to answer the question, are
>     link-only, or are duplicates of other answers.
> - **Skip** if you’re unsure about what to do
>
> ### Common Late answers
>
> - Spam or self-promotion
>
>   - If the answer meets the [description for acceptable self-promotion](/help/promotion), add a
>     comment mentioning this to reduce the chance of other reviewers
>     marking it spam. If it does not, add a comment linking to the help
>     center article and encourage the author to edit the post to meet our
>     guidelines. If it unequivocally looks like spam, flag it as such.
> - Non-answers
>
>   - Answers thanking the author of the question or one of its
>     answers, asking a new question, stating that they have the same problem, or asking for clarification from the author. These should be
>     deleted.
>
> For more information on how to edit effectively, please see our [Help
> center article about editing](/help/editing).
>
> Some of the content of this page is adapted from information in our
> [Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180031),
> which also contains more in-depth  guidance if you are interested in
> reading more about this queue.